# Связь между вопросами на разных языках

Tags: предложение, вопросы, stackoverflow

Предлагаю сделать связь вопросов между форумами различных языков (английский, русский, португальский и т. д.). Например, была создана связь между вопросами на английском и русском языках, если теперь с португальского форума сделают связь на английский или русский вопрос, то становится видно связь и на остальные связанные вопросы.

StackOverflow - это энциклопедия знаний и раз это энциклопедия, то возьмем википедию - там видно статью на другом языке. Было бы очень удобно, чтобы одинаковые вопросы на разных языках были легко доступны по одному клику.

---

Конкретные примеры: [Подсветка ключевых слов в TextBlock или RichTextBox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/421031/) и 
[Highlight text in RichTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5685644/1299307) - два абсолютно одинаковых вопроса. Вот только если кто-то найдет данный вопрос на английском языке, то никогда не увидит замечательный ответ @VladD.

Comment: Прекрасная идея! Спасибо! Добавил в список инициатив. Попробую обсудить с коллегами во время следующего совещания (в конце месяца).

Comment: Если ответ замечательный, то полезно его  перевести, а ссылку на близкий вопрос на другом языке ввиде комментария в любом случае хорошо добавить (или не навязчиво в самом вопросе — можно на Мета.SO обсудить: допустимо ли это).

Answer (score 7):

Это для русскоговорящих и португалоговорящих нормально знать английский, а знают русский среди англоговорящих единицы. Если просто сослаться на русский СО и сказать, что там есть крутой ответ, то это будет дразнилкой: "Ха-ха-ха, у нас есть решение, а у вас нет! Бе-бе-бе!" То есть по-хорошему надо взять и перевести на английский.

С другой стороны, среди посетителей большого СО довольно большой процент русскоговорящих, и вот для них будет очень к месту даже голая ссылка. Более того, такие ссылки на популярных вопросах могут привести на русский СО множество новых пользователей, которые слыхом не слыхивали про наш сайт — он ведь даже из "Hot Network Questions" выпилен.

В связи с вышесказанным всячески поддерживаю перекрёстные ссылки. С оговоркой, что всё-таки надо стремиться переводить текст, а не только давать голую ссылку.

Comment: Вот про привлечение новых пользователей очень заманчивая идея.

Answer (score 3):

Зачем португальскому или английскому СО русские вопросы?

"Данный вопрос является дубликатом" - это для закрытия вопросов. Мы не можем закрывать вопросы как дубликаты английского СО.

Если хочется добавить ссылку на английский СО - это можно сделать комментарием.

Comment: Ну, а зачем в википедии ссылка на «та же статья на других языках»? Чтобы тот, кто владеет обоими языками, мог видеть обе статьи.

Comment: @Abyx я постоянно слышу про то, что надо выпиливать "здравствуйте, добрый день" итп, потому что SO это **энциклопедия знаний** но раз это энциклопедия, то возьмем википедию - там видно статью на другом языке. Я не говорю про то, что закрывать дубликаты на АнглоСО, я говорю про то, чтобы одинаковые вопросы на разных языках были легко доступны по одному клику.

Answer (score 3):

По-моему, надо дать пользователю возможность сказать, какие языки он знает. и пусть сайт показывает ему связанные вопросы только на этих языках. Тогда русскоязычные пользователи увидят ссылку на русскоязычный ответ и порадуются, а англоязычные не увидят и не будут злится.

Comment: Мне кажется, что не зависимо от знания языка должны показываться все сайты. Если человек заходит на английский сайт и предложенные там ответы его не впечатлили, то он зайдет на русский сайт и посмотрит ответы там. Если ответ это кусок кода - код универсален. Если ответ - это текст, то если человеку нужно решение, то он научится пользоваться google translate

Comment: Такой подход мог бы сработать с Hot Network Questions, а так я согласен с @ReinRaus — код универсален.