# Создание связей между одинаковыми вопросами на разных языках

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, ассоциация-вопросов

Обсудив с командой идею, [изложенную в предложении](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347/) @ReinRaus, мы пришли к выводу, что было бы здорово реализовать что-то подобное. Первым шагом к внедрению столь значимых изменений в функционале движка является создание полноценного предложения к рассмотрению. Для этого нам, сообществу, необходимо собрать все имеющиеся идеи.

Чтобы идеи были конструктивнее, предлагаю добавлять в них ответы на следующие вопросы.

1. Каково назначение функционала? Какие задачи мы пытаемся решить?
2. Какими привилегиями и репутацией должен обладать участник? В каких сообществах?
3. Какой минимальный набор функций интерфейса пользователя мы бы хотели видеть?
4. Кому следует показывать аналогичные вопросы на других языках?
5. Какие языки должны иметь перекрестные ссылки?
6. Можно ли будет добавлять пересекающиеся ссылки между сообществами разных тематик?
7. В каком месте следует отображать ссылки на аналогичные вопросы?
8. Какие ограничения к вопросам и ответам должны быть для добавления ссылок?
9. Как добавление ссылки на аналогичный вопрос на другом языке должно взаимодействовать с системой нотификаций и почтовыми подписками?
10. Как обновление аналогичного вопроса или добавление к нему ответов должно взаимодействовать с системой нотификаций и почтовыми подписками?
11. Необходима ли проверка (подтверждение) назначения вопросов аналогичными со стороны сообщества?
12. Должен ли автор перевода/ассоциации получать баллы репутации за создание перевода/связи между вопросами?
13. Если пользователь хочет написать перевод вопроса (не ассоциацию), как следует обрабатывать перевод (назначать общим, кто должен быть автором и т. д.)?

---

Пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь вносить в сообщение правки с новыми вопросами к рассмотрению.

Comment: Зачем было делать вопрос общим?

Comment: @Qwertiy чтобы участники с репой меньше 2000 могли его дополнять.

Answer (score 15):

1. > Каково назначение функционала? Какие задачи мы пытаемся решить?

   1. Продвижение локализованного сайта за счёт основного среди пользователей. В интерфейсе основного сайта сейчас нет абсолютно ничего, что намекало бы на существование сайта на другом языке, в результате даже те, кто мог бы предпочесть SO.(RU|PT), продолжают пользоваться SO.EN.
   2. SEO. Ссылки с SO ценны и уважаемы.
   3. Ну и посетителям будет удобно, да. :)
2. > Какими привилегиями и репутацией должен обладать участник? В каких сообществах?

   Так как перекрёстная ссылка затрагивает оба сайта, то репутация нужна на обоих. Например, сейчас привилегии на 1К (750 на бете) абсолютно бесполезны (карточка юзера, чат-галерея). По-моему, подходящий порог. Учитывая, что его нужно выбивать на двух сайтах, а не на одном, то порог достаточно высокий, то есть можно рассчитывать на адекватность юзера.
3. > Какой минимальный набор функций интерфейса пользователя мы бы хотели видеть?

   Вероятно, стоит запихнуть в форму редактирования вопроса. Выделять в отдельную кнопку под постом смысла большого нет, потому что это не будет настолько часто использоваться, да там и без того тесно.

   Можно добавить список и кнопку "Добавить перекрёстную ссылку". По нажатию отображать список "родственных сайтов". При выборе сайта — возможность ввести вопрос, как в диалоге выбора дубля.

   Кстати о птичках, эта фича может быть полезна не только для локализованных сайтов, но и для размножившихся специализированных сайтов. Тематики достаточно часто пересекаются. Так что в родственных у большого Stack Overflow может быть достаточно много технических сайтов.
4. > Кому следует показывать аналогичные вопросы на других языках?

   Всем. Но с разным приоритетом. См. ответ №7.
5. > Какие языки должны иметь перекрестные ссылки?

   Э... все? Не понял вопрос.
6. > Можно ли будет добавлять пересекающиеся ссылки между сообществами разных тематик?

   Зависит от определения слова "разных". Если сообщества пересекаются по интересам, то ссылки должны быть возможны.
7. > В каком месте следует отображать ссылки на аналогичные вопросы?

   1. Если у юзера есть признаки "локализованности" (IP, Accept-Language, страна в профиле), то показывать первым блоком среди ссылочных:

      - ... Stats, Meta, ads ...
      - **In other languages**
      - Linked
      - Related
      - ... Hot Ntework Questions ...
   2. Для всех остальных отображать, но запрятать подальше, чтобы не мешалось:

      - ... Stats, Meta, ads ...
      - Linked
      - Related
      - **In other languages**
      - ... Hot Ntework Questions ...

   На Википедии ссылки отображаются для всех, и этим никто не возмущается. Кстати о Википедии. Можно добавить к ссылкам метки с количеством ответов, плюсов или ещё чего-нибудь. Это касается всех ссылок на посты, не только вновь добавляемых.
8. > Какие ограничения к вопросам и ответам должны быть для добавления ссылок?

   Как для закрытия как дубля: или принятый, или заплюсованный ответ.
9. > Как добавление ссылки на аналогичный вопрос на другом языке должно взаимодействовать с системой нотификаций и почтовыми подписками?

   Можно уведомлять автора вопроса.

   Можно уведомлять добавившего ссылку, если с ней что-то происходит.

   Но вообще не очень-то надо.
10. > Как обновление аналогичного вопроса или добавление к нему ответов должно взаимодействовать с системой нотификаций и почтовыми подписками?

    Никак. Не вижу простого способа и очевидного профита.
11. > Необходима ли проверка (подтверждение) назначения вопросов аналогичными со стороны сообщества?

    Можно добавить в инструменты модератора список изменений в ссылках. В эффективность массового ревью верится с трудом.
12. > Должен ли автор перевода/ассоциации получать баллы репутации за создание перевода/связи между вопросами?

    Нет. Будет достаточно репутации авторам вопросов за счёт дополнительных посещений.

    Обсуждать добавление репы только за ссылку считаю неприличным, пока не даётся репутация за закрытие вопроса как дубликата — более важное и гораздо более распространённое действие. Сделают репу за закрытие как дубликата — можно будет думать. При реализации репы за закрытие как дубликата встанут те же самые проблемы: когда давать, когда возвращать, как проверять и т. п.

    Кроме того, если не добавлять проверку сообществом, то давать репу за непроверяемое действие — это прямой путь в пропасть.
13. > Если пользователь хочет написать перевод вопроса (не ассоциацию), как следует обрабатывать перевод (назначать общим, кто должен быть автором и т. д.)?

    Никак. Если вопросы связаны, это не значит, что один перевод другого, что один главнее другого и т. п. Если в какой-то момент что-то куда-то было перенесено, это не значит, что развитие остановилось, и никто не будет добавлять новые ответы, или что перевод будет поддерживаться в актуальном состоянии.

    Разводить какую-то невообразимо сложную иерархию, пока нет примеров реального использования, будет преждевременно.

Comment: 11. Мне кажется, что массовое ревью будет полезным. Сделать перекрестные ссылки отдельным блоком ревью, почему Вы в него не верите ?

Comment: 2. Мне кажется, что либо 1к на обоих сайтах, либо примерно 4к на любом из сайтов.

Comment: @ReinRaus 11. Для проверки нужно, чтобы юзер 1) знал два или более языка 2) имел аккаунт на двух сайтах 3) на каждом имел репутации больше, чем нижний порог у добавления ссылки (скажем, 2К), 4) регулярно проводил ревью. Сколько вы знаете активных юзеров, у которых есть 2000+ аккаунт на большом СО, 1000+ аккаунт на СО.РУ (2000+ после беты), которые постоянно сидят в очередях проверок?

Comment: @ReinRaus 2. Общий принцип в том, что сайты независимы. Будь у юзера хоть миллион репы, на новом сайте СЕ он начнёт как простой смертный со 100 репы, с базовых прав (ссылки, мета, голосование, комментарии, чат, вики). Не вижу оснований отходить от этой логики. Ссылки сказываются на содержимом обоих сайтов, поэтому давать юзеру менять содержимое сайта, на котором у него нет прав, и в правилах которого он потенциально не разбирается, было бы неправильным и отхождением от общего принципа.

Comment: @Discord Добавил еще два пункта в конец.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Обновил.

Comment: `Так как перекрёстная ссылка затрагивает оба сайта, то репутация нужна на обоих. ` Что, если там одинаковый вопрос на трёх языках или больше? Скажем, что участник А имеет достаточную репутация на en.so и ru.so, и добавит ссылки между английскими и русскими вопросами. Потом, участник Б, который имеет репутацию на en.so и  pt.so, но не на ru.so, хочет добавить ссылку к португальскому вопросу. Будет ли связь между русскими и португальскими вопросами в такой ситуации?

Answer (score 8):

Я считаю, можно расширить вопрос от "на разных языках" до "на разных сайтах stackexchange". Например:

- [git] есть на [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git?sort=votes&pageSize=30), [ru.so](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git?sort=votes&pageSize=15), [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/git?sort=votes&pageSize=15), [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/git?sort=votes&pageSize=15), [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/git?sort=votes&pageSize=15), [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com//questions/tagged/git?sort=votes&pageSize=15) (вот уж не ожидал)...
- Думаю, некоторые теги и вопросы могут повторяться на English Language & Usage и English Language Learners
- Аналогично на Role-playing Games и Board & Card Games

Тогда эта фича становится более востребованной.

Comment: Совершенно с Вами согласен (сам хотел об этом где-нибудь написать), но лучше бы придерживаться утверждённой переводной терминологии, раз уж на этом сайте мы вынужденны писать по-русски.

Или Вам противно слово «метка»?

Answer (score 6):

Пример ответа.

1. Программисты ищут информацию на английском языке, хотя не всегда обладают достаточными навыками для быстрого прочтения ответов и, что более важно, для правильного понимания и усвоения информации. Если, попадая на вопрос, представленный на английском языке, таким программистам будет доступен аналогичный ответ на русском, то очень вероятно, что они смогут понять проблему глубже, а как результат - лучше выполнить свою работу и, более того, повысить свой уровень знаний.
2. Для добавления перекрестных ссылок участник должен обладать некой суммарной репутацией во всех сообществах. Например, если данная привилегия будет доступна после 20К репутации, то пользователь может иметь 10К + 10К репутации или 20К и 1К репутации. Репутация - это численная мера того, насколько сообщество доверяет вам, а также того, насколько значимый ваш вклад. Как результат, не имеет значения, в какой пропорции ваша репутация.
3. Для начала было бы достаточно интерфейса, аналогичного тому, что используется для назначения дубликатов вопросов. То есть необходимо добавить дополнительный пункт в инструмент редакторов с полем ввода ссылки или идентификатора аналогичного вопроса.
4. Ссылки на аналогичные вопросы следует показывать всем.
5. Нужно создавать единый список ссылок для вопроса. Например, если для вопроса на русском языке есть аналог на португальском, то ссылку на него следует создавать.
6. Да, можно, но только для разных языков, на одном языке одинаковые вопросы - это копии. Разрешить создание ссылок с Stack Overflow на русском, например, на Server Fault следует, потому что на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы, касающиеся системного администрирования, являются тематическими.
7. Ссылки следует отображать в двух местах: 1) в боковой панели, 2) под заголовком вопроса (после меток вопроса). В боковой панели отображать список ссылок на все версии вопроса. Под заголовком вопроса следует отображать ссылку только на один язык, который, вероятно, является первым языком пользователя. Например, определив, что пользователь имеет IP, соответствующей Москве, первым языком будет русский.
8. Следует не допускать создания ссылки на замороженный вопрос, закрытый вопрос и вопросы с большим количеством минусов. Также, скорее всего, следует допускать создание перекрестной ссылки только между вопросами, получившими как минимум один ответ.
9. Следует добавить дополнительную опцию в настройки: “отслеживать добавление аналогичных вопросов на других языках”.
10. Аналогично п. 9.
11. Необходима проверка, аналогичная проверке описания меток, которая после достижения заданного порога репутации / заданного количества успешных ассоциаций будет не нужна.
12. Если пользователь создает перевод вопроса/ответа, то баллы репутации должны начисляться как-будто это был-бы обычный вопрос/ответ. Ассоциацию двух вопросов следует оценивать аналогично улучшающей правке.
13. Скорее всего, вопрос не должен отмечаться общим (за общие вопросы баллы не начисляются), но должен быть помечен как перевод. Первой ревизией (версией) для таких вопросов должна быть исходная версия вопроса/ответа на оригинальном языке.

Comment: Не уверен есть ли смысл принудительно замыкать человека в рамки русскоязычного сегмента вместо англоязычного линка-пинка-под-зад что бы развивал ХОТЯ БЫ **чтение** англоязычной информации. Если тема банальная -- пусть колупается с переводчиком. Это пойдет на пользу гарантировано. Если тема сложная -- есть смысл уже переводить. **А на отсутствие гугления как на русском так и на английском (перед задавания вопроса) по-хорошему делать замечание нужно в обязательном порядке. Как миниум замечание.**

Answer (score 3):

1. > Каково назначение функционала? Какие задачи мы пытаемся решить?

Назначение функционала можно выразить одним словом: [hreflang](https://www.google.ru/search?q=hreflang)

2. > Какими привилегиями и репутацией должен обладать участник? В каких сообществах?

Правами на правку в местном сообществе. Аналогично правке меток

3. > Какой минимальный набор функций интерфейса пользователя мы бы хотели видеть?

   Достаточно hreflang в коде, остальное сделает гугл
4. > Кому следует показывать аналогичные вопросы на других языках?

Тем, кому интересны оба языка. Возможность это выяснить существует как для зарегистрированных, так и для незарегистрированных пользователей. У незарегистрированых можно смотреть на HTTP-заголовок Accept-Language. Зарегистрированным имеет смысл добавить ссылки на сайты, на которых у них есть аккаунт.

5. > Какие языки должны иметь перекрестные ссылки?

С ruSO можно добавлять ссылки только на enSO. Чтобы добавить ссылку с ruSO на ptSO нужно создать две ссылки: ruSO -> enSO и ptSO -> enSO

6. > Можно ли будет добавлять пересекающиеся ссылки между сообществами разных тематик?

Это проще чем поддерживать списки соответствия между сайтами

7. > В каком месте следует отображать ссылки на аналогичные вопросы?

Можно добавить блок "Аналогичные" под блок "Связанные"

8. > Какие ограничения к вопросам и ответам должны быть для добавления ссылок?

Аналогично закрытию дубля

9. > Как добавление ссылки на аналогичный вопрос на другом языке должно взаимодействовать с системой нотификаций и почтовыми подписками?

Сообщать обо всех действиях, но только по тем сайтам, на которых пользователь зарегистрирован

10. > Как обновление аналогичного вопроса или добавление к нему ответов должно взаимодействовать с системой нотификаций и почтовыми подписками?

Аналогично п.9

11. > Необходима ли проверка (подтверждение) назначения вопросов аналогичными со стороны сообщества?

Ещё одна очередь проверок

12. > Должен ли автор перевода/ассоциации получать баллы репутации за создание перевода/связи между вопросами?

Переведенные вопросы ничем не отличаются от обычных. Добавление связи эквивалентно правке меток

Comment: 5 - Не согласен. В таком варианте получается, что ты для каждого вопроса должен знать эквивалентный на enSO. F если не там, а не server fault? А у тебя там и аккаунта-то нет, не говоря о знании о наличии там нужного вопроса. Должно быть можно связать любые два сайта.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я имел ввиду, что один из вопросов должен быть главным. Если создавать ссылки напрямую, работа очереди проверок сильно усложнится. В том варианте, что предлагаю я, для участия в проверке достаточно репутации только на одном, локальном, сайте

Comment: Очередь не нужна. По крайней мере, для начала не нужна. Но я думаю, при соответствующем выборе лимита она и не будет нужна.

Comment: На мой взгляд, добавление такой связи не должно ничем отличаться от добавления новой метки. Добавить может любой, а чтобы добавить миную проверку или участвовать в проверке требуется 2000+ репутации

Comment: Ну так и поставить этот лимит на 2000. Не вижу смысла в проверяемых связях - они создают необходимость иметь несколько людей, разбирающихся в вопросе и знающих оба языка.

Comment: 1. Привилегий уже и так несколько десятков, зачем добавлять ещё одну когда можно использовать существующую? 2. Пользователей, знающих русский и английский значительно больше чем знающих русский и португальский. Можно даже сказать, что читать по английски умеют все программисты. 3. А смысл в проверяемых правках меток видите?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Каково назначение функционала? Какие задачи мы пытаемся решить?

...

> 2. Какими привилегиями и репутацией должен обладать участник? В каких сообществах?

В одном из них, в котором добавляет связь (думаю, это даже проще реализовать).
Но связь двухсторонняя и автоматически добавляется во втором.

> 3. Какой минимальный набор функций интерфейса пользователя мы бы хотели видеть?

...

> 4. Кому следует показывать аналогичные вопросы на других языках?

Всем. Код универсален и не зависит от языка.
К тому же, никогда не знаешь, какие языки знает пользователь.

> 5. Какие языки должны иметь перекрестные ссылки?

Все сайты сети.

> 6. Можно ли будет добавлять пересекающиеся ссылки между сообществами разных тематик?

Да. Тематика меняется и нет смысла ограничивать функционал.
Ограничение списка сайтов - это необоснованное усложнение, которое потом плохо аукнется.

> 7. В каком месте следует отображать ссылки на аналогичные вопросы?

Справа сбоку добавить ещё раздел.

> 8. Какие ограничения к вопросам и ответам должны быть для добавления ссылок?

Никаких. А зачем?

> 9. Как добавление ссылки на аналогичный вопрос на другом языке должно взаимодействовать с системой нотификаций и почтовыми подписками?

Как комментарий со ссылкой на этот же ресурс, которая попадает в связанные вопросы?

> 10. Как обновление аналогичного вопроса или добавление к нему ответов должно взаимодействовать с системой нотификаций и почтовыми подписками?

Никак?

> 11. Необходима ли проверка (подтверждение) назначения вопросов аналогичными со стороны сообщества?

Для начала можно не делать. Если что-то пойдёт не так, то думать.

> 12. Должен ли автор перевода/ассоциации получать баллы репутации за создание перевода/связи между вопросами?

Эм.. Ну мы же не получаем баллы за закрытие дубликата. А почему тут должны?

> 13. Если пользователь хочет написать перевод вопроса (не ассоциацию), как следует обрабатывать перевод (назначать общим, кто должен быть автором и т. д.)?

Не мудрить. На мете уже было обсуждение, что перевод заслуживает голоса.