# Можно ли вручную добавлять ссылки между одинаковыми вопросами на разных языках?

Tags: обсуждение

У нас было предложение [о функционале создания связей между одинаковыми вопросами на разных языках](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/431/176684). Кажется, эта идея получила поддержку сообщества, но ничего не случилось. И по-моему, не очень вероятно, что такой функционал у нас скоро будет, так как это - достаточно большая задача для разработчиков Stack Overflow, и нет никакого доказательства, что такой функционал вообще нужен.

Поэтому, я предлагаю, чтобы мы добавляли ссылки просто так, без официального функционала. Давным давно, в детстве Stack Overflow, когда закрыли дубликаты, добавили ссылки на оригинальный вопрос вручную, а потом появилась специальная фича для этого, когда стало видно, что она нужна. Так что давайте добавлять ссылки вручную, и может быть, когда-то в будущем, появится функционал.

Как говорится, лучше просить прощения, чем разрешения, поэтому я уже добавил такие ссылки между одинаковыми вопросами на разных языках:

- [Что значит "use strict"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/435546/176684)
- [What does "use strict" do in JavaScript, and what is the reasoning behind it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1335851/546661)
- [¿Qué significa “use strict”?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/2184/416)

А как думаете вы? Стоит ли продолжать добавлять такие ссылки?

---

На других языках: [English](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316884/546661) • [Español](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/463/416)

Comment: А почему бы и нет? Вопрос это точно не ухудшает.

Comment: @VladD Может быть подумают, что эти ссылки мало кому важны, и для будущих читателей отнимают внимание от важной информации.

Comment: Могут, конечно. Но я считаю, что обсуждение на других языках часто содержит важную дополнительную информацию, и выигрыш от этого с огромным избытком превосходит проблему добавленной одной строки. В конце-концов, мы здесь делаем базу знаний, а что такое база без связей между данными?

Comment: Полностью поддерживаю, давно хочу чтобы это стало фичей. http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/503/181472

Comment: Вопрос почти о том же: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1568/181472

Answer (score 9):

Не только можно, но и нужно:

- ответы могут быть разными изначально и/или отдельно эволюционировать со временем
- лицензия требует, если материалы другого пользователя с SE сайта используются (см. footer)

Существует аналогичная функция в Википедии: *«Прочитать на другом языке»*.
"Одинаковость" вопросов на SO тяжелее судить (люди могут спорить, что является дубликатом, даже если вопросы на одном языке), поэтому **достаточно публиковать ссылки на "похожие" (related) вопросы в комментариях** (не обязательно, чтобы языки были разными, можно ссылаться на любые полезные ресурсы даже на том же самом языке (SE site, bug tracker, blog, etc)).

В интерфейсе уже есть поддержка для ссылок на вопросы с того же сайта — см. справа "Связанные" (ссылки, опубликованные в комментариях, ответах, вопросе). Возможно стоит расширить эту функциональность, чтобы поддерживать ссылки и на другие SE сайты (с группировкой ссылок по сайтам или отображением иконок сайтов, если необходимо).

Если модераторы, вычищая старые комментарии под вопросом, не будут удалять комментарии с ссылками, то специальная поддержка в интерфейсе для ссылок не очень и нужна.

Comment: `Возможно стоит расширить эту функциональность` Может быть, но что нам делать сейчас? Стоит ли добавлаять ссылки сейчас (либо в правках, либо в комментариях), или надо ждать до того, что изменяют функционал похожих вопросов?

Comment: *"достаточно публиковать ссылки на "похожие" (related) вопросы в комментариях"* (есть плюсы и минусы по сравнению с редактированием вопроса -- можно отдельно обсудить, если есть желание). Достоинства расширения поддержки ссылок: 1- автоматически обратные ссылки создаются 2- ссылки сгруппированы в один список 3- список остаётся даже если комментарии будут удалены. Ждать не надо (кто хочет и так уже оставляет ссылки).