# Перевод ответов: чужая репутация?

Tags: обсуждение, ответы, перевод-содержимого

Вот какая ситуация: я задал [вопрос на SO на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/567511/libsuinput-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8), потом [его же](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39559063/libsuinput-creating-joystick-with-more-than-one-button) на английском SO. Через два дня на enSO объявил конкурс, получил ответ, принял/плюсанул/наградил. Посмотрел профиль автора ответа - он зарегистрирован и на ruSO, но e-mail не написан.

Какое поведение в данной ситуации ожидается от меня? Списать чужой ответ и получить репутацию за него? Написать комментарий со ссылкой к оригинальному ответу, чтобы автор прочитал? Или что-то иное?

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Стоит ли переводить вопросы и ответы с англоязычного SO?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/70/23044)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Зависит от уровня Вашей лени. Публикую список решений, отсортированный по уменьшению уровня лени:

1. **Ничего не делать вообще**

   Сомневаюсь, что такой вариант будет Вам интересен (раз уж Вы сами решили обсудить проблему на Мете) и уж тем более от ничего неделания мир лучше не станет.
2. **Опубликовать ссылку на ответ в комментариях к вопросу**

   Это позволит другим пользователям найти всё же ответ (хоть и на английском языке) на поставленный вопрос. При этом авторство ответа становится доступным. Дополнительно в этой ситуации можно упомянуть автора ответа по нику через `@` с предложением оформить ответ на ruSO.
3. **Опубликовать свой ответ**

   Если автор ответа не отреагировал на Ваше предложение из предыдущего пункта за приемлемое время, считаю, что Вы вправе выполнить вольный перевод его ответа, не забыв, конечно, указать ссылку на первоисточник.

Comment: На мой взгляд, можно выделить лишь третий пункт, как желаемое поведение участников, особенно, в контексте перспективы функционала создания ассоциаций между вопросами на разных сайтах. Ссылка-ответ – плохой способ сбора информации, так как ссылки имеют свойство переставать работать.

Answer (score 17):

Если вы задали вопрос на двух сайтах и получили ответ на одном из них - будет очень неплохо если ответ появится и на другом.

Не переживайте за чужую репутацию. Труд переводчика - тоже труд, и он также нуждается в вознаграждении. Так что смело переводите чужой ответ на другой язык, публикуйте (с указанием авторства) и отмечайте как принятый.

Answer (score 15):

1. Публикуя вопросы одновременно на двух сайтах, надо в них указывать ссылки на вопрос на другом языке. Если отвечающего это заинтересует, он сам выберет, где ответить.
2. Давшего желаемый ответ можно в комментариях спросить, хочет ли он сам его опубликовать на другом сайте.
3. Если не хочет, надо самому опубликовать перевод.
4. Репутация, полученная за перевод, является вполне заслуженной.
5. Но если уж тебе совсем не хочется её получать, можно отметить ответ общим.

PS: [Why are some question-askers active on both English and Russian Stack Overflows?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276523/309650)

Comment: Поскольку так получилось, что изначальный вопрос касается моего ответа, отдельно отмечу, что именно подобная последовательность действий мне кажется наиболее правильной. Я действительно могу не увидеть вопрос тут или там (поэтому ссылку хорошо бы видеть сразу) и я лично не буду переживать вообще, если кто-то переведёт в любую сторону мой ответ с указанием ссылки на оригинал (и получит заслуженные плюсики, да).

Answer (score 14):

Думать в терминах "чужая репутация"—вредно. Акцент на репутации уводит от настоящего вопроса: *для кого полезен ваш вопрос и ответы на него*—улучшат ли они рунет—помогает ли это создать [«свободную библиотеку подробных ответов на любой прикладной вопрос по программированию и системному администрированию»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Если ответ на ваш вопрос может быть интересен русскоязычному программисту (к примеру, ребёнку или энтузиасту, который в индустрии не работает), то стоит опубликовать ответ на Stack Overflow на русском, даже если вы уже получили удовлетворительный ответ (в любом месте).

Если ясно что ответ на русском был бы полезен и вопрос только в том *кто* должен его опубликовать, то стоит автору ответа на английском Stack Overflow комментарий оставить с просьбой это сделать (как вы уже сделали—хотя кратко стоило бы упомянуть *почему* (мотивация) вы думаете стоит переводить ответ). Или [опубликовать самостоятельно ответ (что приветствуется)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)—достаточно кратко упомянуть суть решения и оставить ссылку на более детальный ответ. По-меньшей мере стоит добавить комментарий к вопросу со ссылкой (я это сделал), см. [Можно ли вручную добавлять ссылки между одинаковыми вопросами на разных языках?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2541/23044)

Повторюсь: [изначальная цель "better programming", а не заработать "fake internet points"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/09/five-years-ago-stack-overflow-launched-then-a-miracle-occurred/).

Answer (score -1):

Скорей всего Англо говорящие не будут отвечать на русской версий и еще незабываем о том что ответ на ваш вопрос может помочь другим!
то есть если есть ответ на Русской версий - во время навигаций по интернету поможет одному,а если есть на Английской версий то поможет другому. Не забудем и о комментариях на 2-х языках.

- Так что как вариант можно повторяться если вопрос действительно сложный!

Comment: *Скорей всего Англо говорящие не будут отвечать на русской версий* -- вопрос как раз приводит автора, который знает **и** английский, **и** русский. Если бы автор не знал русский, для него перевод был бы затруднителен и прилагаемые им усилия не стоили бы той репутации, что он мог бы получить за ответ.

Comment: В вопросе отмечено, что отвечающий имеет учетную запись на ruSO, т.е. он не исключительно англоговорящий.