# Ассоциация ENSO Чей ответ отмечать, как верное решение

Tags: обсуждение, ассоциация-вопросов, перевод-содержимого

Прочитал переведенную статью: [Следует ли обращаться к участникам по имени в вопросах на Мете?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4790/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5?cb=1) где есть рекомендация решать вопросы в общем виде и даже не ссылаться на топики, дабы не засветить имя автора, поэтому спрошу вашего мнения в общем виде.

Ситуация такая: Ищу на ENSO интересные вопросы - ответы по своей специализации - SVG. 
Изучаю, перевожу, сначала всё оформляю у себя, на черновиках, чтобы потом быстро оформить вопрос-ответ у нас на сайте. Где-то прочитал здесь, что надо сразу оформлять ответ, если вопрос был по ассоциации ENSO. Но, иногда не успеваю, так как еще комментарии с ENSO, тоже нужно добавлять и вот в эти 5-10 минут разрыва, ребята успевают дать свой ответ. И ответы хорошие на довольно сложные вопросы и код видно, что свой.

Как мне поступать в этих случаях, кому отдавать зеленую галочку? Ответчику с ENSO или нашим отвечающим, если у них свой ответ и он, как минимум не хуже.
Да, забыл добавить,в комментариях у меня всегда добавлена запись: "Ассоциация ENSO" и ссылка на соответствующий топик там.

Comment: Кстати, если вы оформляете вопрос/ответ, вы можете прямо во время написания вопроса поставить галку «Ответить на собственный вопрос», и вы сможете опубликовать ответ _одновременно_ с вопросом.

Comment: А вы ответственно подходите к переводам.

Comment: мета-обсуждение, на которое вы сослались не запрещает вам ссылки на конкретные вопросы/ответы приводить, если это необходимо. Его цель, чтобы люди вместо тем: "давайте <имярек> забаним за X действия", создавали бы темы: "Являются ли X действия допустимыми" (акцент на поведении, а не человеке).

Comment: Об ответственности: [Обратите внимание, что вам нужно, чтобы добавить префиксы поставщиков для поддержки браузера.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/629394/176064) Гугл-переводчик переводит лучше.

Comment: @vp_arth Согласен, там действительно хуже перевел. Исправил

Comment: @Alexandr_T, ссылку на сам вопрос, который переводился лучше добавить _внутрь_ вопроса, а для [ассоциации](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4120/186999) использовать комментарий следующего формата: **ассоциация:ссылка**

Comment: @Grundy В статье исправил: ссылка на источник внутри вопроса, ссылка на ассоциацию в комментариях ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31247310/circle-loading-animation/31250477#31250477    В таблицу, как вы договорились окончательно ссылку с протоколом добавлять или без. Там так и сяк есть

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Как мне поступать в этих случаях, кому отдавать зеленую галочку?

### Кому хотите.

Я серьёзно, **в этом вопросе судья ровно один, и это автор вопроса**, то есть, **вы**. Вообще галочка задумана для того, чтобы демонстрировать, каким решением в итоге воспользовался автор вопроса. Решение может сработать не для всех, но если для него сработало, это достаточная причина поставить ему галочку.

Нередки ситуации, когда галочка отдаётся не самому хорошему ответу, это быстро всплывает по количеству голосов.

У вас, конечно, ситуация немного необычная, у вас проблемы как таковой не возникло, потому и однозначно объявить, чем воспользовались, вы не можете — вы ничем не воспользовались, это вам просто не нужно. Традиционный способ выбора цели для галочки не работает.

**Поэтому проще всего отметить ответ, который нравится вам больше всего.**

Передумаете — нет проблемы переставить.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я думал и думаю точно так же, как Вы и другие участники этого обсуждения. Но есть нюансы, вызванные не полным еще с моей стороны, пониманием лицензионных соглашений и этических норм и правил. Где-то тут, я читал, что к нам на ruSO  может зайти и англоязычный модератор, как он отнесется к тому, что вся ихняя инфа по вопросу-ответу и даже комментарии размещены у нас, а пальму первенства мы отдали своему ответу.

Comment: @Alexandr_T у нас используется лицензия общего назначения для контента, не содержащая никаких особых понятий только о StackExchange. Так что... Ну придёт, и что? :D Вопросы одинаковые? Одинаковые. Значит, ассоциация правильная. А ответы – где какие образовались.

Answer (score 8):

Вы можете поступать абсолютно также как с любыми другими вашими вопросами: **если ответ помог лично вам (автору вопроса), то вы можете отметить его *"принятым"*** ("верный" он или не очень — это отдельный вопрос — в частности поэтому у нас голосование по ответам и существует).

Не имеет значения, что есть похожий вопрос на Stack Overflow на английском (предполагая что необходимые ссылки на оригинальные вопросы/ответы присутствуют, если вы их как-либо использовали). Не имеет значения, что вопрос начал свою жизнь как перевод с английского — важен только результат.

Цель не в том, чтобы дословный перевод получить — цель в том, чтобы задать вопрос, который может возникнуть у многих людей (у вас к примеру) и привести полезное решение для этих людей (для вас). [Происхождение вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3824/23044) имеет второстепенное значение, [простота вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/685/23044) имеет второстепенное значение, [является ли вопрос домашним заданием для кого-то](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/231/23044) имеет второстепенное значение — [важно только](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4181/23044):

1. могут ли этот вопрос найти люди с похожей проблемой
2. насколько полезны ответы для решения это проблемы.