# Допустима ли публикация решений задачек?

Tags: обсуждение, тематика

Недавно мне попалась простенькая задачка про bash (и всякие консольные утилиты в linux). Стоит ли её публиковать на основном сайте вместе с решением?

Даже несколько более общий вопрос: можно ли публиковать условия каких-либо задач (учебных, с собеседований, из тестов и т.п.) одновременно с их решениями. Будет ли это полезно и иметь смысл?

Возможно, стоит как-то перефразировать условие?

Не понятно, как в таком случае сформулировать сам вопрос. Ведь если я вначале буду писать «Я не понимаю, как решить», а затем следом писать ответ, это будет выглядеть несколько странно. А если просто скопипастить условие, без всяких вводных фраз, будет не совсем ясен контекст.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ответ на собственный вопрос](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3542/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81)

Comment: Ну и раздел справки [соответствующий](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: К сожалению, в том вопросе не обсуждается конкретно _решение задач_. Конкретно меня интересует мнение сообщества по поводу публикации решений _тестовых_ или _учебных_ задач. Кроме того, мне нет смыса впоследствии редактировать вопрос (или ответ), как это предлагают в ответе на ворос, на который вы сослались. Я вполне могу его и за один присест написать.

Comment: а в чем Вы видите принципиальную разницу: вопрос на тестовое/учебное задание и любой другой вопрос по теме ruSO?

Comment: @alexolut, дополнил. Мне не ясно, как правильно оформить вопрос в таком случае

Comment: легко и просто: в вопросе описываете задачу, в ответе - решение. Писать в вопросе о том, что "не знаю как решить" совершенно излишне для **любого** вопроса. С самоответом или без. Посмотрите, например вопросы с меткой [tag:соревнование]. Там участники тоже публикуют самоответы.

Comment: То есть выдумывать и приводить в вопросе "попытки решения" также не стоит?

Comment: я бы не стал мудрить и оформлять какое-то художественное произведение в вопросе. Да и в ответе тоже. Всё должно быть четко и лаконично. Меньше воды - больше сути.

Comment: @alexolut опубликуете как ответ?

Comment: @NickVolynkin а у модераторов нет кнопки "преобразовать в ответ"? Вообще, я надеялся на закрытие как дубликат :) Но если Вы настаиваете...

Comment: @alexolut, ну не дубликат же.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну, не факт.

Comment: @alexolut кнопки нет и вопрос мне не кажется дубликатом.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> можно ли публиковать условия каких-либо задач (учебных, с собеседований, из тестов и т.п.)

Если условия являются искусственной серией "сделайте это, сделайте то" и не встречаются на практике в виде одной обрамляющей прикладной проблемы, то вероятно публиковать условие как есть без изменений не очень полезно. Посмотрите [На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

А так происхождение вопроса, кто его автор, и кто авторы ответов не имеет значения, если сам вопрос полезен. [Ситуация аналогична переводам вопросов.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4815/23044)

Для ясности: **можно ответить на свой вопрос на Stack Overflow**, [это  явно поощряется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Можно сделать вопросы более полезными, если вместо публикации полного задания/условия, вы разобьете его на более прикладные составляющие — вопросы, которые могут возникнуть и у других людей.
При принятии решения, разбивать вопрос на несколько или всё в одном публиковать, можно думать о вопросе как о классе/функции (high cohesion внутри вопроса, loose coupling между вопросами) — насколько понимание отдельных частей зависит от деталей других частей задания, насколько самодостаточны отдельные части, насколько понимание ухудшается при дроблении/объединении. Постарайтесь, чтобы ваш [вопрос улучшал сайт](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4181/23044).

Если сомневаетесь, опубликуйте вопрос и слушайте отклики. Если комментарии не ясны или вы продолжаете минусы получать за вопросы, то создайте более специфичное обсуждение на Мете, приведя уже конкретные примеры вопросов.

---

Вопросы с меткой [соревнование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) -- это совсем отдельная тема -- они имеют свои критерии. Начните с [описания метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/info).

Есть также ещё метка [инспекция-кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0), со [своими правилами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0/info).