# Предложение введения многоязычных сообщений

Tags: предложение, перевод-содержимого

На Meta регулярно поднимается вопрос о необходимости перевода тех или иных материалов на языки, отличные от английского, путём копирования их из одного раздела в другой. Однако, подобная практика порождает ряд проблем, а именно:

1. Дублирование. Многочисленные копии вопросов, а также их обсуждение размазываются по различным языковым версиям.
2. Малый охват. Необходимо определять, какие вопросы следует переводить, а какие нет.
3. Неактуальность материала. Для сохранения актуальности содержимого перевода необходимо отслеживать ход дискуссии в исходном варианте, так как после окончания перевода может появиться новый, более актуальный ответ и/или комментарий.
4. Потеря структуры. При переносе теряется информация об оригинальных авторах. Также теряется деление сообщений по сообществам StackExchange, перерождаясь в деление по языковому признаку, что сильно засоряет ленту и поисковую выдачу.
5. Люди, не являющиеся носителями английского языка, не имеют возможности принимать участие в оригинальной дискуссии.

**Предлагаю ввести:**

1. Возможность задания для одного и того же вопроса/ответа/комментария нескольких альтернативных вариантов текста, по одному варианту на язык.
2. Отображение по умолчанию варианта на языке пользователя *(указывать через профиль)* / посетителя *(получать из HTTP-заголовков)*. В случае отсутствия необходимого языкового варианта, либо невозможности определения желаемого языка показывать либо английский, либо исходный вариант.
3. Возможность создания и правки языковых вариантов силами рядовых участников. Подобную деятельность можно поощрять репутацией и знаками.
4. Возможность получения уведомлений о появлении вопросов/ответов/комментариев, которые можно (и необходимо) перевести.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Мертворождённая идея, потому что слишком сложно. Подумайте, как ваша идея взаимодействует с остальными компонентами сайта: коллективная проверка и модерация, геймификация и прочее. Если начнёте расписывать идею во всех деталях, у вас уйдут десятки страниц мелким шрифтом, только чтобы описать всё в общих чертах. Да и банально: кто будет этим заниматься? Посчитайте количество переведённых вопросов, посчитайте переводчиков, прикиньте объём работы.

Ранее обсуждалась идея делать перекрёстные ссылки между сайтами для похожих вопросов, см. [Создание связей между одинаковыми вопросами на разных языках](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/431/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%85). Это уже что-то более реальное, хотя тоже не без потенциальных проблем. К сожалению, похоже, идея подохла. То ли Николас не смог достаточно надавить на манагеров СО, то ли все силы брошены на безумные "документации" и "социалочки", и на реально нужные вещи разрабов не осталось...

Так или иначе, даже гораздо более простая фича осталась нереализованной, поэтому обсуждать радикальное усложнение не имеет смысла.

Comment: [Идея вовсе не умерла](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2768/)!   Некоторое время назад, действительно, было крайне сложно добиться подобных нововведений в следствие большого изменения архитектуры сайта (перенос карьеры, история разработчика, документация и т. д.), но сейчас ассоциация является наиболее приоритетной задачей для международных сообществ. В дополнение, появился выделенный сотрудник, который ответственен за реальное выделение ресурсов для  подобных инициатив.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky О, отличные новости! Из-за туманного заголовка и объёмного мотивирующего вступления прозевал тот пост. :)) Непонятно, что на данной стадии требуется. Вижу огромное количество вопросов — с ними что-то делать надо?

Comment: Сейчас мы находимся на стадии сбора конкретных идей. Ассоциация вопросов – это лишь общая мысль, и нам необходимо понять, что именно надо и зачем. Яркий тому пример баллы репутации. Кто–то за, кто–то против, понять можно только начав переводить по несколько вопросов день. Хотелось бы, чтоб бы участники представили, что функционал уже есть, и попробовали использовать его так, как именно они его видят, а затем, поделились опытом и идеями [на Мете](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2768/). Как минимум, это то, что делаю я время от времени :)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Добавил там свои мысли. Кстати, с каких пор перекрёстные ссылки стали исключительно для переводов, причём сильно похожих? Я думал, что будут ассоциироваться все похожие посты. Например, от большого SO отпочковалось много узких тематик, и местами тоже есть пересечения. Или эту проблему уже не решаем?

Comment: Спасибо! Нет, не только для переводов. Просто я решил начать с них. Как мне кажется, основная проблема, которую мы решаем – попробовать улучшить понимание материала (да и вообще, заинтересованность в нем) коллегами за счет предоставление информации на первом языке. К примеру, если русскоязычный специалист попадает из поиска на Stack Overflow на английском, и мы знаем, что на русском есть аналогичный _отвеченный_ вопрос, мы можем предложить его пользователю. То есть я думаю о связи «один к одному».