# Stack Overflow на русском на HighLoad++

Tags: обсуждение

2-го и 3-го ноября в Москве пройдет HighLoad++, на котором вы сможете найти наш стенд. Также на конференции выступит один из сотрудников Stack Overflow, [Marco Cecconi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7028/sklivvz), который расскажет про производительность серверов Stack Exchange.

Пожалуйста, если вы будете на конференции, найдите стенд Stack Overflow и задайте мне или Марко любой вопрос о Stack Overflow!

Если вы не планируете посещать HighLoad++, буду рад увидеть вас в субботу 31 октября или в воскресенье 1 ноября в Москве. Если у вас есть любой вопрос касающийся сообщества или работы сайтов и у вас есть несколько свободных часов в субботу или воскресенья, пожалуйста, напишите мне на nicolas.chabanovsky@stackoverflow.com и мы обязательно встретимся для общения.

Буду рад вас видеть!

Comment: Думаю, стоит отдельно анонсировать встречу сообщества в Москве, если вы готовы встретиться просто так.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Это не встреча сообщества, которую я бы с удовольствием посетил. Это просто возможность для неформальной встречи для того, чтобы задать имеющиеся вопросы. Если наберется какое-то количество желающих задать вопрос Марко, я бы постарался вытащить его в центр города для «очной ставки».

Comment: расскажете, как прошло мероприятие?

Answer (score 5):

Конференция HighLoad++ получила достаточно много внимания – ее посетило порядка двух тысяч человек. У меня нет личного опыта присутствия на лекциях, но исходя из того, что коллеги говорили мне при встречи в перерывах, конференция была весьма интересная.

Наше сообщество было представлено на конференции стендом, где я рассказывал про  Stack Overflow на русском и его пользу для русскоязычных разработчиков программного обеспечения, а также отвечал на вопросы про другие сайты сети Stack Exchange.

[image]

<sup>Второй день. Сувениры закончились в течение нескольких часов первого дня конференции.</sup>

Стенд задумывался для поддержки выступления [Marco Cecconi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7028/sklivvz), то есть чтобы участники конференции могли задать вопрос про архитектуру решений компании дополнительно, после выступления, а также для ответов на вопросы про русскоязычное сообщество. Вопросов было много, и далеко не всегда хватало времени дать развернутый ответ. Чтобы вопросы не пропали мы организовали офисный мольберт (он же «[флипчарт](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82)»), где каждый желающий мог написать свой вопрос. Я постараюсь собрать и опубликовать ответы на заданные в письменном виде вопросы в отдельной публикации на Мете. Помимо вопросов ко мне или Марко, на стенде можно было взять различные сувениры (ручки, наклейки, футболки) или угоститься сладостями.

Моя личная задача сводилась к выявлению проблем сообщества, то есть поиска ответа на вопрос «есть ли что-то, что не дает сообществу расти?». HighLoad++, в этом плане, приятно удивил. Думаю, для многих не секрет, что в прошлом было достаточно людей, которые знали про Stack Overflow и миссию проекта, но пренебрежительно относились к русскоязычному сообществу программистов (вообще, не только к Stack Overflow на русском). На конференции я пообщался с несколькими сотнями ребят и девушек и только единицы задавались вопросом целесообразности Stack Overflow на русском! Более того, удовлетворенность принятия участия в русскоязычном сообществе была ничуть не меньше чем в англоязычном для тех, кто задает вопросы или читает их на обоих сайтах! Данный факт не может не радовать – шаг за шагом своим примером мы меняем мнение людей о русскоязычном сообществе разработчиков, да и вообще, о профессиональном общении в Рунете! *Спасибо, коллеги!*

Наиболее часто ко мне подходили чтобы:

- сказать спасибо компании и сообществу за собранную базу знаний!
- поинтересоваться, действительно ли существует Stack Overflow на русском;
- уточнить, есть ли [функционал объединения одинаковых вопросов на разных языках](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347/) ([см. также](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/431/));
- взять наклейку.

По результатам конференции, можно сделать вывод, что одна из наиболее критичных проблем для сообщества на данный момент заключается в том, что далеко не все наши коллеги знают про Stack Overflow на русском. На мой взгляд, единственный верный способ исправить этот недочет – рекомендовать окружающим нас коллегам задавать вопросы на сайте, каждый раз когда кто-либо задает вопрос в устном виде. Я искренне верю в пользу профессионального общения не только в контексте создаваемых знаний, но и в контексте получения [навыков постановки проблемы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%83%D1%82%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0)!

Ниже представлен список вопросов заданных на конференции на офисном мольберте.

1. Переводятся ли лучшие вопросы и ответы с других языков? Если да, то автоматически или знатоками?
2. Зависит ли язык ресурса от настроек поиска Google, Яндекс и других?
3. Как в Stack Overflow осуществляется развертывание сборки на Windows-машинах?
4. Как набрать начальный рейтинг?
5. Оркестровка в Docker, мониторинг DevOps.
6. Как эффективнее всего поднять свою репутацию?
7. Сколько русскоязычных участников на Stack Overflow?
8. Как работает полнотекстовый поиск на сайте?
9. Как быстро найти вопрос, на который можно ответить?
10. Если нет ответов (и/или вопросов) на русском языке стоит ли переводить тему полностью или частично из англоязычного сообщества?
11. Зачем нужен Stack Overflow на русском?
12. Каков процент не русскоговорящих посетителей на Stack Overflow на русском?
13. Будет ли автоматический перевод с русского на английский и наоборот и есть ли планы привлекать переводчиков?
14. Каковы основные каналы монетизации в России?
15. Каков алгоритм отображения вакансий в боковой панели сайта?
16. Где взять наклейки?
17. Используется ли стандартный сборщик мусора или есть собственное решение?
18. Как построен процесс проверки кода (он же «Code Review»)?
19. Какие инструменты используются для развертывания?
20. Используются ли какие-то решения для оптимизации в странах с низкой доступностью? (Исходный вопрос «client-side latency for bad cases like in CN or India?».)
21. Zero Downtime и DB
22. Как выглядит архитектура Stack Overflow в двух словах и трех картинках?
23. Пишутся ли Micro BenchMarks и как это делать правильно? Как в этом случае обстоят дела с GC, какие таймеры используются?
24. Делается ли оптимизация программного обеспечения Stack Exchange под конкретное железо? Если делается, то кем?
25. Где взять презентацию Марко?
26. Почему было принято решение использовать .NET?
27. Как происходит процесс отрисовки клиентской части? Только Razor?
28. Почему GC умирает от длинной цепочки репозиториев?
29. Как получается избежать коллизий, в случае если одновременно развертывание делает два и более разработчика, в контексте модели развертки и управления принятой в компании?
30. На чем работают тесты для dev.so?
31. Какими инструментами измеряется производительность?
32. Будет ли реализован перенос базы Stack Overflow на русском и на английском в одно место?
33. Есть ли какие-либо проблемы с производительностью MS SQL Server? Планируется ли переход на No-SQL базу данных?

Comment: _Как эффективнее всего поднять свою репутацию?_ — [Своим ходом, год за годом](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bY8ASMpugq8#t=58m09).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, таак, а ответы-то где? :) мой вот 18-ый как раз.

Comment: @DmitryV. Ответы пока еще не написал. Тут есть важный момент – я не смогу ответить на большенство технических вопросов. Не так давно я переадресовал их [@Sklivvz](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7028/sklivvz), но ответ еще не получил. На неделе планирую начать писать ответы на организационные вопросы.