# Повысим интерес коллег к работе с помощью знаний!

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, ассоциация-вопросов

Нам всем не нравятся невнятные вопросы от коллег. Зачастую мы не хотим быть с неинтересующимися профессией коллегами в одной команде в компании и тем более быть частью одного сообщества. На наш взгляд, побороть посредственное отношение к работе можно лишь за счет профессионального роста таких коллег. Заставить их расти силой, конечно же, нельзя, но можно попробовать увлечь за собой.

**Путь к сердцу разработчика лежит через увлекательные технологии, интерес к которым перерастает в программный код.**

Возможно, низкая заинтересованность в профессии является следствием отсутствия необходимого источника информации, из которого можно было бы черпать интерес к делу жизни.

#### Что можно сделать?

Предоставить неувлеченным профессией коллегам качественный источник знаний, тем самым повысить их заинтересованность в работе, чтобы иметь возможность расти самим в правильном окружении.

#### Возможные решения

1. **Вопросы с собственными ответами от участников сообщества**. Крайне важны конечные знания, которые мы создаем для наших коллег в процессе своего обучения. Это могут быть как заметки, собранные во время изучения технологии, так и просто интересные моменты, возникшие во время профессиональной деятельности.
2. **Источник на первом языке**. С большой вероятность получение знаний на других языках может оказаться для многих коллег неприятной задачей. Создавая знания на первом языке, мы уменьшаем «порог входа», предоставляя большему количеству людей возможность профессионально расти.

Подобные идеи высказывались уже неоднократно, приобретая различные формы. Мы пришли к выводу, что одним из интересных способов того, как можно решить проблему, является создание механизма ассоциации вопросов между сайтами на разных языках, [предложенный](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347/) [@ReinRaus](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/481/reinraus)  и в последствии [раскрытый более подробно сообществом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/431/).

Ассоциация вопросов между сайтами улучшит каталогизацию знаний. Что даст возможность предоставлять более релевантную информацию пользователю, попавшему на страницу вопроса, например, из поисковика.

Самое время это проверить!

#### Какие стадии мы видим?

1. **Сбор идей**. Было бы крайне интересно рассмотреть способы использования будущего функционала. Как мы, реальные участники, это видим? Каковы механики? Что является критичным, а что можно добавить в более поздних версиях?
2. **Обсуждение опыта использования**. Поняв, как мы, сообщество, видим оптимальный опыт использования и конечные цели функционала, мы сможем формализовать идеи на Мете.
3. **Формирование вопроса с предложением реализации «минимального целесообразного продукта»**. Из всех функций мы вместе выберем минимальный набор и передадим в реализацию.
4. **Улучшение**. Получив первую версию, мы сможем начать ей пользоваться и вносить улучшающие изменения.

#### Большие дела делаются маленькими шагами

Это первое значимое улучшение движка сайта вопросов и ответов от международного сообщества.

Но поздравления будут позже, после реализации!

---

Сбор идей продлится месяц, до конца апреля. Замечания и предложения можно публиковать в ответ на этот вопрос.

Часть идей для проверки собраны в публикации: «[Создание связей между одинаковыми вопросами на разных языках](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/431/)».

Comment: Что такое "первый язык"?

Comment: @andreycha Подразумевался «родной» язык, но у некоторых людей родных языков несколько. Я понимаю под первым языком тот, на котором человеку проще говорить, на котором он/она предпочитает общаться, если есть выбор.

Comment: Рад, что эта тема обрела второе рождение.

Answer (score 7):

## Перевод содержимого

Каким образом будет выглядеть ассоциация вопросов между сайтами в случаях, когда на одном из сайтов есть интересный вопрос с ответом, а на других нет. Необходимо исследовать этот момент за счет переводов интересных вопросов с английского языка на русский и публикации их на сайте.

#### Вопросы исследования

- Что движет участником, когда он переводит вопрос?
- Какой функционал может потребоваться?
- Каким образом упростить (например, автоматизировать правильную атрибуцию) процесс?
- Есть ли смысл в инструментах вроде глоссария?
- Как проверить достоверность перевода?
- В каких случаях перевод недопустим?
- Какие ограничения к вопросам и ответам должны быть для написания переводов?

#### Список переведенных вопросов

- «[Что такое stack trace и как с его помощью находить ошибки при разработке приложений?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510755/)»;
- «[Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085/)»;
- «[Каким образом избежать SQL-инъекций в PHP?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511895/)»;
- «[В чем различия между INNER JOIN и OUTER JOIN?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512193/)»;
- «[Как создать HTML-кнопку, которая будет вести себя, как гиперссылка?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512862/)»;
- «[Как получить выбранное значение в выпадающем списке с помощью JavaScript?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/513017/)»;
- [Как принудительно перезаписать локальные файлы во время git pull?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/515435/).
- [Установка свойства “checked” в флаговой кнопке с помощью jQuery](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/517241/6).
- [Получение кода ветки на удаленном сервере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/516889/6)
- [Как закрыть, перезагрузить и завершить сеанс Windows с помощью bat-файла?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/517684/6).
- [Как выглядит конструкция IF…THEN в SQL SELECT?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/518064/)
- [Как включить файл JavaScript в другой файл JavaScript?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/518486/)
- [Как использовать Git для контроля версий в Unity3D?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/519283/6).
- [Как подготовить проект Unity для git?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/519562/)
- [Как преобразовать int в QString?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/519913/)

#### Результат исследования

<sub>Замечания и мысли, которые показались актуальными во время поиска вопросов для перевода и, собственно, перевода.</sub>

<sub>Популярность – это показатель интереса сообщества, то есть количество просмотров, голоса за и количество ответов.</sub>

- Далеко не все популярные вопросы со Stack Overflow на английском популярны на Stack Overflow на русском.
- На очень простые вопросы на Stack Overflow на английском зачастую дается более одного ответа. На Stack Overflow на русском обычно ограничиваются одним.
- Часто на Stack Overflow на русском уже есть такой же вопрос (либо вопрос отражающий суть), но он плохо задан/плохо оформлен/плохо сформулирован.
- Бывает, что на Stack Overflow на русском есть подробный ответ, но не такой развернутый как на Stack Overflow на английском.

  - Необходим процесс, регламентирующий возможность и правомочность внесения правки от ассоциирующего участника.
  - Нужна ли ссылка на оригинал в этом случае?
- На Stack Overflow на русском встречаются неполные переводы завершающиеся ссылкой на Stack Overflow на английском.
- Часто встречаются вопросы/ответы, в которых совершенно по–разному говорится об одном и том же. Являются ли они ассоциируемыми?
- Встречаются несколько альтернатив для ассоциации. Как выбрать правильную?
- Возможно, стоит предлагать улучшать вопросы/ответы при добавлении ассоциации.
- Скорее всего, было бы здорово получать баллы за перевод (ассоциацию) и в то–же время разрешить коллективную правку. Некоторые участники будут рады дополнить перевод своими знаниями.
- Нужна ли атрибуция переводов вообще? Особенно в случае общих вопросов.
- Как обрабатывать изменения (например, правку) ассоциированного вопроса/ответа?
- Некоторые переводы получаются компиляцией нескольких ответов. Какая атрибуция должна быть в этом случае?
- Складывается ощущение, что количество переводов (как минимум авторских) следует как–то ограничивать: 1) по количеству в день, 2) в пропорции от сообщений не переводов.
- Должны ли быть одинаковые метки у переводов/вопросов–ассоциаций?
- Если публиковать сразу вопрос с ответом, то может потеряться шарм ответов. То есть мы копируем опыт, но именно за реальный опыт так ценят Stack Overflow! Плюс, набор вопросов – это репрезентация знаний и интересов сообщества. Возможно, копируя мы вводим сами себя в заблуждение.

#### Результат исследования от Discord

Так как я уже перевёл несколько вопросов, то выскажусь.

Мотивация при написании перевода та же самая, что и при написании оригинального ответа, а эту тему уже обсосали со всех сторон, поэтому необходимости обсуждать это не вижу.

Минимальный функционал — чтобы можно было добавить ссылку и получить её в блоке со ссылками справа. Подключать сообщество к модерированию — слишком объёмная и сложная задача, поэтому на первых порах лучше дать голый модераторский инструмент (10К) со списком изменений в перекрёстных ссылках и поставить порог для добавления ссылок достаточно высоко (1К на обоих сайтах), чтобы оценить объём желающих поучаствовать, при этом избежать цунами немодерируемого контента. Ну и ромбам дать право запрещать добавлять ссылки. Соответственно, модераторский инструмент — тоже часть MVP.

Автоматизация добавления ссылок — это не то, чем СО может гордиться. На данный момент гораздо более важный инструмент — поиск дубликатов — ущербен до безобразия, им пользоваться абсолютно невозможно, и с этим годами ничего не делается. Поэтому нечего фантазировать, можно использовать тот же самый ущербный диалог ввода ссылки на вопрос, что и при закрытии как дубликата. И если возникнут позывы сделать диалог хоть немного полезным, то начать следует с дубликатов опять же. Короче, не усложняем раньше времени.

Глоссарий — ненаучная фантастика. У современных *профессиональных переводов книг* разброд и шатание, перевод самого СО сделать по-нормальному не смогли, поэтому рассчитывать, что сообщество будет сверяться с каким-то глоссарием — по меньшей мере наивно. Скажем так, если кто-то умеет переводить, то он знает, где и какие есть словари. Если не умеет, то словари ему не помогут. Если хочется сделать что-то полезное, то можно в справке сделать страничку со списком уже существующих словарей: мультитран, майкрософтовский и т. п. Это ортогонально разработке фичи.

Всякие проверки качества, ограничения и прочее мне видятся очень затруднительными, потому что количество двуязычных пользователей, которые активны на двух сайтах, причём в модераторской роли — ничтожно. Остаётся понадеяться на авось и традиционные инструменты, в том числе коллективную правку содержимого. Если что-то не сразу высокого качества получилось, то есть надежда, что в конце концов эволюционирует.

Теперь к заметкам Николаса.

- *Далеко не все популярные вопросы со Stack Overflow на английском популярны на Stack Overflow на русском.* — Это не проблема. Получение просмотров, оценок и прочего на СО — это всегда рулетка. Ничего не меняется.
- *Часто на Stack Overflow на русском уже есть такой же вопрос (либо вопрос отражающий суть), но он плохо задан/плохо оформлен/плохо сформулирован.* — По-моему, сложилась традиция не изменять что-то имеющееся до неузнаваемости, а писать с нуля в нормальном виде. Если какой-то сносный вопрос уже есть, автор вопроса куда-то пропал, а в ответах всё релевантно, то уже есть варианты.
- *Необходим процесс, регламентирующий возможность и правомочность внесения правки от ассоциирующего участника.* — Не понял.
- *Нужна ли ссылка на оригинал в этом случае?* — Не изобретаем ничего нового, полагаемся на лицензию и здравый смысл. Если что-то позаимствовано в ощутимом объёме, то ссылка нужна, просто без намёка, что там что-то идентичное. Перекрётсные ссылки — вообще про релевантность, а не про идентичность.
- *Часто встречаются вопросы/ответы, в которых совершенно по–разному говорится об одном и том же. Являются ли они ассоциируемыми?* — Как мне видится, общая логика такая: если ответ на вопрос интересен для нашедшего вопрос на другом языке, то ссылка будет плюсом. Не надо вводить всяких условностей с "точным переводом", это никогда не будет работать и только спровоцирует флейм. Есть ответ, но на другом языке — добавляем ссылку. Всё.
- *Встречаются несколько альтернатив для ассоциации. Как выбрать правильную?* — Сослаться на все. 5 ссылок, 2 из которых бесполезны — хуже, чем 1 ссылка и 2 пропущенные. Можно сделать сортировку по оценке в качестве сносного костыля, если есть опасения о плохом SNR. Если альтернативы реально про одно и то же, то отправить флаг модератору, конечно — процедура аналогична процедуре с дубликатами.
- *Скорее всего, было бы здорово получать баллы за перевод (ассоциацию) и в то–же время разрешить коллективную правку.* — Не надо мудрить. Обычной репы за ответы и вопросы более, чем достаточно. Если перемудрить с мотивацией, можно нарваться на спам. И вспомним про дубликаты — за закрытие репу не дают. До того, как это будет исправлено, считаю, что что мотивирование перекрёстных ссылок обсуждать неприлично.
- *Как обрабатывать изменения (например, правку) ассоциированного вопроса/ответа?* — Да никак. Пусть каждый живёт своей жизнью. Участников не заставить идеально синхронизировать варианты.
- *Должны ли быть одинаковые метки у переводов/вопросов–ассоциаций?* — Общей системы меток нет и вряд ли будет, поэтому нет. Невозможно. Даже в рамках одного сайта с метками чехарда.

Comment: У меня есть свой личный epic quest - перевести сотню топовых вопросов по любимой метке. Как вернусь к нему - что-нибудь напишу тут. )

Answer (score 3):

## Ассоциация вопросов

Каким образом будет выглядеть поиск и назначение ассоциации вопросов между сайтами? Необходимо исследовать, каким образом можно искать одинаковые вопросы на сайтах, как назначать ассоциацию и каким образом проверять её достоверность.

#### Вопросы исследования

- Какими привилегиями и репутацией должен обладать участник? В каких сообществах?
- Кому следует показывать аналогичные вопросы на других языках?
- Какие языки должны иметь перекрестные ссылки?
- Можно ли будет добавлять пересекающиеся ссылки между сообществами разных тематик?
- В каком месте следует отображать ссылки на аналогичные вопросы?
- Какие ограничения к вопросам и ответам должны быть для добавления ссылок?
- Необходима ли проверка назначения вопросов аналогичными со стороны сообщества?

#### Результаты исследования

<sub>Временно пусто.</sub>