# Повысим интерес коллег к работе с помощью знаний: ассоциация вопросов

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, ассоциация-вопросов

### Результаты [предыдущей публикации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2768/)

> **Коротко**.
>   Никаких тонн переводов. Только улучшение структуры базы знаний.

Обдумывая ваши отзывы и результаты проведенного исследования, мы пришли к выводу, что ни сообщество, ни команда разработчиков не считают необходимым делать акцент на переводе содержимого. Мы вместе хотим лишь улучшить каталогизацию знаний с учетом разных языков.

Перевод содержимого на языки, отличные от английского, нужен и важен, но только вкупе со специалистами, которые могут его использовать, ведь Stack Overflow – это отражение интересов и знаний сообщества разработчиков в пространстве языка.

Пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь публиковать свои заметки или переводы в виде «вопроса с ответом», которые могут появляться у вас в процессе изучения новых технологий. Уверен, сообщество будет благодарно вам за это!

### Текущее положение дел

Мы считаем, что перевод вопросов – прекрасная индивидуальна инициатива, но не задача сообщества. Сообщество ответственно лишь за поддержку и накопление своей базы знаний.

#### Конечная цель каталогизации – предоставление наиболее полезной информации

Большинство разработчиков попадает на Stack Overflow из поисковика, когда ищет решение конкретной проблемы. Для поисковиков любой сайт Stack Exchange является «конкурентом» за место в выдаче. Так, выполняя запрос, например, по коду ошибки на английском языке, поисковик может отдать предпочтение Stack Overflow на английском, не беря в расчет уровень владения языком разработчиком. Можно говорить, что Stack Overflow на английском является «точкой входа» для большинства пользователей всей сети Stack Exchange.

В то же время на Stack Overflow на других языка существует немало примеров крайне качественных ответов (например, [Подсветка ключевых слов в TextBlock или RichTextBox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/421031/) и 
[Highlight text in RichTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5685644/1299307)), которые помогли бы разработчику не только решить поставленную задачу эффективнее, но и глубже понять изложенный материал, что, например, подтверждают данные Google Analytics за март 2016 года: пользователи, получающие информацию на первом языке, с большей вероятностью примут активное участие в решении проблемы (и создании знаний), чем те, которые получают ее на иностранном языке, – разработчики, использующие Stack Overflow на русском, задают вопросы в два раза чаще и публикуют ответы в четыре раза чаще, чем их коллеги на Stack Overflow на английском, с установленным русским языком в обозревателе.

#### Полезная информация в зависимости от первого языка, а не домена

Имея связи между вопросами на разных сайтах в отношении «один к одному» и зная предпочитаемый язык пользователя (например, определяя его по языку обозревателя), мы сможем предоставлять пользователю лучшую информацию из имеющейся.

Данная функция создается для пользователей, чей первый язык не является английским и кто хочет получать знания в сообществе, среди квалифицированных коллег.

Идеологически ассоциация вопросов аналогична процедуре назначения дубликатов (закрытию вопроса как дубликат): ассоциируя вопросы, мы говорим, что вся полезная информация, относящаяся к конкретной проблеме, хранится и постоянно пополняется в одном месте.

#### Ключевые особенности

Исходя из проведенного исследования, мы считаем, что ассоциация вопросов должна иметь следующие особенности:

- Ассоциация вопросов происходит по принципу «один к одному».
- Участники предлагают ассоциации вручную. (Возможно, существует какой-либо демон на сервере, который может самостоятельно находить и предлагать ассоциации.)
- Все предложенные ассоциации проверяются сообществом через очередь проверок.
- Очередь проверок ассоциаций существует только на сайтах с отличным от английского языком.
- Ответы ассоциированных вопросов, которые требуют улучшения, попадают в очередь на улучшение.
- Ассоциация может быть отменена.
- Ассоциация возможна только между Stack Overflow на английском и Stack Overflow на другом языке.

Пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь критиковать и предлагать свои решения!

#### Открытые вопросы

Как нам кажется, существует несколько особенностей ассоциации, которые невозможно спроектировать без участия сообщества! Пожалуйста, поделитесь вашими соображениями по поводу следующих открытых вопросов:

1. *Как должен выглядеть интерфейс вопроса, имеющего ассоциацию?* На Stack Overflow английском, на международном Stack Overflow.
2. *Какие инструменты для назначения ассоциации следует добавить?*
3. *Как выглядит «точка входа» для механизма ассоциации?* К примеру, для назначения дубликата существует специальная панель, которая появляется, если нажать на «закрыть» и выбрать соответствующую причину. *Как будет происходить поиск и назначение ассоциаций?*  Как бы вы это делали, если бы были:

   - автором вопроса;
   - автором ответа;
   - участником сообщества, который поддерживает качество базы знаний.

С нетерпением ждем ваших идей, предложений и замечаний!

Comment: *Ассоциация вопросов происходит по принципу «один к одному»* и *Ассоциация возможна только между Stack Overflow на английском и Stack Overflow на другом языке* — почему это?

Comment: Существуют единицы русскоязычных разработчиков, кого может заинтересовать решение на японском. Но главная причина в том, что именно Stack Overflow на английском является «точкой входа»/«посадочным сайтом» в систему сайтов. Русскоязычный пользователь весьма вероятно может на него попасть и ему/ей может быть полезна информация на русском языке. Если разработчики ищет на японском, информация на русском ему будет вряд ли полезна.

Comment: На SO в первую очередь важен код, который можно проанализировать, не понимая описания. Да и познания языка не так уж сильно требуются: чтобы понять суть написанного, достаточно Google Translate. Далеко не все связанные вопросы — портянки текста, где-то просто предоставлены разные решения одной задачи. И вообще, я не про локализованные сайты, а про зоопарк IT-сайтов: нередко случается, что разные решения валяются на разных сайтах. / И почему 1 к 1? Вы уверены, что не возникнет споров, какая перекрёстная ссылка точнее?

Comment: @Discord Если на одном сайте есть одинаковые вопросы, все кроме одного должны быть закрыты как дубликаты. Если вопросы примерно об одном, есть связанные вопросы. Поэтому, связь 1:1.

Comment: Вот как вижу я... Все что Вы предложите будет полной ерундой и пользы будет ноль. Вот Вы сделаете каталог, который будет состоять из каких-то отрывков (не факт что вообще правильных) и это будет выглядеть так, как-будто одну статью писали несколько авторов, которые даже не общались и не обдумывали план изложения информации. Короче мартышкин труд + таскать воду в решете.  

Как бы сделал я будь у меня возможность. Сделал тупо документацию по каждему языку. Пришел кто-то спросить как сделать сортировку массива, ему дали ответ, а активисты взяли и скопировали куски кода в хелп. продолжу..

Comment: И так нужно сделать хелп для каждой отдельной библиотеке. За идеал могу предложить хелп as3, реально лучше просто невозможно представить.

Comment: @vas _Все что Вы предложите будет полной ерундой и пользы будет ноль. _ Буду крайне вам признателен за более конструктивную критику. Пожалуйста, подскажите, что именно, по вашему мнению, не будет работать и почему? _Сделал тупо документацию по каждему языку._ - Пожалуйста, обратите внимание [на статью](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1247/) про новый раздел «документацию».

Comment: Касаемо [предлагаемого](https://github.com/chabanovsky/so_question_association#stack-overflow-in-russian) тега `<assotiation>`: может быть, вместо html-подобного тега имеет смысл ввести 1) новое поле (наподобие списка меток) и 2) новую очередь проверок по ассоциациям?

Answer (score 7):

В дополнение или даже вместо, можно сперва реализовать простейший вариант:  расширить  поддержку ссылок на связанные вопросы с того же сайта до всех Stack Overflow сайтов.

К примеру, если сейчас добавить ссылку на другое сообщение на том же сайте, то она появится в списке «Связанные» в обоих вопросах.

Новая функциональность позволит создавать связи между вопросами не только с одного сайта, но и сайтами на разных языках. Отношение многие ко многим.

---

Связь создаётся простым упоминанием в сообщении или комментарии к нему—без очередей модераторов.  Чтобы принять участие в создании связей не нужно даже знать о существовании специальной поддержки, достаточно естественным образом упоминать вопросы.

Связанные вопросы, сгруппированные по языку локализации, можно всем одинаковые показывать вне зависимости от geoip, настроек локали браузера—как это сейчас происходит (минус группировка по языкам).

Можно поэкспериментировать с выделением группы ссылок на вопросы с выбранным языком:

- никак не выделять
- оставить в правой колонке, но подчеркнуть типографически
- добавить ссылки на связанные вопросы (с выбранным языком) внизу основного вопроса.

---

Уже сейчас  можно упоминать связанные вопросы без специальной поддержки в UI, которая легче локализованные версии позволит находить.
Эта функциональность добавляет чуть-чуть удобства при относительно небольшой сложности реализации и использования.

Comment: Очень–очень крутая идея про расширение разметки для задания ассоциации прямо в теле вопроса. Спасибо!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: *"внизу основного вопроса"* не обязательно означает *"прямо в теле вопроса"*, например, метки находятся внизу вопроса, но не в теле вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

[Покопипастю](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/433) немного, так как реакции на свои предложения я не видел.

> *Как должен выглядеть интерфейс вопроса, имеющего ассоциацию?* На Stack Overflow английском, на международном Stack Overflow.

> 1. Если у юзера есть признаки "локализованности" (IP, Accept-Language, страна в профиле), то показывать первым блоком среди
>      ссылочных:
>
>    - ... Stats, Meta, ads ...
>    - **In other languages**
>    - Linked
>    - Related
>    - ... Hot Ntework Questions ...
> 2. Для всех остальных отображать, но запрятать подальше, чтобы не мешалось:
>
>    - ... Stats, Meta, ads ...
>    - Linked
>    - Related
>    - **In other languages**
>    - ... Hot Ntework Questions ...
>
> На Википедии ссылки отображаются для всех, и этим никто не
>   возмущается. Кстати о Википедии. Можно добавить к ссылкам метки с
>   количеством ответов, плюсов или ещё чего-нибудь. Это касается всех
>   ссылок на посты, не только вновь добавляемых.

---

> *Как выглядит «точка входа» для механизма ассоциации?* К примеру, для назначения дубликата существует специальная панель, которая появляется, если нажать на «закрыть» и выбрать соответствующую причину. *Как будет происходить поиск и назначение ассоциаций?*  Как бы вы это делали, если бы были:
>
> - автором вопроса;
> - автором ответа;
> - участником сообщества, который поддерживает качество базы знаний.

> Вероятно, стоит запихнуть в форму редактирования вопроса. Выделять в отдельную кнопку под постом смысла большого нет, потому что это не будет настолько часто использоваться, да там и без того тесно.
>
> Можно добавить список и кнопку "Добавить перекрёстную ссылку". По нажатию отображать список "родственных сайтов". При выборе сайта — возможность ввести вопрос, как в диалоге выбора дубля.

Comment: Скорее всего, я не верно пояснил текущую задумку. Идея в том, что не будет боковой панели «как на Википедии». Stack Overflow используют для быстрого поиска решений, как результат, смотрят несколько ответов и задают новый вопрос поисковику, если не нашли решение. Как мне кажется, имеет смысл показывать ответы с SOru в вопросе на SOen как обычный ответ, с атрибуцией конечно же.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Свалить ответы на разных языках на необязательно идеально совпадающие вопросы в одну кучу на большом SO? Это безумие. Пользователи не будут понимать, что и откуда отображается, куда какой ответ или комментарий попадает, где и на что какие права; сообщения на разных языках размажутся ровным слоем и хорошенько перемешаются... Я уж молчу, что нередки случаи, когда по заголовкам браузера язык юзера не определяется, то есть это месиво будут лицезреть и невинные жертвы. И в качестве вишенки на торте никто так и не узнает про Ru.SO: зачем он сдался, если всё есть на большом SO?

Comment: Уверен, если все сойдутся во мнение, что отображать ответ напрямую на SOen целесообразно, дизайнеры найдут способ показать, что ответ с другого сайта. Ответы с SOru будут иметь атрибуцию со ссылкой на источник. Комментарии, голосование и т. д. можно отключить на внешнем сайте (то есть необходимо перейти на сайт–источник, чтобы дать уточняющий комментарий, к примеру). Почему именно ответ, а не просто ссылка? Основная задача – предоставлять пользователю лучшую информацию из имеющейся, а не нагнать трафик (для трафика можно и баннеры использовать).

Comment: Ответы на других языках будут показываться только в том случае, если мы будем точно уверены, что пользователь сможет прочитать ответ.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Меня интересуют в первую очередь траффик на Ru.SO, плюсики и обсуждения. Если ответы будут отображаться в режиме read-only, то получается нечто непонятное, что меня мало интересует. *Ответы на других языках будут показываться только в том случае, если мы будем точно уверены, что пользователь сможет прочитать ответ* — Интересно, как? По заголовкам? У меня в настройках браузера стоит английский, я ничего не увижу. А в каком-нибудь публичном компьютере в Японии у браузера будет приоритет на японском, и я увижу японский. Угадывалка уже совершила ошибки обоих типов. :)

Comment: Что касается траффика, то я не наблюдаю ошеломительного эффекта баннеров. Тостер, я так понимаю, до сих пор уделывает СО, а русскоязычных юзеров на большом СО на порядок больше, чем на Ру.СО (кажется, вы числа приводили, не помню значений).