# Предложите ваши вопросы для ассоциации

Tags: обсуждение, ассоциация-вопросов

Ссылка на предыдущие обсуждения: [Повысим интерес коллег к работе с помощью знаний: ассоциация вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2983/)

---

#### Вопрос обновлен.

Для просмотра предыдущей публикации, пожалуйста, смотрите историю правок!

---

#### Обновление

[Согласно предложению](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4507/6), пожалуйста, если вам удобнее добавлять ассоциации через комментарий, используйте следующий формат `ассоциация:ссылка_на_вопрос_на_soen`.

**Используйте именно этот формат «`ассоциация:ссылка`»**. Например, `ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10180765/`.

Время от времени я буду запускать специальный SQL–запрос, который будет находить все вопросы с подобными комментариями на Stack Overflow на русском и добавлять их в ответ к данному вопросу. Если вы будете использовать другой формат, ваши ссылки найти не удастся.

---

В этом вопросе сообщество предлагает ссылки для ассоциации вопросов между сайтами.

**Примерные требования к вопросам**

- Должны быть копии вопросов на обоих сайтах: Stack Overflow на русском и Stack Overflow на английском.
- Ассоциированный вопрос Stack Overflow на русском должен содержать правильный ответ. Отмеченный верным ответ должен быть развернутым, либо в вопросе также должны присутствовать пусть и не принятые, но правильные развернутые ответы.
- Желательно подобрать популярные на Stack Overflow на английском вопросы, чтобы получить максимально большое количество статистики.
- Не рекомендуется брать слишком простые вопросы, например, как сделать CSS–эффект при наведении мыши.

### Обновление: добавляйте ассоциации исключительно через комментарии

Пожалуйста, с настоящего момента добавляйте ассоциации исключительно через комментарии.

Comment: [как я уже говорил](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/3013/23044) связь между вопросами это отношение "многие ко многим", а не "один к одному". Имеет смысл несколько ссылок указывать. Если это усложняет реализацию, и/или имеет ощутимое влияние на производительность, то связи стоит включать вне зависимости от языка, настроенного в браузере (если связь руками прописана, то при поиске решения, знание по какой ссылке пройти важнее языка, на котором она написана (выбор: либо никакого решения, либо пройти по ссылке на незнакомом языке--браузер на лету умеет переводить и просто на код можно глянуть)

Comment: @jfs Как я понимаю, в первой версии реализации разработчики хотят понять, будет ли подобный функционал вообще пользоваться популярностью. [В исходном варианте](https://github.com/chabanovsky/so_question_association) связь один к одному была нужна, чтобы мы могли показывать ответы, например, с SO на русском прямо в вопросе на SO на английском.

Comment: @jfs После тестов, как мне кажется, будет переосмысление функционала в общем. Уверен, связь «многие ко многим» обязательно будет рассматриваться как одна из альтернатив.

Comment: Можно мне сделать отдельную выгрузку только вопросов по метке ansible? Совершенно пустой тег на ru-so.

Comment: @AK Очень сильно сомневаюсь, но я попробую посмотреть модель данных, может что–то получится (очень-очень мало вероятно).

Comment: Требование специального формата в комментарии заметно ухудшают полезность функционала: "ассоциация" это функционал не первого порядка (доля участников, которые об этом знают близка к нулю и нет никаких оснований предполагать, что она может увеличиться), значит связей между вопросами будет значительно меньше, значит меньше шансов что посетители найдут желаемый ответ на русском. Я не понимаю к чему ограничивать связи между вопросами и почему не достаточно простого упоминания как сейчас для вопросов внутри сайта,если вдруг окажется что слишком много связей, тогда ограничения можно было бы вводить

Comment: @jfs Исходная задача сводилась к тому, чтобы показать пользователям, попадающим на сайт из поиска наиболее релевантную информацию, которая у нас есть: если человек ищет особые настройки компилятора и мы знаем, что он понимает русский язык, [почему бы не отобразить ему русскоязычные ответы в англоязычном вопросе](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vb8eC.png)? Многие люди, выполняя поиск в Интернете, скорее быстро копируют код и проверяют его на своем проекте. Для них, чем больше информации, тем лучше.

Comment: В свою очередь, согласно идеи Stack Overflow: «одна заметка формата вопрос–ответ для каждого прикладного вопроса», на сайте не должно существовать дублирующих вопросов. Этим мы достигаем того, что поисковая выдача не забита одним и тем же вопросом. Как результат, идеологически, на двух SO на разных языках не может существовать несколько аналогичных же вопросов. Следующим ключевым моментом наличия лишь одной ассоциации, которая показывается в зависимости от настроек обозревателя, является наличие места для дополнительной информации на странице.

Comment: Представьте, что к вопросу опубликовали по 10 ссылок на «похожие вопросы» на каждом языке и мы статически добавляем их на страницу. Вместе с англоязычными ссылками, которых, представим, тоже 10, будет 50 ссылок. На мой взгляд, в этом никто не будет разбираться, так как проще составить новый поисковой запрос. Мысль о новом поисковом запросе крайне важна. Со стороны движка мы создаем ассоциации 1 к 1 между несколькими базами знаний. Если есть предположение, что пользователь способен воспринять «ассоциацию» на другом языке – мы предлагаем ему это.

Comment: Заметьте, что это дает нам заметное преимущество: если у нас есть дополнительная информация, мы можем это явно подчеркнуть – выделив пусть одну ссылку, но [очень заметно](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vb8eC.png). Информационная гибкость, про которую вы говорите, в этом варианте достигается за счет того, что у пользователя есть возможность задать новый поисковой запрос поисковику.

Comment: я не понимаю, к чему лекция о дубликатах. [С самого первого сообщения](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/3013/23044) я не говорил и не говорю о "похожести" вопросов, а только о **связи** между вопросами: *как уже сейчас функционал работает* внутри одного сайта--единственная новая вещь: добавлять в список не только с одного сайта вопросы, но отслеживать связи между сайтами Stack Overflow на разных языках--всё.  Текущая реализация плоха тем: 1- она требует знания существования фичи (гораздо меньше ассоциаций)  ...

Comment: ...2- требует точные дубликаты искать (непростая задача даже внутри одного языка, если подходить ответственно и знать что делаешь) -- большие усилия опять таки уменьшают количество новых ассоциаций. Достоинство что я предлагаю: 1- связи создаются автоматически и органически (людям не нужно знать о фиче->больше связей) 2- так как ссылки в стороне, то они не мешают людям, которым они не нужны (поэтому их можно показывать ...

Comment: ...вне зависимости от языка пользователя--к тому же если человек по сусекам aka "связанным вопросам" пытается код найти, то можно и на другом языке вопрос показать). Нет проблем [показывать даже сотни связей](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/509211?lq=1)

Comment: @jfs Проблем нет, но какова реальная польза пользователю? Я пробовал искать среди «связанных вопросов» не раз. Мой личны диагноз: эффективней изменить запрос к поисковику. Функционал, о котором вы говорите, никак не конфликтует с ассоциациями. Более того, с большой вероятностью что–то подобное уже есть. К примеру, при запуске SO на русском, [сайт был вручную отфильтрован из горячих вопросов сети](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252518/). Возможно, необходимо лишь чуть-чуть перенастроить движок.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: ради эксперимента, откройте вопросы на английском языке по паре-тройке ассоциаций, которые я ниже предложил (чтобы я понимал вопросы), и пробуйте составить запросы, чтобы найти похожего качества вопросы на русском языке. Результаты сами за себя скажут.

Comment: @jfs Да, наша база знаний меньше, у нас нет многих хороших вопросов. Это большая проблема, согласен.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: без статистики не могу сказать насколько меньше относительно доли русскоязычных программистов (мы это уже обсуждали, результаты не очевидны). Если меньше, то тем больше оснований не игнорировать ссылки, которые люди сами приводят. Аргументы о сборе связанных вопросов *внутри* сайта, ещё сильнее для связей между сайтами.

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky При добавлении новых ссылок система выдает сообщение -- тело имеет максимальную длину 30000 символов, вы ввели 30014. Как я понимаю место в топике ограничено и уже закончилось.

Comment: @Alexandr_T Да, спасибо! Пожалуйста, добавляйте ассоциации через комментарии. Такой способ предпочтительней. Более того, как мне кажется, в будущем нам придется перенести все ассоциации, добавленные в ответ, в комментарии.

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky я и так дублировал - в вопросе-ответе добавлял комментарии - **ассоциация: ссылка** и здесь в таблицу Можно укоротить ссылки в таблице - ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/630695/3d-%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0, оставив только //ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/630695/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Список вопросов

1. Рус: [Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ (возможные причины)](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536546/176217)
   Англ: [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](//stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/3240681)
2. Рус: [Конструкция decltype(auto)](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/563318/176217)
   Англ: [What are some uses of decltype(auto)?](//stackoverflow.com/q/24109737/3240681)
3. Рус: [Что значит * (звёздочка) и ** двойная звёздочка в Питоне?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/594651/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%91%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%91%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%9f%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5)
   Англ: [What does ** (double star) and * (star) do for parameters?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-parameters)
4. Рус: [Как получить часовой пояс на Python](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/135134/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%8f%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python)
   Англ: [Getting computer's UTC offset in Python](//stackoverflow.com/questions/3168096/getting-computers-utc-offset-in-python)
5. Рус: [Перехват сигналов в Python](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/573078/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-python)
   Англ: [Signal handling in multi-threaded Python](//stackoverflow.com/questions/25676835/signal-handling-in-multi-threaded-python)
6. Рус: [Как из Python вывести на Windows-консоль строку в Юникоде?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/141035/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7-python-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-windows-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%ae%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)
   Англ: [Python, Unicode, and the Windows console](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5419/python-unicode-and-the-windows-console)
7. Рус: [Как найти символы из кортежа ('!',',','?') в строке и удалить их?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/437188/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d1%85)
   Англ: [Best way to strip punctuation from a string in Python](//stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python)
8. Рус: [Книги и другие материалы для обучения](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)
   Англ: [What is the single most influential book every programmer should read?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read)
9. Рус: [Python 3 Проверка на дробное число введённое пользователем](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/494591/python-3-%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc)
   Англ: [Extract float/double value](//stackoverflow.com/questions/385558/extract-float-double-value)
10. Рус: [Перенаправление sys.stdout в файл](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/495848/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-sys-stdout-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb)
    Англ: [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python)
11. Рус: [Необходимо вычислить, какое максимальное количество фигур вместится на прямоугольнике. Чем можно реализовать?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512012/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%80-%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb)
    Англ: [Algorithm needed for packing rectangles in a fairly optimal way](//stackoverflow.com/questions/1213394/algorithm-needed-for-packing-rectangles-in-a-fairly-optimal-way)
12. Рус: [Как создать проверку на существование записи?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/517013/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8)
    Англ: [INSERT IF NOT EXISTS ELSE UPDATE?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/3634984/insert-if-not-exists-else-update)
13. Рус: [Как работать с путями c русскими символами?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/527815/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8-c-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)
    Англ: [open file with a unicode filename?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/10180765/open-file-with-a-unicode-filename)
14. Рус: [Присваивание в Python](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/571490/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-python)
    Англ: ["is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](//stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers)
15. Рус: [Прерывание процесса и задержка на исполнение](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/578469/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)
    Англ: [Using module 'subprocess' with timeout](//stackoverflow.com/questions/1191374/using-module-subprocess-with-timeout)
16. Рус: [python 3.5 windows не поддерживает junction point](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/586134/python-3-5-windows-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-junction-point)
    Англ: [Having trouble implementing a readlink() function](//stackoverflow.com/questions/27972776/having-trouble-implementing-a-readlink-function)
17. Рус: [Неявный импорт в python](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/569357/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82-%d0%b2-python)
    Англ: [Why does importing a python module not import nested modules?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/9303179/why-does-importing-a-python-module-not-import-nested-modules)
18. Рус: [Мультизадачность на Python: выполнить две долгие функции одновременно, не блокируя GUI](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/568677/%d0%9c%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80)
    Англ: [Tkinter: How to use threads to preventing main event loop from "freezing"](//stackoverflow.com/questions/16745507/tkinter-how-to-use-threads-to-preventing-main-event-loop-from-freezing)
19. Рус: [Послать сообщение в skype чат используя python](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/524924/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-skype-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8f-python)
    Англ: [need an python script that uses skype4py to send an instant message](//stackoverflow.com/questions/4536146/need-an-python-script-that-uses-skype4py-to-send-an-instant-message)
20. Рус: [Как получить файл (кириллица в имени) с FTP?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/523015/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d1%81-ftp)
    Англ: [Python: Reading Ftp file list with UTF-8?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/29523067/python-reading-ftp-file-list-with-utf-8)
21. Рус: [Как можно получить данные из сертификата .crt?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/463655/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0-crt)
    Англ: [Simple DER Cert Parsing in python](//stackoverflow.com/questions/18806962/simple-der-cert-parsing-in-python)
22. Рус: [Найти суммарный размер всех регулярных файлов в каталоге, рекурсивно обходя все подкаталоги](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/461105/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%85-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5)
    Англ: [Calculating a directory size using Python?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/1392413/calculating-a-directory-size-using-python)
23. Рус: [Запустить программу с измененным именем процесса](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/385246/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0)
    Англ: [How to change argv0 in bash so command shows up with different name in ps?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/3251550/how-to-change-argv0-in-bash-so-command-shows-up-with-different-name-in-ps)
24. Рус: [Воспроизведение музыки формата Flac в python](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/384804/%d0%92%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0-flac-%d0%b2-python)
    Англ: [Playing audio file with Python](//stackoverflow.com/questions/7578238/playing-audio-file-with-python)
25. Рус: [Как проверить существование файла?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/414593/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0)
    Англ: [How do I check whether a file exists using Python?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-do-i-check-whether-a-file-exists-using-python)
26. Рус: [Текущая директория в Python](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535318/%d0%a2%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-python)
    Англ: [Find current directory and file's directory](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-current-directory-and-files-directory)
27. Рус: [Почему нельзя просто взять и сложить два словаря?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431760/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%b7%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8f)
    Англ: [How to merge two Python dictionaries in a single expression?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)
28. Рус: [Вывод файлов с определённым расширением](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/295845/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc)
    Англ: [Find all files in directory with extension .txt in Python](//stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python)
29. Рус: [Как в bash-конвейере использовать вывод из python сразу?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/138185/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-bash-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b8%d0%b7-python-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83)
    Англ: [How to flush output of Python print?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print)
30. Рус: [Чем отличается **repr** от **str**?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/534440/%d0%a7%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-repr-%d0%be%d1%82-str)
    Англ: [Difference between **str** and **repr** in Python](//stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python)
31. Рус: [Преобразование даты между строковыми представлениями](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/419321/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8)
    Англ: [Parse date string and change format](//stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-string-and-change-format)
32. Рус: [Считывание с изменяющегося файла](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/569677/%d0%a1%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0)
    Англ: [How can I tail a log file in Python?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/12523044/how-can-i-tail-a-log-file-in-python)
33. Рус: [Рандомные числа в Python 3: выбирать рандомные значения из массива целых чисел до тех пор, пока эти значения не кончатся](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/585020/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-python-3-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d0%b4)
    Англ: [What is the most pythonic way to pop a random element from a list?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/10048069/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-pop-a-random-element-from-a-list)
34. Рус: [Разделяй и властвуй: подсчет количества инверсий в массиве](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/375825/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b9-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5)
    Англ: [Minimum number of swaps needed to change Array 1 to Array 2?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/2987605/minimum-number-of-swaps-needed-to-change-array-1-to-array-2)
35. Рус: [Как работает self в Ruby?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/548266/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-self-%D0%B2-ruby)
    Англ: [Use of Ruby self keyword?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/6669527/use-of-ruby-self-keyword)
36. Рус: [Наследование от функции](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/517424/178988)
    Англ: [How to extend Function with ES6 classes?](//stackoverflow.com/q/36871299/4928642)
37. Рус: [В чем разница между git add ., add -A, add -u и add *?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431839/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-git-add-add-a-add-u-%D0%B8-add)
    Англ: [Difference between “git add -A” and “git add .”](//stackoverflow.com/questions/572549/difference-between-git-add-a-and-git-add)
38. Рус: [foreach() для enum](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/12401/foreach-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-enum)
    Англ: [How do I enumerate an enum?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/105372/how-do-i-enumerate-an-enum)
39. Рус: [Что значит “use strict”?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/435546/208074)
    Англ: [What does “use strict” do in JavaScript, and what is the reasoning behind it?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1335851/2553424)
40. Рус: [Как узнать, как настроены на push/pull локальные ветки?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/609292/)
    Англ: [how do I get git to show me which branches are tracking what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950725/how-do-i-get-git-to-show-me-which-branches-are-tracking-what)
41. Рус: [Как вернуться (откатиться) к более раннему коммиту?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431520/)
    Англ: [How to undo last commit(s) in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/)
42. Рус: [Как создать выпадающий список из enum'а в ASP.NET MVC?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/611959/)
    Англ: [How do you create a dropdownlist from an enum in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388483/)
43. Рус: [Как задать data-* атрибут в строго типизированном хелпере asp.net mvc](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/610911/)
    Англ: [ASP.NET MVC Adding Attribute “data-message” to Html.TextBoxFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19596232/)
44. Рус: [Как создать папку на другом сервере при помощи ansible?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609260/)
    Англ: [How to create a directory using Ansible?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/22844905/how-to-create-a-directory-using-ansible)
45. Рус: [Как работает текст «Залго»?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/612002/)
    Англ: [How does Zalgo text work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579844/)
46. Рус: [Ошибка 404 в ответе cURL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560138/)
    Англ: [Easy way to test a URL for 404 in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408405/)
47. Рус: [Как поменять свойство Application Name у TADOConnection в Delphi?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/589451/)
    Англ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40528195/
48. Рус: [Как добавлять задачи в OTL, чтобы они обрабатывались LIFO, а не FIFO?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/524851/)
    Англ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37293575/
49. Рус: [Как подвинуть график в Excel на определенную ячейку?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536031/)
    Англ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37877951/
50. Рус: [Как избежать удаления функции _start при межмодульной оптимизации?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/612588/208074)
    Англ: [Prevent __start entry point from being optimized out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39556307/2553424)
51. Рус: [Анимация кругового прелоадера](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/625282/)
    Англ: [Circle loading animation](//stackoverflow.com/questions/31247310/circle-loading-animation/)
52. Рус: [Пользовательский прогресс-бар](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/627171/)
    Англ: [Custom shape progress bar](//stackoverflow.com/questions/27051337/custom-shape-progress-bar/27054259/)
53. Рус [3D Transform по окружности вокруг оси Х](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/628419/3d-transform-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%A5/)
    Англ: [3D Transform around circle on the X axis](//stackoverflow.com/questions/37929882/3d-transform-around-circle-on-the-x-axis/37941155#37941155/)
54. Рус [Прозрачное зачеркивание текста](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/629089/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0/)
    Англ: [transparent strikethrought on text](//stackoverflow.com/questions/24082524/transparent-strikethrought-on-text/24083227#24083227/)
55. Рус [Круговой процентный прогресс бар](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/628297/%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80/)
    Англ: [Circular percent progress bar](//stackoverflow.com/questions/29350504/circular-percent-progress-bar/29512804#29512804/)
56. Рус [CSS радиальное меню](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/628807/)
    Англ: [CSS radial menu](//stackoverflow.com/questions/29104809/css-radial-menu/29231413#29231413/)
57. Рус: [Вставить текст в border CSS HTML](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/629346/%D0%92%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B2-border-css-html/)
    Англ: [Insert text in border CSS HTML](//stackoverflow.com/questions/30164342/insert-text-in-border-css-html/30164520#30164520/)
58. Рус: [Вращение текста вокруг оси Y](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/629393/)
    Англ: [Rotate text on th Y axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39878213/rotate-text-on-th-y-axis/39878486#39878486/)
59. Рус: [Круговой прогресс бар](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/628257/%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80)
    Англ: [Circle border progress bar](//stackoverflow.com/questions/41586078/circle-border-progress-bar/41586345#41586345/)
60. Рус [Разделить фоновое изображение с 3D эффектом толщины](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/628851/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81-3d-%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B/)
    Англ: [Split background image with 3D thickness effect](//stackoverflow.com/questions/39873279/split-background-image-with-3d-thickness-effect/39876163#39876163)
61. Рус: [Как я могу реализовать визуализацию разграничения объекта SVG с закругленными уголками](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/625858/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-svg-%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%B3)
    Англ: [How could I implement a divided bar visualization in SVG with rounded corners?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/42127554/how-could-i-implement-a-divided-bar-visualization-in-svg-with-rounded-corners/42127683#42127683/)
62. Рус: [Как создать кликабельную сетку треугольников с использованием HTML, SVG?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/625387/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-html-svg)
    Англ: [How to create a clickable grid of triangles using html, svg?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/34001691/how-to-create-a-clickable-grid-of-triangles-using-html-svg/34002110#34002110)
63. Рус [Как нарисовать знак “Х” с помощью SVG и CSS?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/626456/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%A5-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-svg-%D0%B8-css/)
    Англ: [How to draw X Sign with SVG+CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36011117/how-to-draw-x-sign-with-svgcss/36011513#36011513)
64. Рус [Как создать повторяющийся border для масштабируемого элемента](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/625655/)
    Англ: [How to create a repeated border for a responsive element?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/36869325/how-to-create-a-repeated-border-for-a-responsive-element/)
65. Рус [Мое первое изображение SVG](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/626813/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-svg)
    Англ: [My first svg image](//stackoverflow.com/questions/42139990/my-first-svg-image/42152107#42152107/)
66. Рус: [SVG - анимация из средней точки на всю ширину](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/626651/svg-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8E-%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83)
    Англ: [SVG > Animate width from middle](//stackoverflow.com/questions/37622422/svg-animate-width-from-middle/37632648#37632648)
67. Рус: [SVG плюс CSS анимация](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/625900/svg-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%81-css-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)
    Англ: [svg plus css animation](//stackoverflow.com/questions/41757925/svg-plus-css-animation/41761166#41761166)
68. Рус: [Вращающийся элемент SVG выглядит слегка подпрыгивающим](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/627908/%D0%92%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-svg-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BC)
    Англ: [Rotating svg element looks like bouncing slightly](//stackoverflow.com/questions/41094766/rotating-svg-element-looks-like-bouncing-slightly/41096118#41096118)
69. Рус: [CSS анимация изменяет положение элемента](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/630449/css-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0)
    Англ: [CSS Animation changes the element position](//stackoverflow.com/questions/39959506/css-animation-changes-the-element-position/39959739#39959739)
70. Рус [Анимационные SVG пути с прерывистыми частями](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/630516/)
    Англ: [Animating SVG paths with discontinuous parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39896469/animating-svg-paths-with-discontinuous-parts/39896916#39896916)
71. Рус: [3D зеркальное отображение карт](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/630695/)
    Англ: [3D flipping card](//stackoverflow.com/questions/41461101/3d-flipping-card/41462226#41462226)

Comment: Протокол в ссылках убираем, чтобы можно было с сохранением https переходить.

Comment: @Qwertiy это в каких случаях актуально?

Comment: @alexolut, в случае перехода по ссылке. Если полазить по enSO, то там большинство ссылок пользователями даны на https (который, в случае открытых сетей не позволяет влезть в страницу). С другой стороны, с https иногда бывают проблемы, что по нему ничего не открывается. Поэтому правильно оставлять пользователю право решать и ставить переход с тем же протоколом, а не навязывать некоторый конкретный.

Comment: @Qwertiy кстати, интересно, будет ли это иметь какое-то значение при просмотре через приложение StackExchange? Мне кажется, что нет. Еще мне хочется для симметрии заменить "Англ" на "Eng" :)

Comment: @alexolut, мне тоже хочется. Можно попробовать поставить tab. Мне вообще хотелось их удалить, но не решился. Про приложение не знаю - не пользуюсь им, т. к. забил всё место в телефоне :(

Comment: @Qwertiy tab? На iPad удобнее через приложение, нежели просто в браузере, хотя бывают нюансы. Бедное забитое место, как же так! :)

Comment: @Qwertiy При добавлении новых ссылок система выдает сообщение -- тело имеет максимальную длину 30000 символов, вы ввели 30014.  Как я понимаю место в топике ограничено и уже закончилось.

Comment: @Alexandr_T, можно ещё один ответ запостить же.

Comment: @Qwertiy Николас уже принял решение - добавлять ассоциации только через комментарии в вопросах.

Comment: @Alexandr_T это решение где-нибудь документировано?

Comment: @NickVolynkin В вопросе указал. В ближайшее время (сегодня вечером, с большой вероятностью), опишу процесс.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky а, отлично!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky вот что, давайте сегодня обсудим встречу. Наконец, свободный день )

Comment: @NickVolynkin ""Alexandr_T Да, спасибо! Пожалуйста, добавляйте ассоциации через комментарии. Такой способ предпочтительней. Более того, как мне кажется, в будущем нам придется перенести все ассоциации, добавленные в ответ, в комментарии. – Nicolas Chabanovsky♦ 2 дня назад"" и update Nicolas  был в посте, сейчас, что-то не вижу его/  Вижу он вам уже тоже ответил

Comment: @Arhad Пожалуйста, перенесите добавленные вами ассоциации из данного ответа в комментарии (добавьте к вопросу на Stack Overflow на русском комментарий вида: «ассоциация: ссылка_на_so_en»). В течении недели я планирую закрыть этот вопрос и перейти полностью на отслеживание ассоциаций через комментарии. Если по какой–либо причине вы не можете этого сделать, пожалуйста, дайте знать, я перенесу ассоциации самостоятельно (в этом случае, к сожалению, потеряется ваше авторство ассоциации).

Comment: @Kromster Пожалуйста, перенесите добавленные вами ассоциации из данного ответа в комментарии (добавьте к вопросу на Stack Overflow на русском комментарий вида: «ассоциация: ссылка_на_so_en»). В течении недели я планирую закрыть этот вопрос и перейти полностью на отслеживание ассоциаций через комментарии. Если по какой–либо причине вы не можете этого сделать, пожалуйста, дайте знать, я перенесу ассоциации самостоятельно (в этом случае, к сожалению, потеряется ваше авторство ассоциации).

Comment: @AK Пожалуйста, перенесите добавленные вами ассоциации из данного ответа в комментарии (добавьте к вопросу на Stack Overflow на русском комментарий вида: «ассоциация: ссылка_на_so_en»). В течении недели я планирую закрыть этот вопрос и перейти полностью на отслеживание ассоциаций через комментарии. Если по какой–либо причине вы не можете этого сделать, пожалуйста, дайте знать, я перенесу ассоциации самостоятельно (в этом случае, к сожалению, потеряется ваше авторство ассоциации).

Comment: @Qwertiy Пожалуйста, перенесите добавленные вами ассоциации из данного ответа в комментарии (добавьте к вопросу на Stack Overflow на русском комментарий вида: «ассоциация: ссылка_на_so_en»). В течении недели я планирую закрыть этот вопрос и перейти полностью на отслеживание ассоциаций через комментарии. Если по какой–либо причине вы не можете этого сделать, пожалуйста, дайте знать, я перенесу ассоциации самостоятельно (в этом случае, к сожалению, потеряется ваше авторство ассоциации).

Comment: @NickVolynkin Пожалуйста, перенесите добавленные вами ассоциации из данного ответа в комментарии (добавьте к вопросу на Stack Overflow на русском комментарий вида: «ассоциация: ссылка_на_so_en»). В течении недели я планирую закрыть этот вопрос и перейти полностью на отслеживание ассоциаций через комментарии. Если по какой–либо причине вы не можете этого сделать, пожалуйста, дайте знать, я перенесу ассоциации самостоятельно (в этом случае, к сожалению, потеряется ваше авторство ассоциации).

Comment: @D-side Пожалуйста, перенесите добавленные вами ассоциации из данного ответа в комментарии (добавьте к вопросу на Stack Overflow на русском комментарий вида: «ассоциация: ссылка_на_so_en»). В течении недели я планирую закрыть этот вопрос и перейти полностью на отслеживание ассоциаций через комментарии. Если по какой–либо причине вы не можете этого сделать, пожалуйста, дайте знать, я перенесу ассоциации самостоятельно (в этом случае, к сожалению, потеряется ваше авторство ассоциации).

Comment: @jfs Пожалуйста, перенесите добавленные вами ассоциации из данного ответа в комментарии (добавьте к вопросу на Stack Overflow на русском комментарий вида: «ассоциация: ссылка_на_so_en»). В течении недели я планирую закрыть этот вопрос и перейти полностью на отслеживание ассоциаций через комментарии. Если по какой–либо причине вы не можете этого сделать, пожалуйста, дайте знать, я перенесу ассоциации самостоятельно (в этом случае, к сожалению, потеряется ваше авторство ассоциации).

Comment: @alexolut Пожалуйста, перенесите добавленные вами ассоциации из данного ответа в комментарии (добавьте к вопросу на Stack Overflow на русском комментарий вида: «ассоциация: ссылка_на_so_en»). В течении недели я планирую закрыть этот вопрос и перейти полностью на отслеживание ассоциаций через комментарии. Если по какой–либо причине вы не можете этого сделать, пожалуйста, дайте знать, я перенесу ассоциации самостоятельно (в этом случае, к сожалению, потеряется ваше авторство ассоциации).

Comment: @Alexandr_T Пожалуйста, перенесите добавленные вами ассоциации из данного ответа в комментарии (добавьте к вопросу на Stack Overflow на русском комментарий вида: «ассоциация: ссылка_на_so_en»). В течении недели я планирую закрыть этот вопрос и перейти полностью на отслеживание ассоциаций через комментарии. Если по какой–либо причине вы не можете этого сделать, пожалуйста, дайте знать, я перенесу ассоциации самостоятельно (в этом случае, к сожалению, потеряется ваше авторство ассоциации).

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky Я сразу делал ассоциации и в комментариях и в таблице. Поэтому уже всё есть, во всех переводных топиках,  в комментариях **ассоциация:ссылка**

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: на ваше усмотрение с ссылками поступайте

Comment: *"в этом случае, к сожалению, потеряется ваше *авторство ассоциации*"* - можно плиз уточнить, какие бонусы это дает?

Comment: @Kromster Пока не известно про бонусы, но будет таблица лучших участников!)

Comment: @Alexandr_T Спасибо!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, сделано.

Comment: @Arhad большое спасибо!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, формат ссылки любой? А что там с твоей утилитой для ассоциаций? И вообще, по-прежнему счиатю, что чатом было бы удобнее.

Comment: @Qwertiy Формат ссылки  – любой. Инструмент – дописываю прямо сейчас.  Подскажите, в чем особенность решения с чатом? Как–то автоматически обрабатывать сообщения в нем или для обсуждения ассоциаций?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, чаты подхватывают превью с любых сайтов сети. Соответственно идея в том, что бросаешь туда пары и больше вопросов, сразу видишь, что всё хорошо и ставишь какой-нибудь разделитель в отдельном сообщении (ну === например). У чата нет ограничения на размер, так что накидать можно много и в любой момент.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, заметь, в твоём варианте ещё и две вещи желательно в буфере обмена иметь - слово "ассоциация: " и ссылку - неудобно.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, лимит на комментарии - задержка 20 секунд после каждого третьего. UPDATE: уже 24 секунды (после 12го).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, вроде расставил 20 ассоциаций по своим вопросам. Надеюсь, нигде не ошибся. Ещё есть 7 вопросов без ответов - их не трогал. И ещё одну поставил [сюда](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/292361/178988).

Comment: @Qwertiy Спасибо!

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky после некоторых размышлений, поддерживаю предложение Qwertiy - " Alexandr_T, можно ещё один ответ запостить же".  В топиках будет видно, что это переводная статья по ассоциации, а здесь, в таблице получается своеобразный каталог, где всё на виду. Это очень две разные вещи, искать в строке поиска конкретный вопрос или пробежаться глазами по каталогу и увидеть интересный вопрос, который не пришел бы в голову при штатном поиске. Лично для меня не было проблем размещать ссылки, здесь в таблице и одновременно давать ссылки в переводных статьях.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky готово.

Comment: Развернул пробную версию инструментов ассоциации: http://demo.chabanovsky.com/ Буду рад услышать отзывы и предложения!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, ни к кому не обращаешься, никто не увидит коммент. А мне ассоциировать уже нечего, кажется. Ещё не пойму, что за чистка была 2 дня назад в этом ответе.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, было бы хорошо ссылку на вопрос на SO. И ещё переключатель, чтобы видеть вопросы не с SO, а с ruSO. Ну и прикольно, что в топе на ассоциации вопросы с исторической блокировкой (хотя на мой взгляд это фича - они действительно интересные).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky добавил. Всего 2 штуки только.

Comment: @alexolut Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 8):

Чтобы руками не редактировать ссылки, написал в помощь Питон скрипт, который умеет превращать пары ссылок на SO вопросы, в соответствующую Markdown разметку, добавляя заголовок:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import logging
import fileinput
import se_url2info

question_template = "0. Рус: [{ru_q.title}]({ru_q.link}) Англ: [{en_q.title}]({en_q.link})"

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

urls = filter(None, map(str.strip, fileinput.input()))
questions = se_url2info.get_questions(urls, preserve_order=True)
for ru_q, en_q in zip(*[iter(questions)]*2):
    print(question_template.format(**vars()))
```

где используется [`se_url2info` модуль](https://gist.github.com/zed/01d629090110a4f95e2325521f5c4540).

Пример вызова:

```
$ ./se-links2markdown input.txt >output.md
```

где `input.txt` выглядит как:

```
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/594651/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-parameters

http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/135134/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168096/getting-computers-utc-offset-in-python

http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/573078/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676835/signal-handling-in-multi-threaded-python
```

а на результат можно [в разметке редакции ответа посмотреть](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/4121/7).

Чтобы вывести список вопросов в порядке уменьшения числа просмотров:

```
for ru_q, en_q in sorted(zip(*[iter(questions)] * 2),
                         key=lambda qs: max(q.view_count for q in qs),
                         reverse=True):
    print(question_template.format(**vars()))
```