# Предложение создать стоп-лист для q/a/comments, включив в него приветствия, просьбы, спасибо и т.п

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, приветствия

Издавна создаются дискуссии по поводу удалять или не удалять приветствия, спасибо и т.п. и в каких случаях. Предлагаем убрать зерно раздора путем создания списка стоп-слов и включив в него приветствия и слова благодарности. Этим мы уберем дискуссии по данному вопросу и уберем необходимость проверки простых правок, состоящими только из удаления приветствий, спасибо и т.п., которые напрягают некоторых участников сообщества.

**Принцип работы:**

при попытке отправки вопроса, ответа или комментария под вопросом или ответом участнику должно выводиться предупреждение

> Пожалуйста не используйте приветствия, просьбы или слова благодарности. Приветствия не несут информативности. В качестве благодарности Вы можете проголосовать за подходящий Вам ответ.

Исключения должны составлять данные слова в тегах кода. Кроме этого в комментариях скорее всего стоит допускать приветствия(сомнительно, возможно нужно обсуждение участников общества), т.к. очень многие, отсылая читать справку, вежливо приветствуют нового участника.

Comment: Английский SO вроде бы сам вырезает приветы. Может быть механизм можно просто настроить и включить - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989

Comment: @PashaPash если это так, то нужно посмотреть алгоритм работы, чтобы не получилось обрезков предложений. А во-вторых если участник сам удалит свои лишние фразы несколько раз, то он скорее всего быстрее поймет, что эти фразы использовать не стоит.

Comment: Единственное опасение -- что будут резаться нормальные предложения, поэтому я бы включение делал аккуратным, взвешенным. Русские словоформы более вариативны в окончаниях, так что лучше избегать масок, а прописывать явно.

Comment: Это решит проблему новых вопросов/ответов, старые от этого, как я понимаю, никуда не денутся.

Answer (score 4):

Подобный функционал уже есть на сайте. При необходимости, остается лишь настроить его. Будет ли он работать – не ясно. Обычно, участники не ограничиваются одним «Привет!» (если бы ограничивались, проблемы бы вообще не было), а пишут вводное предложение или даже целый абзац (например, поясняющий «начальный» уровень знаний). Вырезать подобное можно, но сложно. Предположу, что при текущем количестве подобных ошибок и настоящей стадии развития сообщества, если бы у меня поинтересовались моим мнением, я бы предложил сделать что–нибудь  другое (например, [Предложите ваши вопросы для ассоциации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4120/)).

Comment: Одно другому не мешает. Развитие же должно быть разносторонним. К тому же данный функционал сократит затрачиваемое участниками время на подобные правки и проверки, а это значит, что они смогут уделить больше времени другим моментам, например тем же вопросам для ассоциации. Кстати говоря предложение было не вырезать, а не давать публиковать в/а/к со словами из стоп-листа, отображая соответствующее предупреждение.

Comment: В принципе можно и вырезать, но, как уже было верно подмечено, русский язык более сложный , а его носители порой весьма изощренны в высказываниях. Поэтому вероятнее всего на настройку придется потратить больше времени чем коллегам из en.so

Comment: Я постараюсь разобраться, возможно ли «из коробки» получить удовлетворяющий результат (в чем я сомневаюсь). Если фильтры качества необходимо настраивать, то это будет необходимо сделать нам с вами, так как [в компании практически отсутствуют русскоговорящие сотрудники](http://stackoverflow.com/company/team).

Comment: За помощью в настройке дело не станет. Помогу с удовольствием.

Comment: @Alex Большое спасибо! Как что–либо станет известно, сразу дам знать!