# Что делать с вопросами, заданными на разных сайтах?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, ассоциация-вопросов

Имеет ли смысл включать в ассоциацию [вопросы, которые задавал на обоих языках](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4928642+%22PS%3A+Same+question+in+Russian%22)?

С одной стороны они действительно одинаковые и их стоило бы связать.

Но с другой - в них уже есть ссылка между сайтами. Получается, надо эту ссылку убирать? Или пусть будет две - представленная в вопросе и ассоциированная? Не сделает ли это последующую статистику непоказательной в том плане, что переходы по ссылке внутри вопроса трекаться как переход к асоциированному вопросу не будут?

И есть ещё один момент. [Что если](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/31477/23135) англоязычный сайт - это не SO?

В общем, что делать?
Или тихо сидеть и не вертеться до окончательной реализации ассоциации?

Comment: я думаю стоит добавить

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Добавлять определенно стоит! Ассоциация сегодня задается *вручную*! Чтобы это сделать, мне необходимо знать, что вопросы дубликаты на разных языках. Ссылка в самом вопросе ни о чем не говорит. (Если честно, до вашего вопроса я даже не знал, что такую выборку можно сформировать.) Ссылку из вопроса убирать не надо, это часть сообщения.

Будет крайне полезно [добавить ассоциации в список](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4120/), чтобы в дальнейшем я мог обновить настройки сайта.

На текущий момент поддерживается ассоциация только между Stack Overflow на разных языках (например, английский – русский).

**Дополнение**

Сейчас нет проверки на то, есть ли у вопроса ответы и не удален ли вопрос или его ответы. Мы полагаемся на то, что все ассоциированные вопросы на русском языке не удалены и имеют ответы, причем хорошие!

Comment: Насколько можно сформировать выборку в общем случае, я не знаю. Поэтому там и прописан мой id - я-то знаю, что оставлял такую ссылку при публикации вопроса, а вот что другие оставляли - понятия не имею. Хотя можно попробовать поиском по адресу ссылки что-то сделать. Мне как-то пока лень руками переписывать пачку вопросов в список для ассоциации. Может потом что-нибудь придумаю. Кстати, 8 из 26 перечислены [в другом ответе на мете](//meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/2519/178988).

Comment: Да, а что если на вопрос нет ответов? Его в ассоциацию не включать?

Comment: Значит всё-таки не все надо ассоциировать :)

Comment: _"имеют ответы, причем хорошие"_ - а если ответ переведён и не добавляет ничего нового? Можно всё-таки более подробно расписать, в каких случаях следует добавлять в список на ассоциацию?

Comment: @Qwertiy Ответ должен быть удовлетворяющего качества. Нет необходимости сравнивать его с ответом на английском. Перевод в любом случае повышает доступность знаний для русскоязычный разработчиков.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Хорошо, а можете создать отдельный вопрос, где будем ставить ассоциации для другого плана ruSO ↔ [сайт StackExchange, но не enSO], то есть к примеру ruSO ↔ dba, ruSO ↔ softwarerecs и т. д.? Или начнём с какой-то черновой реализации?