# 0-индексация в списках

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, markdown, список

[Иногда](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/616781/178988) в сообщение хочется внести в список некое предполагаемое предусловие нулевым пунктом. Но даже при разметке

```
0. Предусловие
1. Первый пункт
2. Второй пункт
```

пункты автоматически перенумеровываются:

> 1. Предусловие
> 2. Первый пункт
> 3. Второй пункт

Хотелось бы иметь возможность явно задавать номер первого элемента - хотя бы 1 или 0.

---

Уточнение: предлагается не сохранять нумерацию, а добавить *любой* способ *намеренного* указания начального значения. Да хоть через html-разметку:

https://jsfiddle.net/c46mvma8/

```
<ol start=0>
  <li>Предусловие</li>
  <li>Первый пункт</li>
  <li>Второй пункт</li>
</ol>
```

Кстати, почему эта разметка выдаёт unordered list вместо ordered list?

> Предусловие
>
> Первый пункт
>
> Второй пункт

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, мне кажется, ты неправильно понял суть предложения. Дополнил вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0. Обновили
1. Теперь можно с нуля

Comment: [meta-tag:status-completed]?

Comment: @AntonMenshov, ну в принципе можно, хотя скорее [статус-side-effect] xD

Comment: Ну, хоть тушкой, хоть чучелом

Comment: А произвольный порядок всё равно нельзя :(

Comment: @andreymal, не совсем нельзя: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11081/178988.

Comment: @Qwertiy эт костыль, там списки раздельные если в html-код заглянуть

Comment: @andreymal, так я же так и написал: "поделить
на разные
списки" ;) И комменты между всеми пунктами для того, чтобы каждый был в своём списке и отступы получились одинаковые.

Answer (score 4):

Многие задают все пункты как [`0.`](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4121/6), ожидая, вероятно, начало отсчета списка с 1.  Все такие сообщения разъедутся. На сайте используется более или менее стандартный MarkDown редактор. Этот вопрос скорее к самому редактору, так как многие пользователи будут ожидать совершенно другого поведения.

**Но!** частично эта функциональность уже [реализована](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137077).

```
3. Предусловие
1. Первый пункт
2. Второй пункт
```

Становится

3. Предусловие
4. Первый пункт
5. Второй пункт

Comment: Вот надо `0` разрешить в качестве начального значения и @Qwertiy будет доволен.

Comment: Это хорошо, но 3 - это не 0. А что насчёт html-варианта?

Comment: @Qwertiy надо попробовать поиграть на переполнении целого :)

Comment: @Qwertiy balpha в совем ответе [пишет](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239121/274323), что `<ol start=0>` [устарел](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html) еще тогда. Видимо, отдельно в [редакторе](http://commonmark.org/), [который мы используем](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238957/), его поддерживать не планируется.

Comment: @Qwertiy Эх, больше `2147483647` не работает, но зато за края формы выезжает.

Comment: А если проверять не просто на `0.`, а на `0.` и `1.` в первых двух пунктах?

Comment: @Qwertiy Если вы имеете в виду, что случится с нумерацией, ответ – как я понимаю, значение имеет только первая цифра, от нее идет дальнейший отсчет.

Comment: @Qwertiy а ещё, начиная с 22 цифр, например, `2222222222222222222222` список из нумерованного превращается в ненумерованный.