# Как создать список с начальным счётчиком равным нулю?

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, сниппеты, редактор, список

Только что с удивлением обнаружил, что местный HTML-движок считает себя умнее всех и не даёт создать нумерованное перечисление с нулевым начальным пунктом, а также не даёт создать нумерованное перечисление с одинаковыми номерами пунктов.

Между тем в практике программирование нумерация с нуля это обычное явление. Также и одинаковые номера (например, вывод в цикле и завершающий вывод после цикла с тем же счётчиком) это тоже обычное явление.

**UPD1:** итак, по просьбе коллег, задним числом (уже после полученного ответа) формулирую вопрос - как на сайте SO сделать нумерованный список с нумерацией, начинающейся с нуля.

За полный и содержательный ответ отдельно ещё раз спасибо коллеге с ником MSDN.WhiteKnight.

Comment: Если это данные выводимые кодом, то их надо оформлять как цитату или блок кода, мне кажется

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, в чем состоит ваш "вопрос"?

Comment: @Kromster Вопрос в том, как создать на сайте программистов (!) список с начальным счетчиком равным нулю. Но на этот вопрос уже ответили. Оказывается, что даже в 21 веке для этого нужно вручную (!) верстать HTML. :-)

Comment: Поправил название вопроса, согласно вашему комментарию

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Обновление.** Ответ больше не актуален, теперь нумерованные списки с началом от нуля работают, предположительно, в связи с переходом на [CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/370389).

---

Это не совсем "дефект", скорее отсутствие функционала. Markdown преобразует список в HTML тег ol, но не дает возможности задать атрибут start. Можно использовать экранирование:

```
0\. Иван

1\. Петр

2\. Мария
```

Результат:

0. Иван

1. Петр

2. Мария

Или вставку HTML, если нужен именно выровненный список:

```
<ol start="0">
  <li> Иван</li>
  <li> Петр</li>
  <li> Мария</li>
</ol>
```

Результат:

0. Иван
1. Петр
2. Мария

Answer (score 0):

0. Обновился
1. Теперь
2. даёт

---

1. А если

2. поделить

2. на разные

3. списки

3. То можно и

4. номера повторять

---

8. Произвольный

4. порядок

2. тоже

1. кучкой

3. списков

Разметка:

```
0. Обновился
1. Теперь
2. даёт

---

1. А если
<!-- -->
2. поделить
<!-- -->
2. на разные
<!-- -->
3. списки
<!-- -->
3. То можно и
<!-- -->
4. номера повторять

---

8. Произвольный
<!-- -->
4. порядок
<!-- -->
2. тоже
<!-- -->
1. кучкой
<!-- -->
3. списков
```

Comment: При добавлении комментов видимые разрывы появляются. Так что так себе выглядит. И разве такой способ раньше не работал?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, да, потому что списки разные. Думаю, работал и раньше.