# Предложение создания списка топовых вопросов большого SO, которые участники могли бы переводить при желании

Tags: обсуждение, перевод-содержимого

Достаточно часто во время поиска информации в интернете я нахожу хороший заплюсованный вопрос на английском Stack Overflow. Этот вопрос и ответы к нему, конечно, можно прочитать, особенно если использовать переводчик. Но мне было бы бесконечно приятней, если бы я читал ответы на аналогичный вопрос на русском языке.

Первое очевидное предложение: `переведи текст вопроса и задай его на русском Stack Overflow`. Оно может не подходить, например если текст вопроса достаточно длинный (в этом случае не всегда может получиться создать качественный перевод). Более того, когда я нахожу нужный вопрос на английском Stack Overflow, в первую очередь мне хочется узнать решение и применить его в текущей рабочей задаче, а не отвлекаться на перевод вопроса.

---

Предлагается создать обновляемый список хороших вопросов английского Stack Overflow, которые желающие участники могли бы переводить. Алгоритм использования этого списка:

- участник при решении рабочей задачи находит хороший английский вопрос и добавляет ссылку на этот вопрос в список.
- другие участники при желании просматривают этот список, находят интересный им вопрос для перевода, переводят его (с добавлением ассоциации) и удаляют вопрос из списка.

Вопросы уважаемому сообществу:

- Кому-нибудь будет интересно переводить вопросы из этого списка, если он будет создан?
- Насколько идея создания списка хорошая/плохая?

Спасибо.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Список переведенных вопросов и ответов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1262/%d0%a1%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: Мне кажется на [этом сайте](http://qaru.site/) уже что-то подобное сделали

Comment: @Grundy так список готовых, и список желаемых это разные вещи.

Comment: @alexolut, в каком-то из связанных вопросов список для перевода вроде тоже обсуждался

Comment: @Grundy, вроде бы это не дубликат, если такое уже предлагалось, можете, пожалуйста, дать ссылку на связанный вопрос

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, тот сайт статичный ведь? Там перевели несколько вопросов и всё. Или нет?

Comment: @user272505, нет, там гугл-транслятором или подобным сервисом перевод вопросов с enSO идет

Comment: @user272505 если ткнуть в "Вопросы", увидеть 1500 страниц и это назвать "несколько", то да, несколько вопросов и всё

Comment: @Grundy но перевод там довольно ништяковый для транслятора, хочется отметить

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, все зависит от текста вопроса: [Эта строка разыскивает нулевой указатель](http://qaru.site/questions/14387/this-code-appears-to-achieve-the-return-of-a-null-reference-in-c) и [исходник](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2894891/2881286)

Answer (score 6):

Подобный список не так просто собрать и поддерживать: вы не сможете отсортировать вопросы на англоязычном сайте по количеству просмотров (популярности) от русскоязычных разработчиков. Для этого не достаточно информации в открытом доступе.

С другой стороны, ***все уже сделано для нас!***

1. *Инструменты ассоциации вопросов*. В рамках пробной реализации механизма ассоциации вопросов я собрал список наиболее просматриваемых вопросов русскоязычными разработчиками на Stack Overlow на английском. Данные по просмотрам брал по дням из логов англоязычного сайта. На сколько я понимаю, это и есть предлагаемый вами список!

   Пожалуйста, обратите внимание.

   - Аннонс инструментов ассоциации: [Инструменты ассоциации вопросов между сайтами](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4857/)
   - Сайт инструментов ассоциации: http://ru.rudevs.ru/
2. На любом сайте сети Stack Exchange есть секретная выборка «величайших хитов», доступная по адресу 'домен.сайта/questions/greatest-hits' (например, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/greatest-hits). Как я понимаю, сюда попадают вопросы на основе взвешенной оценки нескольких параметров (просмотры, голоса и тд).

Пожалуйста, обратите внимание, что у механизма ассоциаций обширная история, на основе которой можно сделать выводы, какие переводы сообщество воспримет хорошо.

- [Повысим интерес коллег к работе с помощью знаний!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2768/)
- [Повысим интерес коллег к работе с помощью знаний: ассоциация вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2983/)

Comment: Не очевидно, насколько полезны переводы: смогут ли их люди, которым нужен соответствующий ответ найти вопрос органически в гугле? (насколько близок лексикон переводчика, к словам, используемым  человеком с действительной проблемой).

Comment: @jfs Именно по–этому для ассоциаций мы решили, что массовые переводы — не наш путь.