# Как выбрать вопрос для перевода?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, перевод-содержимого

В самом конце предыдущего года мы вместе рассмотрели [проблему сайтов с машинным переводом содержимого Stack Overflow на английском на русский язык](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8267/6). На основе отзывов, мы добавили [новую статью в справочный центр](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8429/), которая рассказывает о достигнутом консенсусе относительно переводов на нашем сайте. И теперь, когда у нас есть консенсус, очень хочется время от времени видеть хорошие переводы интересных вопросов на русский язык. Возникает вопрос...

#### Как выбрать вопрос для перевода на русский язык?

В прошлом, я делал небольшое [исследование о переводе вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2770/6) в контексте [инициативы ассоциации вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4857/6). Тогда я использовал сортировку «[величайшие хиты](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/greatest-hits)», хотя выбрать вопросы для перевода из этой сортировки было не так просто.

**(1)** Подскажите, как бы вы выбирали вопросы для перевода? На какие аспекты бы обращали внимание при выборе?

#### Как выбрать вопрос для перевода на основе имеющихся данных?

Мы также можем подойти к вопросу выбора сообщений для перевода с другой стороны — проанализировать данные и построить модель, которая отсортирует все вопросы на английском языке по выбранному нами критерию. В этом случае, всё, что нам с вами останется, в случае желания перевести вопрос на русский язык — взять один из вопросов такой сортировки и перевести!

**(2)** Подскажите, по какому критерию(ям) вы бы хотели иметь возможность отсортировать вопросы на английском языке для выбора сообщений для перевода?

Буду крайне признателен за любые предложения и идеи!

---

На этой неделе у меня есть возможность немного поэкспериментировать с данными  и попробовать построить модель рекомендаций вопросов для перевода. На текущий момент, я думаю, что было бы здорово иметь две сортировки:

1. *По репутации*, которую сможет заработать участник, переведя вопрос на русский язык (другими словами, наиболее интересные вопросы).
2. *По просмотрам*, которые получит переведенный вопрос (другими словами, наиболее важные для сообщества вопросы).

**(3)** Пожалуйста, подскажите, какие признаки вы бы использовали для построения модели и какую бы модель выбрали для создания указанных выше сортировок? (По возможности, признаки должны быть построены на [общедоступных данных](https://data.stackexchange.com/)).

Я не знаток анализа данных. Без ваших отзывов мне будет крайне сложно. Пожалуйста, поделитесь мыслями и опытом в ответах к этому вопросу!

---

## Проверка идей, высказанных в ответах

Конечная цель эксперимента:

> Среди интересных вам вопросов на английском языке, найти те, перевод которых добавит максимально возможную ценность в базу знаний русскоязычного сообщества.

На мой взгляд, наиболее простой эвристикой определения ценности вопроса может быть:

- *Количество просмотров.* Если вопрос имеет большое количество просмотров, его часто ищут через поиск. Чем более популярным будет вопрос, тем большим людям мы поможем.
- *Количество голосов за.* Если участники голосуют за вопрос он им интересен. Интересные вопросы — это здорово!

#### Вопросы

На основе предложений в ответах к этому вопросу я попробовал проанализировать базу знаний на английском языке и сопоставить ее с русскоязычной базой. Для этого я сделал четыре выборки:

1. 500 тысяч вопросов на английском языке отсортированных по убыванию голосов за.
2. 900 тысяч вопросов на английском языке отсортированных по дате публикации (от более старых к новым).
3. Все имеющиеся вопросы на русском языке (чуть меньше четверти миллиона).
4. Чуть больше полутысячи ассоциированных вопросов на английском языке.

Исследуемые параметры (признаки):

- количество просмотров;
- рейтинг;
- количество ответов;
- рейтинг ответов;
- число раз добавления вопроса в избранное;
- количество комментариев,
- размер вознаграждения конкурса (если был);
- дата закрытия вопроса (если есть).
- длина тела вопроса;
- длина заголовка;
- дата создания;
- метки вопроса.

Основные замечания:

- Чем больше рейтинг у вопроса:

  - тем больше рейтинг у ответов;
  - тем больше ответов;
  - тем больше участники добавляют вопрос в избранное.

  Закономерность справедлива как для русского языка, так и для английского, где она более выражена.
- Количество просмотров и рейтинг вопроса довольно сложно предсказать (точнее, у меня это сделать не получилось вообще!)
- Из популярности вопроса на английском языке не следует его популярность на русском.
- У ассоциированных вопросов (если смотреть на их «половинки» на английском языке) выше корреляции между исследуемыми параметрами, чем у вопросов отсортированных по голосам или по дате создания. Таким образом, можно предположить, что все–таки они выбирались как-то не случайно (но закономерность пока описать не получилось).
- Если смотреть на исследуемые параметры у ассоциированных вопросов на разных языках (например, количество голосов у ассоциированного вопроса на английском и его «половинки» на русском языке), то выраженной связи (корреляции) между ними нет.
- Абсолютные значения количества просмотров вопросов в среднем: 561 просмотр на русском языке, 44 632 просмотра на английском языке и 246 637 у ассоциированных вопросов на английском языке.

Учитывая это, сделать какие–то интересные предположения о том, какой из интересных вам вопросов на английском языке принесет больше пользы на русском сделать не получилось.

#### Метки

Другой подход заключается в том, чтобы переводить вопросы по определенным меткам. Интуитивно кажется, что стоит обращать внимание не на все метки, а только на некоторые:

- метки, по которым мало вопросов;
- метки в тренде (новые технологии);
- метки с высоким количеством просмотров и голосов за в среднем.

Я загрузил метки русскоязычного сообщества и сообщества на английском языке. Далее выбрал множество топ–меток по количеству голосов за вопросы и множество топ–меток по количеству просмотров. Затем пересек два множества с сортировкой по количеству-просмотров. Получилось следующее:

Stack Overflow на английском:

```
Имя метки           |Количество| Суммарный | Количество
                    |вопросов  | рейтинг   | просмотров на вопрос
---------------------------------------------------------------
identity-operator   | 14       |  7901     | 205 380 
array-initialize    | 11       |  993      | 190 126
firm-real-time      | 1        |  74       | 157 769
thread-confinement  | 2        |  839      | 149 046
comment-conventions | 7        |  706      | 141 046
```

Stack Overflow на русском:

```
Имя метки           |Количество| Суммарный | Количество
                    |вопросов  | рейтинг   | просмотров на вопрос
---------------------------------------------------------------
wcrypt              | 1        |  13       | 19 329
git-revert          | 12       |  106      | 17 301
git-reset           | 18       |  186      | 14123
git-rm              | 2        |  25       | 11 974
git-checkout        | 21       |  140      | 11 923
```

Если также учитывать количество просмотров вопросов по метке, то топ-10 англоязычных меток будут: [git](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git), [string](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string), [.net](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net), [datetime](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datetime), [bash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash), [shell](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell), [tsql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsql), [date](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date), [linux](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux), [list](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list). В русскоязычном сообществе: [git](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git), [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc), [c](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), [linux](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux), [windows](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows), [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), [c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), [ubuntu](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu), [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android).

Результаты анализа для меток выше очень сильно зависят от гиперпараметра — размер множества топ–меток.

#### Выводы

На мой взгляд, найти какие–то нетривиальные закономерности, анализируя вопросы или пытаться предсказать количество голосов и просмотров по одним лишь данным англоязычного сообщества — слишком сложная задача. С другой стороны, исследовать метки с небольшим количеством вопросов и с большим количеством просмотров и голосов за, кажется куда более перспективной идеей.

#### Что можно делать дальше?

На мой взгляд, необходимо продолжать анализировать имеющиеся базы знаний. Как минимум, это очень захватывающее занятие! =) Которое, возможно, поможет нам лучше понять, какие знания очень нужны русскоязычным разработчикам.

Единственное, что нас держит — это идеи! Пожалуйста, поделитесь вашими мыслями, на что конкретно можно было бы обратить внимание? Каким образом? Что такое исследование нам даст?

Буду очень рад проверить максимальное количество ваших предположений!

Answer (score 6):

Лично мне интересно переводить вопросы с определёнными метками, в которых я разбираюсь. Поэтому в первую очередь я отталкиваюсь от определённой тематики - asp.net-mvc, c#, git, ansible.

И уже только потом я могу как принимать во внимание какие-то численные параметры типа количества просмотров или количество апвоутов, так и могу являясь экспертом в тематике выбрать вопрос не самый популярный, но интересный с какой-либо точки зрения.

Чисто в роли переводчика выступать мне неинтересно. Ну вот есть допустим, вопросы по c++ или java - и я мог бы сделать перевод один-в-один, но с одной стороны лично мне это неинтересно (не даёт мне новых знаний, так как это темы, в которых я не собираюсь специализироваться), с другой стороны вероятность ошибиться больше (незнакомая область + чужой язык) и мне это обернётся как репутационными издержками, так и повышенным временем на выверку материала.

И ещё. Из опыта работы с переводными вопросами (а я там где-то [в десятке](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4857/213987) тех, кто потихоньку что-то переводит) могу сказать, что как ни странно, но количество просмотров на en so и количество голосов практически не влияют на количество репутации, которое можно набрать на ru so.

Исключения есть - это какие-то мега-мега-хиты, которые потом будут многократно цитировать, использовать в качестве закрывашек, но если ставится задача именно по большому крупному переводу сайта - то таких вопросов резко станет меньше и количество вашей репутации будет зависеть от числа постоянных читателей какой-то метки, а не от количества голосов на en so.

Так что мой совет тем, кто хочет заниматься переводом:

> Переводите то, что вам самим интересно и нравится.

---

Updated

> Подскажите, по какому принципу вы выбираете вопрос для перевода в рамках метки?

Открываю список вопросов, иду по списку читая вопросы и оцениваю с двух позиций:

- разбираюсь ли я в теме (даже в рамках одной метки есть некоторая специализация)
- вопрос мне кажется интересным

Соответственно, мне без разницы, сколько у вопроса просмотров и голосов, но в принципе мне некритично что есть какая-то сортировка (скажем, по убыванию голосов), это вполне удобно.

Но мне очень нужны следующие вещи:

- возможность указания более чем одной метки (сегодня мне интересно ковырнуть тему C# + entity-framework, а завтра - c# + asp.net-mvc или c# + asp.net-core
- возможность трёх сортировок: по количеству просмотров вопроса, по голосам на вопросе, по цитируемости вопросов

Поскольку я всегда читаю связанные с вопросом ссылки (в связанных вопросах бывают очень любопытные вещи), то список вопросов по цитируемости кажется достаточно интересной сортировкой. Подозреваю, что будет явная корреляция между просмотрами, голосами и индексом цитируемости - но хочется как-то разнообразить списки вопросов, они всё же будут различаться.

Comment: Блин, на [rudevs](https://ru.rudevs.ru/api/leaderboard/) опять SSL-серт просроченный.

Comment: Обновил сертификат, извиняюсь.

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв. Да, все метрики должны вычисляться в том числе с возможностью фильтра по метке. Я когда переводил, также старался брать только то, что понимаю более или менее.

Comment: О, я даже в пятёрке уже, а не в десятке. ) @NicolasChabanovsky Помнится, вы мне отдельно выгружали по ansible руками - и фильтр по метке уже давно пора автоматизировать, чтобы можно было искать самостоятельно.

Comment: @AK, там же считаются ассоциации, а не количество переведенных вопросов/ответов :)

Comment: Так-то даже я в десятке с 15 ассоциациями и 0 переводов. Просто мало кто знает про эту фичу, да и не нужна она им

Comment: @AK Подскажите, по какому принципу вы выбираете вопрос для перевода в рамках метки?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Дополнил ответ.

Comment: @АндрейNOP не знаю про эту фичу и не буду знать, не нужна, да :D

Comment: @AK Мысль цитированием очень интересная. Смотрю, можно ли эти данные получить. Вы также упоминаете, что вам важно, чтобы вопрос был вам интересен. Подскажите, можно ли численно оценить параметры, по которым вы оцениваете интересен ли вам вопрос или нет? Не могли бы вы привести несколько примеров «интересных» и «не интересных» вам вопросов?

Answer (score 5):

От участника, пожелавшего остаться анонимным, пришло следующее предложение по поиску вопросов для перевода.

#### Отслеживать и переводить вопросы по технологиям в тренде

Основная мысль в том, что зачастую очень сложно найти информацию о совершенно новой или очень узкой технологии. Наличие такой информации на русском, поможет создать сообщество вокруг технологии и повысить уровень знаний каждого участника. Сам перевод обычно связан больше всего с желанием изучить технологию.

**Идея**: поиск меток, которые есть в англоязычном сообществе, но отсутствуют в русскоязычном (аналогично сильной диспропорции количества вопросов в сообществах). Среди таких меток выбрать те метки, количество просмотров (нормированное на время вопроса на сайте) вопросов по которым выделяется.

Comment: А почему этот ответ не отмечен как "общий"?

Comment: Потому что не подразумевает коллективную правку.

Comment: Разве из наличия статуса общего автоматически следует, что сообщение можно менять вдоль и поперёк без сохранения исходного смысла?

Comment: Мне кажется, ваш вопрос о другом. Я не вижу причин, почему этот ответ должен быть общим.

Comment: О чём же он тогда?

Comment: @älёxölüt Обратите, пожалуйста, внимание на справку по [общим вопросам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki)

Comment: Зачем мне обращать внимание на страницу с неактуальной информацией?

Answer (score 5):

Мне кажется, что была бы интересна сортировка не по просмотрам, по суммарному количеству голосов за **ответы** или, как вариант, по количеству голосов за ответ, с максимальным числом голосов в этом вопросе.

Это если для перевода один в один. Количество просмотров показывает сколько людей столкнулось с проблемой, а количество голосов за ответы - на сколько полезен этот ответ.

А вот если переводить только вопрос, а ответ писать свой, то тут достаточно числа просмотров

Comment: Спасибо, идея отличная! Как ни странно, очень высокая корреляция между голосами за вопрос, ответы и число добавлений в избранное. Следом идет корреляция с количеством просмотров.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky [так себе корреляция](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=views%3A100000).