# Стоит ли ставить статус "общего" у сообщения, авторство которого принадлежит другому человеку?

Tags: обсуждение, общие-сообщения

Участник написал сообщение, полностью заимствовав идею другого человека (либо не имеющего учётной записи на сайте, либо пожелавшему остаться анонимным).

Стоит ли в таких сообщениях устанавливать статус "общего"? В частности, дабы не получать репутацию за чужой интеллектуальный труд. Или копи-паст тоже должен быть вознаграждён?

Comment: Пожалуйста, (1) уточните на Мете или на основном сайте; (2) разделите случаи: когда мне говорят буквально в двух словах "я хочу того–то", после чего я исследую проблему и пишу на эту тему развернутый вопрос или ответ, на мой взгляд, кардинально отличается от того, когда кто-то отписался в комментариях, а я скопировал его комментарий ответом или вопросом.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky (1) совершенно не важно, я рассматриваю общий случай. (2) Вы можете рассмотреть различные ситуации и описать это в собственном ответе, если посчитаете необходимым. Не считаю правильным перегружать вопрос какими-то частными случаями, это может склонить отвечающих к иным формулировкам, нежели они были готовы сделать изначально.

Comment: Тогда «копи-паст» тут не к месту, так как этот термин подразумевает, что текст был написан где–то. В этом случае это вопрос лицензии первоисточника и мы явно против прямого копирования!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky не думаю, что есть большая разница между копированием напечатанного/рукописного текста или произнесённого, скажем, вслух.

Comment: Огромная, на самом деле! :)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky с точки зрения авторства - никакой. Если мы, конечно, говорим о какой-либо честности, а не рассматриваем ситуацию с точки зрения некоторых правил первой публикации (кто раньше встал, того и тапки).

Comment: Возможно, мы с вами говорим о чем–то совершенно различном. Попробую пояснить мысль. Чтобы воспроизвести написанное, человеку необходимо выделить текст, скопировать в буфер, вставить и опубликовать. Чтобы воспроизвести то, что кто–то сказал, необходимо дойти до ПК, вспомнить, перефразировать устную речь в письменную при этом дополнить так, чтобы текст получился связанным и интересным. Как вы видите, разница огромная! Наиболее близкий аналог копированию — письмо под диктовку, которое, как ни странно, также требует куда больше усилий.

Comment: На самом деле, устная рекомендация ничем не отличается от той, что мы находим в поисковой выдаче. Таким образом этот случай аналогичен ситуации, когда кто–то увидел интересный вопрос, нашел примерное решение в поиске и написал своими словами ответ. Учитывая что практически все наши с вами прикладные знания получены примерно таким путем, то если попросить каждый раз делать вопрос общим, то скоро у нас останутся только общие вопросы.

Comment: Я так делаю, когда понимаю тему - ищу и компилирую ответ. Хотя мог бы найти наиболее похожий ответ и объявить дубликатом. Не только на СО.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> TL;DR Ставить статус "общего" сообщения не нужно

У нас есть такое явление, что многие старички дают ответы в комментариях ([раз](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4671/213987), [два](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4578/213987), [три](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3061/213987)...), не особо утруждая себя написанием полноценного ответа. Не, ну есть кому и после 20к+ репутации процесс интересен, но чаще интерес к увеличению счётчика ослабевает.

И общественный консенсус таков, что если человек не захотел давать ответ — значит, он понимает, что добровольно отказывается от возможной репутации. Компилируй ответ из комментариев, получай репутацию.

Поэтому если вы будете обсуждать вопрос в контексте именно написания вопросов-ответов — то вопрос уже неоднократно был отвечен ранее и можно задубликатить.

Если же вопрос про [этот кейс](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8501/213987), то я считаю, что следует поступать по аналогии. Хочешь — сделай общим, хочешь — оставь как есть. Технически на мете репутации [не совсем но] нету, основная суть того кейса — анонимизировать мнение выполнена.

Я бы в такой ситуации посчитал, что нужно оставлять авторство за конкретным сотрудником, который получил мнение и опубликовал от своего аккаунта. Это эдакий эквивалент слова "спасибо", выраженный в виде небольшого увеличения репутации за общественную работу.

В целом же я особой значимости поднятой проблемы не вижу. Она не массовая, она не затрагивает широкие слои участников, она этически достаточно нейтральная.

Comment: *"В целом же я особой значимости поднятой проблемы не вижу."* Однако, это не помешало написать ответ. И честно говоря, я не понимаю, зачем подобное выражение вообще добавлять в ответ - голосуйте лучше "против", если пользы от вопроса нет и место на сервере лучше выделить для более полезных сообщений.

Comment: Хотя, вероятно, это такая реакция на мои "проблема раздута" из предыдущих сообщений :)

Answer (score 3):

Назначение общих вопросов — коллективная правка. Об это явно говорится в [справочном центре сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki). Репутация дается за вклад на сайте, соответственно, она достается тому, кто публикует полезное содержимое. Ко всему, проверить, придумали ли вы сами подход «Одиночка» или подсмотрели его у [Гаммы и тов.](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2457392/) никто не сможет.

#### «О репутации»

В одном из ранних интервью (вроде бы в [этом](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWHfY_lvKIQ), если я верно помню), Джоэл говорил, что лучший подход заработать первую репутацию на сайте — посмотреть интересные темы, найти те, где есть несколько ответов, которые описывают проблему с разных сторон, объединить их в один, добавить соответствующие выводы, тесты, пояснения, и опубликовать своим ответом.

Идея Stack Overflow — это постоянно пополняемая, модерируемая база знаний. Если чей–то ответ правильный, но не полный, используйте его как основу своего, добавьте все необходимое и опубликуйте!