# Нет перевода на странице "величайшие хиты"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, величайшие-хиты

Мало кто знает, но у нас на ruSO есть такая страница "величайшие хиты":
 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/greatest-hits

Вот на ней нет перевода описания, что это за хиты такие:

[image: скрин дефекта]

Comment: Ух ты! Где ты ссылку нашел на эту страницу? В справке где-то?

Comment: @Глеб [в одном из старых постов на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8493/532877).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавил переводы:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17420
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17421

Будут в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2023.10.13.43676