# Ассоциация вопросов между сайтами доступна!

Tags: поддержка, ассоциация-вопросов, вехи

Безумно рад сообщить, что несколько часов назад стартовал [долгожданный](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347/) эксперимент ассоциации вопросов между Stack Overflow на английском и Stack Overflow на русском!

#### В чем заключается эксперимент?

Для многих наших коллег, Stack Overflow – это база знаний, состоящая из готовых решений. Для них, пользователей, которые только читают, но не участвуют в жизни сообщества, главная ценность – созданные нами знания (вопросы и ответы, особенно ответы). Чем качественнее сами знания и чем эффективней мы сможем представить эти знания пользователям, тем полезнее результат нашего с вами труда.

На сегодняшний день мы имеем совершенно разъединенные англоязычное и русскоязычное сообщества разработчиков (тому есть исторические причины, которые опускаются). Ассоциация вопросов между сайтами – это первый шаг в объединении двух баз знаний (и сообществ!), что непременно скажется на более эффективном, а значит и полезном, представлении данных пользователям.

Задача сводится к тому, чтобы показывать пользователю наиболее нужное ему содержимое: мы допускаем, что если русскоязычный разработчик читает англоязычный вопрос, который получил хороший ответ на русском языке, то, с большой вероятностью, ему будет интересен русскоязычный вопрос, который нам надо показать пользователю. Данный функционал должен быть крайне полезен для коллег, попадающих на сайт из поиска. В то же время он призван повысить значимость вопросов и ответов на русском языке, так как создаст новый способ попадания пользователей в русскоязычное сообщество.

#### Что было сделано?

На данный момент был реализован (спасибо [@Konamiman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4574/konamiman?tab=profile), [@balpha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115866/balpha?tab=profile), [@Tim Post](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50049/tim-post?tab=profile)) минимум, необходимый, чтобы проверить гипотезу:

[image]

Все ассоциации задаются статически парами `soen_id=soru_id` через запятую в настройках сайта Stack Overflow на английском. Любой участник Stack Overflow на русском может предложить ассоциации в [специальном ответе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4120/). Я отслеживаю прогресс добавления новых ассоциаций, после чего формирую нужную строку пар идентификаторов, затем Тим обновляет настройки Stack Overflow на английском.

Обновление настроек будет происходить, например, раз в неделю.

#### Как предложить ассоциацию?

Для того чтобы предложить ассоциацию, добавьте новый элемент списка, содержащий ссылки на вопросы на Stack Overflow на английском и Stack Overflow на русском, в конец [ответа](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4121/6). (Пожалуйста, следуйте общему стилю форматирования!)

#### Что будет дальше?

Мы будем собирать статистику в течение нескольких последующих месяцев, после чего, конечно же, поделимся результатами с вами!

#### Пожалуйста, [предлагайте](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4121/6) ассоциации!

Чем больше ассоциаций будет, тем больше данных мы сможем собрать! Нам очень нужна ваша помощь!

Чтобы повысить вероятность получения данных, время от времени я буду обновлять список наиболее посещаемых вопросов на Stack Overflow на английском русскоязычной аудиторией, который содержится в вопросе: [Предложите ваши вопросы для ассоциации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4120/6). (**Пожалуйста, если вы добавили ассоциацию для вопроса из списка, не забудьте удалить его!**).

Пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь предлагать ассоциации ваших любимых вопросов, заданных или отвеченных вами, если вы считаете, что ответы на эти вопросы могут быть полезны вашим коллегам!

Comment: Что-то я не вижу такой плашки в этом вопросе. Фича ещё не выпущена? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10180765/open-file-with-a-unicode-filename

Comment: @NickVolynkin У меня все в порядке. Возможно у вас не определили как русскоязычного (язык в обозревателе?)

Comment: Точно, дело было в этой настройке. Заработало!

Comment: у меня Russian присутствует в списке языков в Chromium, но я не вижу ассоциации [по указанной ссылке](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10180765/open-file-with-a-unicode-filename). Так ли это полезно проверять язык в браузере? В чём вред от наличия ссылки, по сравнению с вредом для людей, которые могли бы эти ответы посмотреть, но не могут?

Comment: @jfs Главная задача – предоставить пользователю наиболее полезную информацию из той, что у нас есть, имея некоторые знания о пользователе. Англоязычным пользователям SOen, которых сейчас большинство, подобная информация не нужна (более того, многие из них, с большой вероятностью, высказались бы за удаление подобного блока). Есть два способа определить, нужен ли, к примеру, русскоязычный контент: по IP и по языку обозревателя. Как мне кажется, в будущем, хорошо бы было иметь возможность изменять наличие ссылки в настройках учётной записи.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky 1- я русскоязычный и не вижу ссылки (Accept-Language содержит ru; geoip: Russia, Moscow) 2- утверждение что ответ не поможет англоязычным пользователям не обосновано (по меньшей мере это необходимо тестировать): код в переводе не нуждается, браузер автоматически предлагает перевести текст—наличие машинного перевода может быть лучше чем отсутствие ссылки на вручную выбранный ответ.

Comment: @jfs Да, тестировать надо, согласен. Первоочередной задачей сейчас является проверка гипотезы, что подобный функционал вообще нужен, как пользователям, так и, что самое важно, активным участникам сообщества. Все остальное – вторично.

Comment: @jfs Поясню. Я ничего не имею против статического указания дубликатов, как и связи многие ко многим. Все эти идеи – действительно замечательные. Когда кто–либо в компании или вне ее предлагает что–либо добавить на сайт, первым ответом, который будет от разработчиков – «Действительно ли это вообще надо сообществу? С чего вы взяли?». Сегодня мы получили прекрасную возможность получить реализацию крайне важной функциональности, компания действительно готова это сделать, более того, многие разработчики поддерживают идею. Правила игры при этом остаются прежнее.

Comment: Компании необходимо понимать, что подобный функционал, как бы он не выглядел в будущем, нужен сообществу. Это определяется, по большому счету, не количеством переходов по статической ссылке (которая, к слову, находится не там, где [изначально предлагалось](https://github.com/chabanovsky/so_question_association)), а по количеству предложенных ассоциаций нами! Какое бы решение о внешнем виде ни было, ассоциации ожидают от нашего сообщества. Без интереса к самой конечной цели не будет никакой реализации.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: не вижу как это с моим комментарием связано, но если есть желание моё мнение по этому поводу услышать: связи между вопросами это эффект не первого порядка (~1% понимает русский, один из тысячи перейдёт по ссылке: итого ~1e-5 от всех посетителей). Активных участников только сотни, а ссылки регулярно добавляют *единицы*, поэтому [следует использовать существующие ссылки (в комментариях, вопросах, ответах), которые естественным образом добавлены (как связанные вопросы сейчас работают внутри сайта, только с обобщением на SO на разных языках).](https://goo.gl/CQs7D0)

Answer (score 5):

А будет ли обратная ассоциация? Для русских вопросов английские аналоги?

Могу рассказать чем это будет полезно:

1. Будет возможность добавлять новые ответы на оба SO.
2. Будет возможность дополнять существующие ответы на обоих SO.

Только не надо думать и говорить, что от это только SO на русском выиграет и будто это для нас одолжение. Я не раз видел, когда у нас более полные ответы, чем на англоязычном аналоге.

---

#### Множественные ассоциации между всеми техническими сайтами StackExchange

Предлагаю более глубокую реализацию: помимо соответствия между локализованными версиями, давайте сделаем состветствия между разными сайтами StackExchange, у которых пересекается тематика.

Примеры: Stackoverflow пересекается (особенно русский) тематически c

- [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/). Куча вопросов по SQL и БД.
- [softwarerecs.stackexchange.com](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Немало вопросов по поводу выбора технологий
- кучей специализированных сайтов по [Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), [Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/), [WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) и т.д.

Также это нововведение популяризует другие сайты StackExchange помимо английского StackOverflow и будет дополнять и унифицировать базу знаний разных сайтов.

При этом подразумеваю чтобы у нас на ruSO можно было бы добавить соответствие не только на enSO, а также на другие сайты StackExchange.

Comment: Связь двунаправленная. Если вы имеете в виду, будет ли в русскоязычном сообществе упоминаться, что существует англоязычный аналог, то, с большой вероятностью, ответ да, будет (я пытался показать видение на [небольшом примере](https://github.com/chabanovsky/so_question_association)). В любом случае, пока нет никакой реализации, а это означает, _она может быть любой_! Предлагайте ваше видение!

Answer (score 0):

#### Многие ко многим

Есть предложение, чтобы можно было бы указать ассоциации с несколькими вопросами с другого ресурса, потому что бывает что отлично подходят несколько.

Comment: Несколько похожих - и не связаны ссылками как дубликаты? Мгм.

Comment: @AK Вы тут, похоже, правы... Может удалить этот ответ?

Comment: Зачем? Может быть кто-то придёт и скажет другую мысль, которая начисто перечеркнёт мой комментарий. Сначала подождите несколько дней. Я часто видел, как мысль одного находила неожиданное продолжение, наталкивая кого-то на другую мысль.

Comment: @AK возможно, например когда наш вопрос объединяет в себе темы двух англоязычных.