# Можно ли задавать одинаковые вопросы на разных stackoverflow?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка

Возможен ли такой вариант - я задал вопрос на русском stackoverflow там не получил ясного ответа и спросил на английском? Не заблокируют ли за это модераторы?

Comment: тут такой вопрос уже задавался, надо поискать..... вкратце ответ на ВАШ вопрос - нет не заблокируют.

Comment: Нет, не заблокируем. Но стоит в вопросе на русском оставить ссылку на вопрос на английском.

Comment: Можете даже продублировать ваш вопрос на любом другом более узкоспециализированном сайте StackExchange:  [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) — вопросы по SQL и БД, [softwarerecs.stackexchange.com](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) — вопросы по поводу выбора технологий, и на других узкоспециализированных сайтах по [Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/), [Latex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/), [WordPress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) и т.д.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov только помарочка, емнип, @NicolasChabanovsky писал что при этом нельзя писать одновременно в два из одной сети. то есть одновременно на `dba`  и `softwarerecs` один и тот же вопрос нельзя задавать, а вот если бы был `dba.en`, `dba.ru`, `dba.es` и другие разноязыковые - то можно..... к сожалению не могу найти ответ. можно спросить у него

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы обозначите эти вопросы как [ассоциацию](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4409/), то это только приветствуется. А если вы переведёте ответ, который получили на enSo, на русский, и запостите его под своим же вопросом, указав, что это перевод, будет ещё лучше.

Comment: ассоциацию нужно ставить только после того, как будут ответы и в русском и в английском варианте, при этом желательно, чтобы вопрос набрал популярность и ещё несколько других ответов.

Comment: @pavel Чтобы были ответы на русском и английском сайтах, вопрос нужно как минимум разместить на обоих сайтах. Denis об этом и спрашивает - можно ли разместить. Что можно, ему ответили в комментариях, а я дополняю, как это правильно сделать.