# Инструменты ассоциации вопросов между сайтами

Tags: предложение, ассоциация-вопросов

## Статистика

Цифры прежде всего!

```js
fetch("https://ru.rudevs.ru/api/leaderboard/").then(resp => resp.json()).then(({items}) => { document.body.innerHTML = `<h1>Ассоциаций: ${items.reduce((s,x)=>s+x.count,0)}</h1>` + items.sort((x,y)=>y.count-x.count).map(x => `<p><img width=208 height=58 src="//ru.stackoverflow.com/users/flair/${x.id}.png"> <span>${x.count}</span></p>`).join(" "); })
```

```css
body { text-align:center; counter-reset: i; } span, p::before { display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; } span { background:blue; color:white; line-height:1.5em; width:1.5em; border-radius:50%; } p::before { counter-increment: i; content: "#" counter(i) "\A0"; } h1 { color: blue; }
```

<sub>Отдельное спасибо @Qwertiy за реализацию кода блока статистики!</sub>

## Инструменты ассоциации вопросов между сайтами

> ### Коротко
>
> Пробная версия инструментов ассоциации вопросов доступна по адресу: http://ru.rudevs.ru/*. 
>   С нетерпением ждем ваших отзывов и предложений!

<sub>* Да, не лучший выбор домена, это точно. В самое ближайшее время мы выберем новый на основе ваших предложений (ждем их в комментариях к вопросу).</sub>

### Что такое инструменты ассоциации?

Вопросы–ассоциации – это, по сути, дубликаты вопросов между сайтами на разных языках: Stack Overflow на английском и Stack Overflow на русском ([подробнее про ассоциации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4409/)). Предлагаемые инструменты ассоциации является улучшением опыта пользователя для поиска одинаковых вопросов между сайтами. Инструменты содержат две части: расширение для обозревателя и серверное приложение.

[image]

### В чем преимущество ассоциаций для сообщества?

**Дополнительное внимание**

Основную пользу созданная нами база знаний приносит нашим коллегам, которые попадают на сайт из поиска. Для поисковых систем Stack Overflow на русском и Stack Overflow на английском являются совершенно разными сайтами, что может приводить к конкуренции за верхние позиции в поисковой выдаче, а как результат, к недостаточному вниманию к одному из сайтов.

Создание ассоциаций между сайтами, позволяет обойти ограничение поисковиков, и предоставить наиболее полезную информацию пользователям вне зависимости от «точки входа» на семейство сайтов Stack Overflow (другими словами: перенаправить часть русскоязычных разработчиков с англоязычного сайта, на русскоязычный и в обратном направлении, при необходимости). Таким образом, ассоциированные вопросы смогут получить больше заслуженного внимания.

**Улучшение структуры общей базы знаний**

На сегодняшний день, базы знаний сообществ, как и сами сообщества, совершенно не связаны. Одна из основополагающих идей Stack Overflow заключается в том, чтобы собрать как можно больше полезной информации о каждой прикладной проблеме в одном вопросе, что позволит сообществу поддерживать качество информации в ответах, непрерывно улучшая ее с одной стороны. С другой стороны, результатом будет отсутствие в поисковой выдаче одного и того же вопроса заданного многократно. Для этого создан механизм закрытия вопросов.

Наличие связей между вопросами на разных языках даст возможность создать дополнительный функционал для еще более эффективной поддержки релевантности представленных в ответах знаний.

**Взгляд на базу знаний нашего сообщества через призму Stack Overflow на английском**

Выполняя поиск ассоциаций для популярных вопросов на английском языке на Stack Overflow на русском можно увидеть, каких вопросов не хватает в нашей базе знаний, и какие ответы можно значительно улучшить.

### Как работают инструменты ассоциации?

На сегодняшний день процесс и реализация выглядят следующим образом.

#### Реализация

На стороне движка реализация минимальна: на Stack Overflow на английском в настройках сайта мы можем задать строку, которая содержит пары идентификаторов вопросов с сайтов вида `soen_id=soru_id;soen_id=soru_id;...`. Под каждым вопросом на Stack Overflow на английском, с идентификатором из этого списка появляется специальная вставка, говорящая, что на Stack Overflow на русском имеется аналогичный вопрос.

[image]

Эта вставка, в нашем случае, показывается только русскоязычным пользователям Stack Overflow на английском.

Для того, чтобы идентификаторы пар вопросов попали в настройки Stack Overflow на английском, ассоциации необходимо создать. *Ассоциация создается за счет добавления специального комментария под ассоциируемым вопросом на Stack Overflow на русском.* Комментарий должен иметь определенный формат: слово «ассоциация», затем двоеточие «:» и ссылка на вопрос на Stack Overflow на английском. Например:

```
 ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211771/how-to-convert-int-to-qstring
```

Допускается использовать короткую ссылку (из блока «поделиться»).

#### Процесс

Участники в любое время могут добавлять ассоциации в комментариях к вопросам на Stack Overflow на русском. Один раз в неделю, с большой вероятностью, по пятницам, я выполняю SQL запрос по базе данных Stack Overflow на русском и выбираю все комментарии–ассоциации, формирую из них строку с идентификаторами и затем вручную обновляю настройки Stack Overflow на английском.

#### Где нужны инструменты ассоциации?

Инструменты позволяют упростить поиск ассоциаций между сайтами, автоматизировать создание комментариев и формирование строки настроек.

**Детально: [расширения для обозревателя](https://github.com/chabanovsky/so_association_tools/tree/master/extension)**

1. Добавляет в ссылку «ассоциировать» под каждый не ассоциированный вопрос на Stack Overflow на русском, нажав на которую вы увидите поле ввода ссылки на вопрос–ассоциацию на Stack Overflow на английском.

   [image]
2. Преобразует комментарий–ассоциацию на Stack Overflow на русском в специальный блок.

   [image]

**Детально: [серверное приложение](http://ru.rudevs.ru/)**

Серверное приложение упрощает поиск одинаковых вопросов между сайтами и автоматизирует добавление комментариев-ассоциаций. Для работы с приложением необходимо авторизоваться через Stack Exchange OAuth.

Приложение содержит четыре основных раздела.

[image]

1. «Наиболее просматриваемые» – список вопросов со Stack Overflow на английском, которые наиболее часто просматривают русскоязычные пользователи. Список формируется для каждого участника независимо, на основе статистики и пропущенных конкретным участником вопросов.
2. «Пропущенные» – список вопросов, для которых участники сообщества не смогли найти ассоциации на Stack Overflow на русском. Список един для всех участников.
3. «Запросы на перевод» – список вопросов, для которых, вероятно, нет ассоциации на Stack Overflow на русском и которые, по мнению сообщества, крайне важны для нашей базы знаний. Предполагается, что неравнодушные участники воссоздадут знания на русском языке за счет перевода или публикации своего опыта по данному вопросу, а затем ассоциируют вопросы. Список един для всех участников.
4. «Предложенные» – список вопросов, которые были добавлены в приложение участниками вручную. Выборка наиболее просматриваемых вопросов создается на основе ежедневной статистики Stack Overflow на английском. Участники, с другой стороны, могут вручную добавить любой вопрос со Stack Overflow на английском по своему усмотрению для поиска ассоциации. Список един для всех участников.

Выбрав в списке вопрос для поиска ассоциации, вы попадаете на страницу вопроса.

[image]

Помимо описания вопроса, статистики и ссылки на него на Stack Overflow на английском, на странице присутствуют:

1. Кнопка «пропустить». Используйте ее, если не можете найти ассоциацию к данному вопросу. Пропустив вопрос вы больше не увидите его в списке наиболее просматриваемых вопросов.
2. Кнопка «запросить перевод». Используйте ее, если вы считаете, что вопрос должен быть в базе знаний сообщества, но все еще не был задан.
3. Поле поискового запроса – для поиска ассоциаций на Stack Overflow на русском. Используйте поисковый запрос наиболее точно описывающий англоязычный вопрос. Поиск осуществляется по сайту на русском языке с помощью Google. Рекомендуем использовать русский язык для текста запроса. По умолчанию используется заголовок вопроса на английском.

Выполнив поиск вы увидите список кандидатов для ассоциации.

[image]

Выбрав подходящего кандидата для ассоциации вы увидите оба вопроса с ответами. Если вопросы совпадают, следует использовать кнопку «Ассоциировать», если не совпадают – «Вернуться назад».

Если вы принимаете решение ассоциировать вопрос, приложение автоматически добавит комментарий под выбранным вопросом на Stack Overflow на русском за вашим авторством. Комментарий будет содержать ключевое слово «ассоциация» и ссылку на Stack Overflow на английском. Вам нет необходимости делать что–либо еще для назначение ассоциации. После назначения ассоциации, ассоциированный вопрос пропадет из соответствующей сортировки приложения для всех участников.

### Предложения, дефекты и будущее ассоциаций

Инструменты ассоциаций – проект с открытым исходным кодом: https://github.com/chabanovsky/so_association_tools. Любой желающий может принять участие в исправлении дефектов и реализации нового функционала. Если вы видите дефект, но по тем или иным причинам не можете исправить его самостоятельно, пожалуйста, опубликуйте описание дефекта в ответе к этому вопросу или на GitHub. Помимо дефектов, в ответах к этому вопросу, будем рады увидеть ваши отзывы и предложения по улучшению приложения.

**Будущее**

Инструменты ассоциаций находятся на стадии инициативы. Если вы находите данную инициативу полезной, пожалуйста, обязательно примите участие в назначении ассоциаций, подборе нужных сообществу вопросов и их публикации. Решение о создании данного функционала внутри движка Stack Overflow зависит исключительно от интереса к нему с вашей стороны. Нам крайне важно ваше мнение!

Comment: Хотелось бы корректной обработки url на вопрос в поле для ассоциации вопроса: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wgKII.png

Comment: @Qwertiy по сниппету хорошо бы добавить место в рейтинге и общее количество.

Comment: @alexolut, готово.

Comment: @Qwertiy ура! Я в десятке!

Comment: Запрос с `https` на `http` блокируется, что ожидаемо. Сделайте для `http://demo.chabanovsky.com/api/leaderboard/` шифрование, хоть [отсюда](https://letsencrypt.org/).

Comment: @Other Добавил обработчик HTTPS.

Comment: Добавить - добавили, но, видимо, сапопальный, который блокируют браузеры.

Comment: @Other Спасибо за подсказку. Поправил.

Comment: Теперь кошерно и работает, спасибо.

Comment: Обновил статистику просмотров до 2017/03/17.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky а еще будут обновления статистики?

Comment: @Alexandr_T  Прямо сейчас собираю. Думаю, до конца дня соберу все и залью на сервер.

Comment: Обновил статистику просмотров до 2017/04/02.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Почему-то ошибка `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE` для `demo.chabanovsky.com/api/leaderboard/`.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Были (видимо, пока еще «есть», а «не были») какие–то проблемы с сервером. Вообще, я перевел приложение на другой домен `https://ru.rudevs.ru/api/leaderboard/`. Вроде бы с ним, все работает на данный момент.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky То же самое почему-то с другим доменом.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Кажется, понял проблему (ошибка в сертификате). Постараюсь вечером посискать решение. Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Почему-то до сих пор не работает.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Пока не начинал делать. Стыдно. Сегодня в 12 начну и не сдамся пока не закончу!

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Поправил, как я понимаю. Проверьте, пожалуйста!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Спасибо огромное, работает.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Вам спасибо!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Только как-то странно, что у меня всего 5 ассоциаций, мне казалось, что их уже должно быть больше.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Я обновлял данные последний раз ~2 недели назад. Если вы добавляете ассоциации через комментарии напрямую на сайте, приложение их не увидит до следующей синхронизации. Также, пожалуйста, обратите внимание, что приложение учитывает только ассоциации _между вопросами, между сайтами Stack Overflow на разных языках_ (то есть ассоциация на ответ на SO или ассоциация на вопрос на AskUbuntu в данной статистике учитываться не будет).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Я это понимаю, но просто даже с учётом этого, кажется маловато. А можете (если вам не сложно) кинуть ссылку на SQL-запрос (где-то в сети есть такой сайт, где это можно, не помню название) на мои комментарии, которые начинаются с "ассоциация"?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Я выполняю запрос по внутренней базе данных. С другой стороны, запрос практически без исправлений можно выполнить по публичной версии. Пожалуйста, посмотрите на [пример того, как можно получить данные на SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/686828/associations-on-the-site).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Спасибо огромное! То что надо. А вы заметили, что там комментарии-ассоциации (не только мои, если что) иногда в совсем разных форматах (очень наглядно видно в этой выборке). Может часть из этих комментариев невалидна как ассоциация?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Я постараюсь проследить, какие именно ассоциации игнорируются во время загрузки. С другой стороны, вы можете самостоятельно посмотреть на [код загрузки выборки](https://github.com/chabanovsky/so_association_tools/blob/master/server_app/database.py#L139).

Comment: Синхронизировал ассоциации. Отправил запрос на обновление настроек SOen. В ближайшее время новые ассоциации должны быть доступны на сайте.

Comment: Синхронизировал ассоциации и обновил настройки Stack Overflow на английском: все ассоциации должны быть доступны!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky  желательно увеличить срок действии лицензии. Не уверен, но срок действия всего месяц.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Вроде бы три. Только они как–то слишком быстро и незаметно заканчиваются.

Answer (score -1):

Я вот чего не понимаю:
Если ассоциация показывается под английским вопросом, а пишется под русским, то почему я не могу проассоциировать один русский вопрос с несколькими английскими?
Например, вот этот [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/979472/185618) (не перевод) может быть связан с вопросами https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081895/trouble-with-batch-conversion-of-png-to-pdf-using-convert и https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261855/recommendation-for-compressing-jpg-files-with-imagemagick.
И как тут поступать?

Comment: Создать новый вопрос на Мете и сослаться не текущий вместо публикации вопроса здесь в поле ответа.