# Хотели бы мы иметь рекламу от сообщества? Если да, то какую?

Tags: обсуждение, реклама-сообщества

Многие сайты сети Stack Exchange пользуются популярностью (другими словами, имеют большое количество показов страниц в месяц). Мы утилизируем часть показов для платных рекламных объявлений. [Делаем мы это взвешенно, не перегружая сайты](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/03/25/responsible-advertising-feed-a-programmer/). Даже с учётом платных объявлений, у нас остаются существенные возможности по показу рекламы.

#### [В этом году мы рады предложить воспользоваться рекламой от сообщества участникам Stack Overflow на русском!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/05/31/community-promotion-ads/)

Подскажите, расскажите:

1. Хотели бы вы видеть рекламу от сообщества на сайте или лучше обойтись без неё?
2. Если вы хотите видеть рекламу от сообщества на сайте, то в каком виде?

#### Вид рекламы

На всех сообществах Stack Exchange предлагается размещать рекламу о:

- социальных активностях сообщества (например, [создании ассоциаций между вопросами](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4857/6));
- бесплатных инструментах и приложениях связанных с темой сайта;
- конференциях или других событиях, которые могут быть полезны участникам;
- других потенциально интересных участникам активностях, связанных с темой сайта.

Есть лишь один сайт-исключение — Stack Overflow на английском. На нём действуют ограничение: [рекламировать можно только проекты с открытым исходным кодом](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/12/19/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/), а сама реклама должна быть направлена на привлечение новых участников в проект (то есть рекламируется принятие участия в написании кода). Наш сайт довольно близок к Stack Overflow на английском. Кажется, что подобное ограничение должно быть и у нас… Или не должно?

Что думаете? Нужно ли? Если да, какой подход выбрать для Stack Overflow на русском? Пожалуйста, поделитесь вашими мыслями!

Пожалуйста, обратите внимание, мы оставляем за собой право на редакторскую правку и / или отказ показа любой рекламы, которая, на наш взгляд, идёт в разрез с интересами сети Stack Exchange.

Comment: Речь идёт о бесплатной рекламе или о платной?

Comment: Речь про бесплатную рекламу, которую предлагают сами участники сообщества.  @Qwertiy

Answer (score 19):

**Да**, но с весомыми ограничениями:

- *Проекты с открытым исходным кодом*
  Как для набора разработчиков, так и для привлечения пользователей.
- *Крупные конференции для разработчиков (например, [Highload++](https://www.highload.ru/), [FrontendConf](https://frontendconf.ru/))*
  В основном хотелось бы видеть ежегодные IRL конференции. Но и другие виды вполне допустимы, если у них имеется хорошая репутация.
- *Важная активность сообщества*
  Как нашего сообщества, так и сообщества программистов в целом. Обсуждать такие объявления предлагаю отдельно.

**Не хотел бы видеть**:

- *Рекламу любых инструментов и приложений с закрытым исходным кодом*
  Коммерческих или некоммерческих — неважно.
- *Рекламу любых образовательных ресурсов*
  Это касается и онлайн-школ, и бесплатных онлайн-митапов для разработчиков, и недельных интенсивов, и нового невероятного курса по обучению [с++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%2b%2b) за 21 день.
- *Предложения вакансий*

Answer (score 4):

Да, но в таком виде, чтобы она мне не мешала, когда я занят другим делом. Т.е. было бы неплохо создать отдельную страницу (раздел) с продвигаемыми предложениями разбитыми по определённым признакам (меткам). В противном случае многие пользователи, которые умеют пользоваться расширениями для обзорщиков, большинство предложений и не увидят вовсе.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы пока не стал накладывать излишние ограничения на рекламу.

Чего я бы хотел видеть:

- активности сообщества
- бесплатные программы и инструменты, связанные с программированием или администрированием
- IT-конференции, хотя есть вопросы:

  - все или только бесплатные?
  - только онлайн или все?
  - как определять, кому показывать уведомления об оффлайн-конференциях - по регионам?
- другие интересности по тематике сайта

Чего я бы не хотел видеть:

- реклама коммерческих продуктов
- поиск работы

Answer (score -3):

Я за любую айти рекламу в адекватном формате. Не вижу ничего плохого в рекламе:

1. ПО закрытого, открытого, свободного, коммерческого, бесплатного и т.д.
2. Услуг связанных с айти
3. Предложений о работе или наоборот резюме.
4. Рекламы сообществ, конференций и т.д.