# Реклама сообщества 2020

Tags: обсуждение, реклама-сообщества

Настало время попробовать что-то новенькое! Встречайте инициативу [бесплатного размещения рекламы проектов с открытым исходным кодом на Stack Overflow на русском на основе голосования](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/)! Создайте графическую рекламу для любимого проекта и разместите её ответом под этим вопросом, и она заполнит неиспользуемые показы на Stack Overflow на русском!

### Требование к рекламе

[По результатам обсуждения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10301/6) и опыта Stack Overflow на английском, мы предлагаем следующие ограничение на рекламу.

Предлагаемая реклама должна быть о **вовлечении программистов в написание исходного программного кода** и других задачах связанных с программированием (документация, проверка кода, исправление дефектов и т.д.) В то же время реклама не предназначена для продуктов как таковых, даже если у них открыт исходный код.

Чтобы ваша реклама участвовала в отборе (с технической точки зрения), она **должна следовать** следующему шаблону.

### Шаблон ответа

```
[![Альтернативный текст, если изображение не загружается.][1]][2]

  [1]: http://ссылка-на-изображение
  [2]: http://целевая-ссылка-перехода
```

Пожалуйста,  **не добавляйте что-либо еще в ответ**. Если вы хотите пояснить что-то, используйте комментарии.

### Требования к изображению

Изображение:

- должно иметь разрешение **300 пикселей на 250 пикселей** или в два раза больше для High DPI;
- должно быть загружено через стандартную загрузку изображений на сайте (imgur);
- допустимы расширения GIF или PNG;
- GIF без анимации;
- абсолютный размер файла до **150 KB**;
- должно иметь не белую границу в 1 пиксель как часть фона, если фон белый (2 пикселя в случае с High DPI);
- текст рекламы должен быть на русском языке.

По ссылке ниже доступны объявления, которые в конечном итоге будут отображаться на Stack Overflow на русском.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/ossads/300x250

### Порог рейтинга

Ответ с рекламой должен преодолеть **порог минимального рейтинга** (в настоящий момент равен 6) для того, чтобы отображаться по ссылке выше и в будущем попасть в ротацию на Stack Overflow на русском. На странице ниже отображаются рекламные объявления, которые удовлетворяют минимальному порогу и другим критериями:

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/10472

Comment: На январских праздниках выкладывал в opensourse свой проект домашних финансов ([фронт](https://github.com/akmetainfo/WallyFrontend), [бек](https://github.com/akmetainfo/WallyBackend)), это не будет считаться за "продукт как таковой"?

Comment: @AK Как я понимаю, главное — призывать участвовать в разработке.

Comment: 1. Почему в тексте _"По результатам обсуждения и опыта Stack Overflow на английском",_ если ссылка ведёт на наше обсуждение на русском? 2. В том обсуждении явно написано _"Проекты с открытым исходным кодом
Как для набора разработчиков, так и для привлечения пользователей."_ - почему тут стало только для привлечения разработчиков? 3. Прими что ли ответ в том вопросе, чтобы к нему скроллить не приходилось.

Comment: «должно иметь границу в 1 пиксель как часть фона, если фон белый» — что-то я не могу понять, в чём смысл?

Comment: @andreymal  На сайте белый фон. Если и у изображения будет белый фон, то оно «сольется» с сайтом. Границы нужны чтобы выделить (обвести) баннер.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky тогда нужно написать, что эта граница должна быть не белая, иначе непонятно ничего

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо! Поправил.

Comment: Пункт про границу очень странный. Это должно делаться на уровне движка. Потому что какая бы она не была: белая, тёмная, прозрачная — при изменении дизайна [может сломаться](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTxwh.png).

Comment: Думаю, что в требования стоит добавить наличие фона в принципе (отсутствие альфа-канала), а границу просить также не тёмную. На мой взгляд, хорошо бы подошёл оранжевый и голубой.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Спасибо! Если увидите еще подобные баннеры (с прозрачным фоном для темного оформления сайта), пожалуйста, нажмите «пожаловаться на рекламу», указав проблему «прозрачный фон». Мы заменим баннеры на такие же с непрозрачным фоном.