# Ограничение количества копирований на SO

Tags: обсуждение, 1-апреля

С текущего момента количество копирований с сайта SO ограничено 2мя в сутки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также открыт предзаказ на [уникальный девайс](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/03/31/the-key-copy-paste) (хотя у меня уже давно такой, хотя и самодельный):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Всех с 1 Апреля :))

Comment: LOL ура, шутка все-таки есть XD у нас правда не пашет...

Comment: ну хоть увольняйся теперь... :(

Answer (score 16):

Так как ограничение действует только на Stack Overflow на английском, это хороший повод переманить аудиторию на наш сайт.

Доступные каждому два копирования в день предлагается использовать с умом. Для этого найдите популярные и интересные вам вопросы на enSO и перенесите их на наш сайт (можно даже сделать перевод!), если этого ещё не сделали до вас.

Не забывайте ставить ссылку на исходное сообщение согласно лицензии [cc by-sa](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) и добавлять комментарий для [ассоциаций](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4857/176217).

Answer (score 2):

О том, что в каждой шутке есть здравое зерно.

Stackoverflow провели исследование о том, как часто люди копируют информацию и какую.

Вот тут сама статья: [How often do people actually copy and paste from Stack Overflow? Now we know.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/04/19/how-often-do-people-actually-copy-and-paste-from-stack-overflow-now-we-know/)

Вот тут на хабре перевод на русский: [Мы выяснили, что люди копируют со Stack Overflow и насколько часто](https://habr.com/en/company/productivity_inside/blog/553890/)