# Можно ли задавать вопросы в стиле "Плохой ли это код?"

Tags: поддержка, вопросы, инспекция-кода

Допустим я хочу задать вопрос: "Плохо ли использовать `meta` тэги в `body`?"

Не будет ли это оффтопом или нарушением правил по корректной формулировке вопроса?

Comment: Попробуйте - узнаем

Comment: Попробуйте, если поставят минус то скиньте ссылку сюда.

Comment: С одной стороны, это прямой путь к закрытию с причиной *«необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать объективно верный ответ»*. Но с другой — всё зависит от качества ответа и его способности показать, что вопрос не так прост, как кажется, и имеет подводные камни.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, `А замусоривать мету подобными вопросами - какая-то дикость и глупость.` — не соглашусь. Вопрос, который автор собирается задать, не является однозначно плохим, ровно как и однозначно хорошим. Так что пусть лучше здесь поинтересуется и получит рекомендации по оформлению. Тем более, что тема *потенциально хорошая*.

Comment: @Arhad правильно. давай все вопросы в начале задавать на мете, а потом, если их кто-то "одобрил" - публиковать на основном сайте. К тому же то, что тут кто-то что-то посоветует или скажет: публикуй - не означает ни сколько, что на основном сайте его не заминусуют и не закроют. Или тут верховный суд собрался? Или мета - консультативный пункт перед публикацией? Бред.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  Ну в теории да, мета (задолбало автозаполнение на телефоне, upvote у кого жиза) это то место где можно попросить совет у гуру-программистов (и не только) иногда и по совместительству агрошкольниками (но это не точно). Я думаю это отличное место, где можно задать вопрос немного не подходящий по тематике программирования, но довольно близкий к ней, когда ты обратился к потокам своего сознания и ответа долго не было.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваш вопрос очень похож на «[What happens if the meta tags are present in the document body?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1447842/2553424)».

Рекомендую поступить следующим образом: перевести вопрос и наилучший ответ по ссылке,  а затем создать [ассоциацию](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4409/208074).

И, разумеется, в конце вопроса стоит дать ссылку на его оригинал, как-то так:

```
(Здесь заканчивается текст вопроса)

---

*Данный вопрос является переводом «[What happens if the meta tags are present in the document body?][1]».*


 [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1447842/2553424
```

Comment: Мне кажется, или ссылка на «ассоциацию» ведёт куда-то не туда? (Я попадаю на вопрос «Можно ли задавать технические вопросы с юридической или финансовой составляющей»)

Comment: Отлично, спасибо!

Comment: Прошло больше года, вопроса так и не появилось или я просто слепой?

Comment: @andreymal Что не так? Прошёл по всем трём ссылкам — всё работает. Или речь о том, что никто так и не взялся за перевод вопроса?

Comment: @Arhad да, о переводе. А то если до сих пор нет, то может я напишу

Answer (score 6):

Если абстрагироваться от вопроса про html теги, то на сайте есть специальная метка [инспекция-кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0), которую можно использовать, когда требуется выяснить проблемные места в готовом и работоспособном коде.