# Когда ассоциация станет полноценным функционалом?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, ассоциация-вопросов

Более полугода назад [стартовала ассоциация вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4409/%D0%90%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BD%D0%B0). Это не так и мало, но давненько не слышно новостей по этому поводу.

1. Это считается экспериментом. Он скорей удался или провалился? Какие критерии успеха/провала?
2. Когда и/или при каких обстоятельствах это выйдет как полноценная часть сайта, от кого или от чего это зависит?
3. Будет ли отображаться ассоциация для русских вопросов на англоязычный аналог? Если нет, то почему?
4. Будут ли ассоциации между разными сайтами сети StackExchange (помимо enSO и ruSO)? Если да, то от чего/кого это зависит?

---

По поводу пункта 4 спросил [на главной мете](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297063/346987), так как пока нет планов по реализации этого пункта.

Comment: А это, детектив, правильные вопросы.

Comment: Подозрительная тишина...

Comment: Николас ответил в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38030528#38030528).

Answer (score 3):

Николас ответил в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38030528#38030528):

> Добрый день! Вопрос видел, он крайне интересный, но пока чего–то конкретного ответить не могу, к сожалению. Точнее, я не могу что–то утверждать с достаточной уверенностью. Ассоциацию обещались добавить на сайт еще год (!!!) назад.
>
> В связи с изменившимся курсом компании, сделать это не смогли. Сделали через настройки сайта. Потом, когда прототип был готов, воде ребята опомнились и хотели сделать очередью вопросов, но опять не сложилось, так как продуктовый руководитель сайтов вопросов и ответов решил обратно стать разработчиком. Потом мы искали нового продуктового руководителя.
>
> Нашли, вот пару месяцев как уже он все дело осваивает, вроде все выходит на состояние до смены руководителя, то есть есть вероятность, что все–таки ее запилят, но случится ли что–то опять, я знать не могу, озвучить какие–либо сроки не могу.
>
> По остальным вопросам, мы уже вели беседу. Ситуация, в принципе, не изменилась.
>
> Про обновления ассоциаций на SOen. Чтобы ассоциации обновились, необходимо скопировать строку настроек (от сюда) в настройки SOen. Сейчас организация процессов в компании устроена таким образом, что не у всех сотрудников есть доступ на изменение настроек сайта. Тим Пост взял на себя задачу по обновлению именно ассоциаций. К сожалению, иногда случается, что он забывает их обновлять.

Comment: Ответ Николаса дан в июне 2017 года, сейчас на дворе почти июнь 2018. Год. Стоит ли публиковать такой старый ответ? Вероятно лучше дать новый? И лучше самому Николасу ответить, что поменялось за прошедший год, м?

Comment: @AK Возможно, вы и правы, просто недавно просто общался в чате по поводу ассоциаций. Дал ссылку на этот вопрос — и понял, что ссылка в чате — единственное, что есть как обратная связь. Я не знаю, насколько долговечны ссылки на сообщения в чате, поэтому решил опубликовать. Есть ощущение, что ничего пока не поменялось, но в любом случае это не от Николаса зависит, а от комманды. На данный момент, судя по мете, у них много планов — уверен, что ассоциация сейчас тем более не в приоритете. В любом случае, удалить ответ — проще простого, но другого пока ничего нет и непонятно когда будет…

Comment: @AK: чат для чата. Ответы на мета-вопросы должны на Мете публиковаться. Если лучшей информации нет, то можно хоть 10-летнюю цитату использовать.