# Насколько другим может быть русскоязычный Stack Overflow по отношению к англоязычному?

Tags: обсуждение

Насколько сложно принимать решения по изменению какого-либо функционала на ["*Stack Overflow на русском*"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)? Т.е. хочу узнать, насколько русскоязычный *Stack Overflow* может измениться по отношению к [англоязычному](https://stackoverflow.com/)? С какими проблемами сталкивается сообщество, если, к примеру, захотелось добавить функционал, которого нет на англоязычном *Stack Overflow*?

Comment: `захотелось добавить функционал, которого нет на stackoverflow` - то можно об этом даже не думать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, понятно.А более подробно ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский:  функционал может быть добавлен для нужд Stack Overflow на русском. Это очевидно хотя бы из того, что на русском интерфейс сайта. Если негативную информацию публикуете, хотя бы убедитесь, что она правдива и может помочь как-то в решении вопроса.

Comment: @jfs локализация != функционал. Если хочется ерунду пописать кому-то - отправляйтесь на другие ресурсы

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: вы хоть к одной программе пытались поддержку нескольких языков добавить? Код меняли? (если вы хотите лично лицом к лицу мне объяснить "отправляйтесь на другие ресурсы" фразу, то почта в моём профиле -- жду).

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а почему тогда у русского SO лента "живая", а на большом приходиться F5ячить?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev потому что они у себя **намеренно отключили** это. Потому что активность на столько высокая, что каждую минуту могли появляться десятки вопросов, а посетителей дофига и у них там с вебсокетами начались проблемы. Поэтому на остальных сайтах где активность еле-еле, в т.ч. ruSO - вполне себе работает

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> С какими проблемами сталкивается сообщество,если к примеру захотелось добавить функционал, которого нет на stackoverflow ?

С тем, что кодовая база у них, по большей части, общая, а фичи конкретных сайтов реально присутствуют на всех и управляются настройками разных уровней, в т. ч. довольно глубоких и доступных только разработчикам.

В целом, можно считать, что:

### если из всех сообществ Stack Exchange фича нужна *исключительно* на Stack Overflow на русском, этой фиче *не бывать*

***Но:*** насколько часто это реально имеет место? Если фича действительно хороша, вряд ли она будет полезна только здесь. В сети Stack Exchange очень много очень разных сообществ, не только технических. Принимайте их во внимание, если хотите что-то предложить.

---

Скажем, есть довольно нишевая вещь, [ассоциации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4409/181100), которая получила какую-никакую реализацию. Зародилась идея здесь, и задумывалась как средство связывания вопросов на разных языках. Связь между ru.SO и en.SO здесь как полигон для тестирования.

Но если идея "взлетит", другим локализованным сообществам эта фича бы тоже не помешала; а то и вообще любым сообществам с пересекающимися областями (что не входило в исходную задумку, но тем не менее возможно и полезно).

Comment: ваш ответ **"не бывать"** можно интерпретировать как: "бессмысленно на ru.SO новую функциональность предлагать" что слишком пессимистично преждевременно (даже если шансы промахнуться велики, вы промахиваетесь в 100% случаев, если вообще не пытаетесь — tradeoffs). Я вижу что множественные числа в интерфейсе адекватно переведены (это тяжело сделать без специальной поддержки русского—[правила здесь разнятся на разных языках](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/735467/23044)). Я вижу список причин закрытия отличается.  Я вижу что разрешённая тематика отличается (по сравнению с http://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @jfs локализацию как фичу они начали сами, и она полезна не только ru.SO; список причин закрытия различается только в разделе офф-топика, который настраивается, это не фича вовсе. Разрешённая тематика тоже не фича, а скорее общественная договорённость, подкреплённая страницами справки.

Comment: вы конечно можете определить слово "фича": «если отличается на разных сайтах, то не "фича"».  Думаете, те, у кого возможно удачная идея появилась изменить сайт, не вводя новых "фич" в вашем понимании, смогут эти тонкие отличия заметить? Кстати, наличие или отсутствие причины закрытия homework я считаю критическим для видения сайта (его миссии). Это может не иметь сиюминутного эффекта, но долговременно отношение к тем кто задаёт вопросы, атмосферу на сайте это меняет.

Comment: @jfs я рассматриваю "новую фичу" как *новое изменение функциональности* сайта (в противоположность доработке существующей), требующее новой логики в работе сайта и, вследствие этого, нового программного кода. В этом контексте мой ответ, надеюсь, выглядит понятнее. Но вопрос изначально был об этом: "захотелось добавить функционал".

Comment: допустим «живая лента» была бы выключена для ru.SO. А какой-то пользователь захотел добавить похожий "функционал". Они могли посмотреть на английский SO -- не увидели этой "фичи". Посмотрели на ваш ответ и решили *"этой фиче не бывать"* (performance) . Вы конечно скажете «живая лента» это не "фича", это настройка. Формально может и правы, но *на практике нельзя ожидать, что обычные пользователи знают все настройки доступные только разработчикам*, поэтому ваш ответ, в котором жирно выделено "фиче не бывать", вреден. Лучше ошибаться в пользу людей, которые интерес достаточный проявляют к сайту.

Comment: @jfs "живая лента" полезна не только для ru.stackoverflow, так что и этот пример не годится, даже если бы она требовала разработки. Если хотите, напишите свой ответ, изложите своё видение ситуации.

Comment: да, если читать мелкий шрифт. Я говорю о том, что у вас **ЖИРНЫМ** выделено. Вы выделили, не я.

Comment: @jfs да нет, слово "исключительно" тоже в жирном блоке. Могу добавить курсива :)

Answer (score 8):

Любые более-менее значимые изменения нужно просить на [метамете](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), однако опытным путём было установлено что нужды меньших народностей практически не удовлетворяют, разве что парочка особо сочувствующих разработчиков сделают.

Забавно выходит: расизм искореняем там, где нужно очень-очень захотеть увидеть, зато на нужды забиваем.

Comment: Пушкин говорил и писал на русском. Меж тем он был наполовину негром. Караул! Чернокожего притесняют! Всё, можно требовать реализацию любой фичи на русском :).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, а Вы знатный хитрец, сударь! Да, надо так и сделать :)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov На четверть он был негром.

Comment: @Cerbo и на четверть немцем. Что только добавляет весёлости в эту аналогию.