# Можно ли задвать один и тот же вопрос на разных языках?

Tags: обсуждение, правила, stackoverflow

Не так давно я задал вопрос на SO eng о подсветке синтаксиса в qt, но ответ не получил. ([вот он, кому интересно](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73905941/qt-creator-lines-that-draw-boundaries-of-block/73906892#73906892))
Я захотел задать этот этот же вопрос на SO ru, но не разобрался можно ли так по правилам.
Прямых запретов я не нашел(может и проглядел где-то, потому что дело не самое для меня приятное), но держу пари, что если я задам,то найдутся люди которые накидают мне дизов и жалоб, отметят вопрос дубликатом ссылаясь на мой же вопрос:)

Так вот : можно ли задавать один и тот же вопрос на разных языках при отсутствии ответа?

Comment: можно. Также можно сразу добавить [ассоциацию](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4409/186999)

Comment: Абсолютно, но будьте готовы, что не все пользователи отнесутся с пониманием. Пример моего ответа с добавлением ассоциации https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1335678/209304

Comment: @Grundy тема в предложеной ссылке устарела по-моему. Или до сих пор можно предлагать ответы на ассоциацию? Сейчас вроде можно просто оставить комментарий в формате `ассоциация:ссылка`

Comment: @Dmitry, об этом как раз в секции "Обновление" сказано