# Перенос ответов с англоязычного stack на русский

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

Несколько раз видел ситуацию, когда на вопрос, заданный на ru, отправляли на en версию stackOverFolw. Чем я был опечален, если честно...

> Вопрос: Стоит ли в таких случаях, если нет ответа на такой же вопрос на ru ресурсе, делать перенос ответа с англоязычного на русский и давать ответ(с линковкой, вроде как видел такую возможность, что можно залинковать ответ на русском с английским)?

Допустим, в каких то случаях, я готов потратить время на перевод ответа на русский и опубликовать перевод в качестве ответа.

Будет ли это считать плагиатом или как вообще действовать в таких случаях?

Comment: недавно задавался такой вопрос, не вижу смысла дублировать. Ответ: нет, это не считается плагиатом. Для этого кейса существует специальный механизм ассоцииации вопросов между enso и ruso.

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12171/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%85

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4409/%d0%90%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bd%d0%b0

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7543/%d0%af%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%89%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%85-stackoverflow

Comment: @МихаилРебров чтобы оставлять более короткие ссылки вы можете их копировать под самым вопросом ссылка [Поделиться](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12197/209304). Эта ссылка короче и не содержит русских и спецсимволов. На будущее) В том же окошке, вы найдете и ссылку на лицензию о которой спрашивается в этом вопросе) Вот эта CC BY-SA 4.0

Comment: @Dmitry, спасибо - я знаю. Обычно я форматирую ссылки, но с  мобильного писал и так просто удобнее и быстрее было.