# Поддержите инициативу ассоциации вопросов!

Tags: обсуждение, ассоциация-вопросов

Stack Overflow — это творение разработчиков, созданное разработчиками для разработчиков. Ассоциация вопросов — частный случай новой функциональности [предложенной сообществом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347/). Эксперимент заключается не только в том, чтобы понять насколько функционал полезен разработчикам, попадающим на сайт из поиска (пользователям), но и насколько полезным его считают активные участники.

На мой взгляд, польза для активных участников заключается в следующем.

- *Истинная необходимость функционала*. Нет никакой пользы от ассоциации, которую никто не создал. Если участники не используют функцию движка во время эксперимента, она не будет реализована, какую бы потенциальную пользу в будущем она не несла для пользователей. Stack Overflow создается для участников, да, именно для вас. На сайте будет только то, что нужно вам, что вы используете, то, что вам интересно.
- *Понимании конечной ценности*. Все, что мы делаем, должно быть полезно нам и нашим коллегам. Ассоциация вопросов не исключение. По сути, Stack Overflow — это большая база знаний в форме вопросов и ответов. Весь функционал сайта — это либо инструменты, позволяющие вносить [полезные] изменения в базу знаний, либо различные способы подачи имеющейся информации. Как бы в будущем ни выглядел функционал ассоциаций, любое улучшение структуры связей в базе знаний — бесценно само по себе!

#### Без ваших ассоциаций функционал никогда не будет добавлен

На данном этапе крайне важно понять насколько ассоциация вопросов на самом деле интересна вам. Ранее уже несколько раз обсуждалось, что может быть, а чего нет. Сейчас самое критичное — начать добавлять ассоциации. Только это показывает, что сообщество считает ассоциации полезной затеей.

#### Допустимость переводов популярных вопросов с английского языка

Как мне кажется, в сообществе имеет место быть [противоречивое отношение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/70/) к «искусственно» заданным вопросам (а–ля переводам). Предлагаю разрешить их следующим образом.

Из большого количества общения с пользователями (теми, кто только читает сайт) я вынес следующее. Stack Overflow невероятно полезен в том плане, что на страницах сайта представлен реальный опыт других разработчиков. Именно этим ценен сайт для наших коллег. Учитывая это, пожалуйста, переводите вопрос если вы понимаете, о чем говорится в вопросе или, что лучше, сами сталкивались с подобной проблемой, а также сможете поддерживать релевантность и правильность информации в переводе в течении всего времени жизни вопроса, либо уверены, что сообщество сможет это сделать. В обратном случае, лучше воздержаться от перевода.

Мы не сайт переводов, но если какой-либо вопрос первым был задан на англоязычном сайте, а не появился у нас — это не означает, что у русскоязычного сообщества нет экспертизы.

#### Цели

Как мне кажется, поддерживая уровень в 10 ассоциаций в день, можно смело говорить о наличии интереса к функциональности со стороны участников сообщества. В пределе, как мне кажется, эта цифра может быть 10% от количества вопросов задаваемых в день.

10% — это примерное количество закрываемых вопросов от общего числа. Для закрытия одного вопроса в общем случае необходимо пять участников, для ассоциации — достаточно всего одного (вас)! Поскольку структуризация знаний не менее важна часть движка, как мне кажется, оно того стоит и нам это по силам!

#### Говорить — не ассоциировать

На стадии реализации, разработчики уделят особое внимание мнениям тех участников, которые активно участвовали в подборе ассоциации, ведь именно они будут понимать большинство «подводных камней».

#### Знаки отличия

На текущей стадии эксперимента, наград — нет, но функционал ассоциаций — крайне важен. В будущем мы постараемся добавить знаки отличия и другие аспекты геймификации. Ваш вклад не останется незамеченным!

#### Расскажите, что вам необходимо для подбора ассоциаций

Если вам необходима какая-либо информация, которую я могу предоставить вам на основе имеющихся у меня данных (как у сотрудника, у меня есть доступ к различным внутренним базам данных, например, к логам, из которых можно получать интересные данные, например, о наиболее популярных вопросах на Stack Overflow на английском среди русскоязычной аудитории), пожалуйста, дайте знать! Буду рад всячески содействовать в создании крайне важных ассоциаций!

**[Добавьте ценности в уже существующие вопросы как на русском языке, так и на английском, предлагайте ассоциации!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4120/)**

Сделать что-то большое и по-настоящему полезное обществу мы сможем только вместе!

Comment: а я не совсем понял: в чем должна выражаться поддержка?

Comment: @Grundy Самая необходимая поддержка – _добавление ассоциаций_. Добавляя ассоциации мы тем самым показываем, что данный функционал будет нужным и его стоит реализовывать.

Comment: А [добавление только в список недавнего вопроса](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4120/186999)?

Comment: @Grundy Да, совершенно верно, [в ответ](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/4121/6) к вопросу! Далее я дело за мной! (Если у вас есть идеи о том, как упростить процесс, буду рад услышать!)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Кардинально бы упростило процесс, если бы ассоциации были двусторонние. Глядя на вопрос на русском, я вряд ли узнаю, добавлена ассоциация или нет (разве что в вопросе написано, что это перевод). А так можно было бы покрывать целые темы намного быстрей.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Согласен. Действительно, на данный момент это можно сделать лишь посмотрев [на ответ](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/4121/6)  со списком вопросов. Уточню, можно ли что–либо «рабочее» с этим сделать быстро.

Comment: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4523/178988

Comment: как добавить ассоциацию? что будет если ассоциация не верна?

Comment: @while1pass Детально процесс добавления ассоциаций описан в вопросе: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4120/. Если в двух словах, то сейчас существует два способа: 1) добавить новый элемент в конец списка ассоциаций в [ответе](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/4121/6); 2) добавить к ассоциируемому вопросу на русском языке комментарий содержащий ссылку в формате `ассоциация:ссылка_на_вопрос_на_английском`. Если ассоциация не верная, при проверке я дам вам знать, что что–то пошло не так.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Я правильно добавил [комментарий](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/612002/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be/612005#comment847517_612002) для ассоциации?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov абсолютно! Спасибо!

Answer (score 11):

Мне кажется добавление совсем неудобно через вопрос на мете.

Было бы здорово, если бы можно было оставлять комментарий под вопросом со ссылкой на английский ответ. Возможно в каком-нибудь специальном формате.

Comment: Теоретически, такая возможность есть. Но необходимо задать жесткий формат, к примеру, комментарий должен содержать следующее `soen_link:link_to_question_on_soen`. Как вариант, если это будет удобнее, можно указывать лишь id вопроса на английском. Идея заключается в том, что я могу выполнять SQL запросы по базе. Если мы будем использовать специальную метку в комментариях (как в примере выше), я смогу найти все ассоциированные таким образом вопросы.

Comment: Проверил. Комментарии смогу найти! Обновил вопрос: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4120/.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, Отлично!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, можно добавить в тот вопрос ссылку на реальный комментарий, чтобы совсем понятно что именно в нем может быть и как его составлять

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, кстати, это будет расцениваться как ассоциация в каком направлении: в нашему вопросу добавится плашка что есть ответ на английском? или к английскому добавится плашка что есть ответ на русском? или в оба вопроса плашки добавятся?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Можно ли на русском сайте сделать дополнительную кнопку в тулбар, для добавления подобного тега? Либо какой-нибудь скрипт/виджет для твойки популярных браузеров. Хотя я бы предложил именно кнопку, для тех, у кого 500+ репутации.

Comment: @AK Зная как устроенны процессы в компании, смею предположить, что пользовательский скрипт – куда более быстрое решение.

Comment: Предлагать ассоциацию комментарием удобно тем, что сразу видно, предложен ли уже вопрос на ассоциацию.

Answer (score 6):

В предложенном виде реализация идеи "ассоциации вопросов"—ущербна. Полезной реализацией было бы *автоматическое* создание связи на основе ссылок, упомянутых в самом  вопросе, ответах и комментариях как это сейчас происходит внутри сайта для "Связанных вопросов" (колонка справа).

Comment: Про выдергивание из комментариев формат в принципе предложили, не до конца автоматически, но хоть что-то

Comment: Это экспериментальный функционал. Сделан на коленке? – Да, так и есть. Ущербный? – Опять да, согласен на 100%. Чтобы получить полнофункциональную версию необходимо, чтобы сообществу вообще идея была интересна не только на словах, но и на деле.

Comment: @Grundy: нет. Никакого специального формата--вся идея состоит в том, чтобы ассоциации могли бы быть созданы естественным образом людьми, которые ничего об этой функциональности не знают. Подобным функционалом пользуются 1 из 100000 или меньше пользователей--если требовать обучения пользователей  для его использования, то он бесполезен

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: люди добавляют ссылки на другие вопросы--это факт, а не слова.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, кстати, раз можно разбирать ссылки - можно ж просто выбирать комментарии в которых ссылки на enSO, тогда и формат же никакой не нужно просто - есть ссылка на enSO - добавить ассоциацию с этой ссылкой

Comment: @jfs И это очень здорово! Я буду крайне рад всячески этому содействовать (по аналогии с предложением Grundy). Эксперимент продлится несколько месяцев. По его окончанию можно будет судить интересен ли он _нашему_ сообществу (сколько ассоциаций будет сделано, сколько участников внесли свой вклад и тд).

Comment: @Grundy Нет, не получится. Ссылок много в комментариях публикуют. Мы же собираем дубликаты на разных языках.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, тогда как вариант - добавить новый вид тревоги

Comment: @jfs, в принципе можно добавить пункт в справку по комментариям, что-то вроде: для указания дубликата на английском написать так-то.

Comment: @Grundy Как мне кажется, комментарий со ссылкой и какой–либо меткой (например, как предложен, `ассоциация:`) намного проще.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, проще для поиска? ведь по сути на сколько я понимаю в запросе просто нужно будет поменять `like 'ассоциация'`, на что-то вроде `like 'http://stackoverflow.com/'`. А уж выдергивание ссылок из тела комментария далее не изменится

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, кстати, а как это сейчас работает со связанными вопросами? они выдираются на уровне базы или где-то в коде?

Comment: @Grundy Ассоциации жестко задаются в настройках сайта парой идентификаторов (soen_id=soru_id). Да, я просто ищу по базе `LIKE N'%ассоциация%'`. Мы не можем просто запросить все ссылки! Их будет уйма, но ассоциации будут из них единицы!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky крайне неправильно использовать участие в конкретной (ущербной) реализации как меру *полезности* идеи "ассоциации вопросов" вообще. Если реализация бракована, это не значит что сама идея не является полезной. Такие тонкие эффекты (менее 0.001% от просмотров) требуют внимания к деталям, понимания что хочется получить и как сайт работает (подумайте о пользе для сайта: как эта фича  помогает  посетителям из поисковика и активным участникам). Требование явного создания связи вместо автоматического значительно снижает полезность фичи.

Comment: @jfs Я с вами ни в коем случае не спорю! Более того, практически все из перечисленного вами было в изначальном документе запрашивающем функционал.

Comment: @jfs, а автоматическое снижает качество. "Для тех, кому лень почитать комментарии, мы вытащили из них все ссылки на SO - вдруг будет не лень почитать их" - это точно полезно? Дубликаты же автоматом не назначаются, так что и ассоциации не должны.

Comment: @Qwertiy я не понимаю о чём вы. Лень здесь ни при чём. По вашей логике существование SO сайта с его акцентом на сигнал/шум отношение вообще бессмысленно—так как трудолюбивые люди по вашему сами полезный сигнал накопают среди мусора. О дубликатах речь не идёт. Связанные вопросы уже внутри сайта **автоматом** назначаются **в обе стороны** (комментируя на одном вопросе связь и на другом появляется). Расширение до нескольких сайтов было бы полезно. Введение специального синтаксиса, интерфейса значительно уменьшает полезность потому что не следует забывать что медиана репутации на SO равна единице

Comment: @jfs, но ведь мы сейчас обсуждаем функционал, аналогичный дубликатам. Т. е. такой же вопрос, но на другом сайте; а не просто связанный, а как именно - неизвестно (да ещё и на другом сайте).

Comment: @Qwertiy я не обсуждаю дубликаты. [Дубликаты между сайтами вообще особого смысла не имеют—пользы нет по сравнению с установлением связей.](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2541/23044)

Comment: @jfs, я запутался. Ассоциации вопросов между сайтами - это такой же род связи как дубликат, только без закрытия вопроса. Т. е. мы сообщаем, что в другом месте есть такой же вопрос и в него стоит заглянуть. Такой уровень связей может выставлять только человек, и никак не автоматическая выборка ссылок на все вопросы из комментариев. Отображение ссылок на вопросы на других сайтов из комментариев кажется мне совсем другой фичей, хотя она тоже может быть полезна.

Comment: @Qwertiy я не понимаю к чему эти вопросы. Вы начали с одного потом на другое перепрыгнули, потом на третье. Начните отдельное обсуждение про «являются ли "ассоциации вопросов" межсайтовыми дубликатами» (я всегда высказывался за связь многие ко многим—никакого отношения к дубликатам—но у других может быть другое мнение).

Comment: @jfs, значит у нас разное мнение. Для меня ассоциация = дубликат без закрытия. И вроде я про это с самого начала говорил. Видимо, из-за разного понимания мы запутались :)

Answer (score 1):

Пополнение базы знаний на русском языке это хорошо. Но реализация через "ассоциации"?

Каждый в отдельности вопрос - частность. Хорошо бы инструмент, который обобщает несколько вопросов по теме, вычленяя ядро: особенный метод предполагаемого решения, специальный случай.

Каким-то образом должно проходить голосование за актуальность такого вопроса. Затем или сразу добавление "канонического" ответа (переведенного или сформулированного инициатором "ассоциации").

Но главное: предложено соревнование (challenge) дать более правильный ответ, лучше оформленный, более ясный. Победитель соревнования получает баллы репутации в зависимости от ценности (актуальности) вопроса.

**Подвожу итог:**

```
     - вопрос должен быть актуальным, специфичным, но достаточно общим;
     - предложенный автором ответ должен пройти экспертизу;
     - экспертиза проводится посредством соревнования на лучший ответ;
     - соревнование проводится в течение какого-то времени (недели, двух);
     - вознаграждение за лучший ответ зависит от актуальности вопроса;
     - в базу попадают лишь актуальные вопросы и ответы, прошедшие экспертизу.
```

Comment: Для этого, как минимум, надо изменить софт, оформив таким образом *базу знаний*, как выделенный объект

Comment: База вопросов и ответов, по-моему, и есть "база знаний", это не специальное значение и термин)). Вообще, неплохо бы иметь "канонические вопросы", куда сходились бы подобные вопросы. Вся проблема в степени подобия)). Но, главное, - иметь развернутые, канонические ответы, больше даже статьи, чем просто ответы на конкретный вопрос.

Comment: Сейчас все это будет в одной куче. Предложите, хотя бы к каноническим темам особую метку цеплять. Только метки это по большому счету профанация, при поиске обычные люди их никак не используют. Поэтому я и говорю, *база знаний* должна быть отделена. Как википедия. Может даже отделена другим www-адресом

Comment: Если вы про последний пункт, то ДА!!! Предполагаю, что к этому и идет. Для чего тогда эти "ассоциации"?.. Как будут выделены, много вариантов. Но зачем на другой сайт, наоборот, все должно быть доступно в одном месте. Из моносервисного сайта "вопрос-ответ" можно сделать всеобъемлющее приложение. С чатом, с энциклопедией, с набором людей на проекты разные... Почему нет?

Comment: Если кто-то   это сделает и найдутся *квалифицированные* энтузиасты, то хорошо. Только где вы их в нужном количестве найдете? Поэтому следут признать, что *база знаний* это утопия. И использовать что есть для **помощи конкретным людям**.