# Имеет смысл задавать вопросы по ассемблеру?

Tags: обсуждение

Всем привет, на стаке задают вопросы в основном по поводу [c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), [javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), [html](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) и.т.д.

Вопрос: имеет ли смысл задавать вопросы по [assembler](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembler), если на нем никто не кодит? Я как-то давно учил assembler и даже забыл что в нем делать, и задавать ли вопросы по assembler на англоязычном стаке.

Comment: На ассемблере-таки кодят (но чаще всякие pic/avr/arm и прочий embedded), и у нас есть почти 500 вопросов по метке [tag:ассемблер]. Есть и отвечающие.

Comment: @Nofate, кстати, глядя на первую страницу вопросов с тегом [assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembly) на аглийском SO, у меня создается впечатление, что у нас процент вопросов с ответами повыше, чем там. P.S. Хотя глобально не сильно выше, там 21% неотвеченных, у нас 17% неотвеченных.

Comment: Как это никто не кодит? (обиженно) а я? :))))

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Нельзя сказать, что на языке Ассемблера никто не кодит. Я лично не программирую на нем постоянно, но использую в своем хобби-проекте (правда, скорее с "обратной" стороны). На ru.SO отвечаю на вопросы по ассемблеру, так же как и по другим знакомым мне языкам - если вопрос мне интересен, и если вопрос в сфере моей компетенции:)

По своему опыту - на ru.stackoverflow.com задают вопросы по assembler, и, более того - отвечают на них. Смысл задавать есть.

Для сравнения, у нас почти 500 вопросов по ассемблеру, примерно 87% как минимум с одним ответом с положительным рейтингом. А есть еще такой язык как [prolog](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog), по которому за все время было всего 58 вопросов, из них всего 15 без ответов с положительным рейтингом (по факту всего 8 вопросов по Прологу вообще без ответов). Можно ли сказать, что на Прологе практически никто не пишет (вне ВУЗа)? В отличие от ассемблера - думаю можно. Имеет ли смысл задавать по нему вопросы? Имеет, и с большой вероятностью на вопрос кто-то ответит.

Answer (score 30):

Безусловно стоит. Если не будет вопросов, то не появятся и ответы.

Бесспорно, на английском SO больше как информации, так и участников с соответствующими знаниями. Но раз уж Вы решили обсудить этот вопрос тут, на русском SO, значит англоязычная версия не в полной мере Вас устраивает. К тому же, даже если Вы зададите вопрос на enSO и получите там ответ быстрее, чем на ruSO, хорошим вариантом будет [перевод полученного ответа](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/71/176217), размещения его на русском языке и создания соответствующей [ассоциации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4500/176217). Таким образом Вы будете содействовать развитию сообщества разработчиков на русском языке.